# How can I revert my "reaction" to a Teams post?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, reactions

Stack Overflow for Teams added an option to select an emoji for a post, which is fine. I am neither against it nor support it.

I tried to test this feature, and "reacted" to a post with a particular emoji. I tried this only to test it, and I want to revert my action.

How can I revert my reaction to that particular post?

Answer (score 7):

Just open the react dialog again and toggle the reaction you have selected. It will unmark it.

Apparently there is no locking mechanism (unlike normal voting, that just can be undone within 5 minutes of voting): I reacted to a post yesterday and I was able to undo it right now, after more than 10 hours.

Comment: Still unable to revert . Increase emoji like but unable to  revert  previous  reaction . Sorry.

Comment: How weird, @Shree. In the Team I am part of, there is no locking. I suggest waiting a bit until the formal presentation is done and see if they talk about this issue.