# Feature test: Thank you reaction

Tags: discussion, announcement, reactions, thanks

We just announced a new feature test for the "thank you" reaction on The Overflow [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/).

We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers. Although it's less common on questions, the percentage of “thanks” comments has continued to slowly increase over the last few years.

[image: chart showing the percent of comment on Stack Overflow with a "thank" in them, over time]

Using this data and user research, we're introducing this clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions.

#### Share your thanks

On the left of an answer post, you'll find a *hands icon* underneath the usual voting controls. By simply selecting the icon, you can share your thanks to the post-author. As reactions are added by users, a count of the reactions will appear below the icon.

This feature is available to all registered users, regardless of reputation (unlike voting, which is only available for users with 15 reputation or more).

#### Test variations

We’re testing two versions of the “thank you” icon:

[image]

We hope that this test will have a positive impact on our community and reduce:

- Friction for users whose comments are deleted,
- The burden on moderators, and
- The time active users spend flagging/deleting comments.

#### Other details

- Users will only be able to award 30 reactions during a single UTC day, like with voting, and you'll get a notification if you are approaching the target.
- Users will only be able to award reactions to 5 posts by any given post owner during a single UTC day. You'll get a notification if you have reached the limit.
- Reacting to an answer doesn't impact reputation so if you can vote and the answer solves the problem in the question, don't forget to vote as well.
- Reactions don't notify the person who wrote the answer.

You can find more information about this in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/reactions).

#### What's next

We’ll be monitoring usage and other data over the next month and will use those results to inform how we may move forward with this experiment. If you run into any issues or bugs, please share them here.

---

**Update**: Please see [Data validation & background for the Thank You Reaction feature test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398909/data-validation-background-for-the-thank-you-reaction-feature-test) for more details on the plans for evaluating the results of this test, and for responding to the feedback given here

Comment: I don't like the facebook-esque aspect of how this feature looks, but this looks like a solid first step to determining useful answers on old posts (something we've been lacking for years). I assume this change is a part of that and I'm glad to see it.

Comment: The frst step to transform this community to a Social network? This seems to me the "Like" of facebook.

Comment: Would it not have been a better idea to suggest this idea to the community first, get feedback and possible better solutions, and then test it?

Comment: Oh no. Whatever next. Allow users to mark posts with emoticons? I really don't need to see clapping hands everywhere.

Comment: I've just seen the feature and after reading the explanation page ... what exactly is the purpose? Isn't *voting* covering everything mentioned there?

Comment: Surely this is what an upvote is for!? Why not just reduce that "1 in 6 coments says thanks" and do a "if comment.contains("thanks") && user == OP then upvote" and it might cull those 1/6 stats down a bit.. Are we soon to get a wired telephone, cobweb or maybe netscape navigator logo to mark answers as obsolete?

Comment: (I can't help but think that changing the upvote tooltip to "This was useful, thanks" would have saved a lot of dev..)

Comment: I thought Stack Overflow was [done with forcing unpopular changes on its users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/566903)

Comment: Could we have a "No-thanks" button for this post so that I can downvote it twice please?

Comment: Why can't I thank myself? I tried to give myself a good thanking but I couldn't. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that most people use the "two hands touching palm-to-palm" emoji exclusively to indicate "praying" rather than 'high five', putting aside any addtional issues of trying to connote "upvote by providing +10 reputation and +1 score" with the act of giving someone a 'high five'.

Comment: @LisaPark Please also study votes cast on questions affected by this as I suspect we'll see fewer votes cast on this as people thing a "high five" is adequate. That will have the unfortunate side effect of people spending their clicks and effort on actions that have no effect. I don't care if a post has 500 positive reactions, because that doesn't help me or the system classify it. If a post has 500 upvotes, it directly affects the status of the post within the Q&A page, and it directly affects the status and privileges the author has.

Comment: Personally, I am not able to find the wisdom in introducing a second "meaningless-to-the-system" act which I can only see as diverting attention away from the method we *already have* for saying thanks, giving high fives, providing kudos, awarding chili peppers, etc: **the upvote**. I think such efforts would be better served by trying to point people more clearly to the up/down vote options.

Comment: Was there some outcry for this "feature"? Why are SO devs wasting there time with this when there's a long list of other problems and features that have been hanging around for ages? [Stackoverflow's founder already told us how to say thanks](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) [(2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question/17886#17886). Stop wasting your time and fix other things.

Comment: @CaiusJard Or just increase the threshold on the regex for comments; if a comment would be auto-deleted based on its content and length e.g. "+1 thanks", block  those comments instead, and show a banner that says "want to say thanks? upvote the post, instead!"

Comment: I'm assuming this privilege is available to _all_ users, regardless of their reputation? If so, as someone who focuses mostly on reviewing answers, I am definitely interested to see the results of this test. Hopefully, it helps cut down on the clutter from users who don't yet have enough reputation to either vote or comment, and thus leave their "Thanks" as an answer. If this serves its intended purpose, one might similarly imagine a "Me too!" reaction. That said, for users with >=15 rep, the distinction between the "Thanks" reaction and an upvote feels a bit ambiguous.

Comment: This is a small thing, but your X axis says "month" but only years are labelled.

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites the way to say *thank you* is to 
[upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the tick mark on the left. You're free to switch later when a better answer comes along.

Comment: Y'know, one of the *most* requested features we have from new users is for downvoters to optionally explain why they're downvoting.  Why not expand this system to provide the same thing for bad posts?  If the dev work has already been done, let's give these users what they want!  ...Cue angry users wanting to know why they got negative reactions along with the downvotes.

Comment: This is even worse than the "Hot Network Post" banner. In addition, it can be used to taunt other users "You're getting a thanks.. that's it."

Comment: @Vickel You can't use that for reference. That page just hasn't been updated to include the thank button. :]

Comment: How are reactions supposed to be different than voting for the question? As a contributor and user -- why would I want a clapping hands icon instead of an upvote? Very confusing and bewildering what practical purpose these things are supposed to serve? Looks more like a gee-whiz widget looking for some place to be used rather than a solution crafted to solve an identified problem. How many years have we nuked `"+1"` comments? We'll go with it and see with where it goes...

Comment: Can people stop posting good comments and answers to this highly thoughtful feature? I just hit the voting limit. No seriously, give me a thank button on comments.

Comment: I know saying thanks in the comments is discouraged, but I do it anyway sometimes. And since pressing the thank you button doesn't notify the user, I'll keep saying thank you in the comments.

Comment: How to decide whether I should **Upvote** or use **Thank you** when a post is helpful? Also, how can I say a "No Thank you"?

Comment: ***THANKS*** for robbing us of reputation since, inevitably, some people will press thanks instead of upvote.  How about a facepalm button to use on this question?

Comment: On my 101 PPI monitor, the first icon is completely incomprehensible, it looks like a lawn sprinkler underneath a T square.  If I hadn't seen this post in "Featured on Meta" I would have had no idea what to make of it.

Comment: Why aren't you getting the community feedbacks before launching it ? i think you missed the flow of requirements(feedbacks) -> test -> launching

Comment: "a new feature test" It's not exactly clear, what a feature test is. Maybe the methodology (length, number of testers, ...) could be explained a bit. "introducing this clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks"" There was always voting to say thanks. From my own experience I can say that I say thanks in a comment only if I also want to say something else. This clutter-free way would not help me. Actually, I would find it rather more distracting. If it becomes implemented, I would like to have an option to turn it off for me completely (not seeing the button nor the number).

Comment: Maybe people here forgot how it was to be lowrep user, just reading without asking or answering questions at first. That's a way for the 1-14 rep users to show their satisfaction for a Q/A without modifying / influencing the reputation system. We may have a bias because 1-14 rep users barely go on meta, can't comment or vote or post here anyway.

Comment: It boggles the mind. After everything that's happened over the last year, I can't believe how tone-deaf this company still is. No matter how many lengthy allegories about [gardeners and visitors](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/the-loop-june-2020-defining-the-stack-community/) you post, you still don't get it. Of course the main concern of the community was going to be how this would impact voting. You could have gotten ahead of that by addressing that in your post. Or, better still, by asking community feedback before releasing. But, as we have come to expect, you chose to do neither.

Comment: If you can _comment_ a "Thanks" you got enough reputation to upvote - this feature is a waste of energy, time and clutters the UI. You do NOT target "silent" users that have no way to express thanks . The priority here is : Upvote, Maybe add a targetted comment. Using a "clap" emote that does not even reach the _author_ of the answer_ is bs.

Comment: 'the percentage of “thanks” comments have continued to slowly increase over the last few years' Except what you are really doing is overreacting to a worry of Eternal COVID. Don't worry, it will soon settle back down to Eternal September.

Comment: If someone thanks an answer I wrote, and somehow I find out about it, I feel like it would be only polite if I could press a "You're welcome" button that also serves no purpose.

Comment: Seems like people here are missing one big point, which is: **new users cannot vote**. Yes we all agree that the best way to thank a poster is to upvote their question / answer, but there's a good chunk of our user base that just cannot do that. @JeremyCaney already commented about this; I took the next step and edited the question to explicitly mention it. Feel free to rollback, of course.

Comment: I'll be pruning some comments here since the discussion got lengthy. Let's continue the discusson in [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room) or [Discord](https://discord.gg/tpgZmwR).

Comment: @walen then add the thanks function only to the new users, who can't upvote. In 50-75% of the case the don't even bother accepting the answer, or upvoting at all if they have the minimal reputation to do it. !Even! after you answer to their extra questions under the question, which you shouldn't even care about. Point collecting is already a waste of time. One single week was more then enough for me, and I think I was smart not to do it for years, because most of the users doesn't respect your time you spend  on helping to them. And this feature wont help either

Comment: This Thank you feature is not useful. Now I noticed people are giving me thanks reaction rather than upvotes. I want upvotes. My reputation will not increase if it keeps happening. And In the mobile web version, thanks rection is not showing.

Comment: This is now the most downvoted question in Stack Overflow Meta.

Comment: Just because everyone has a clap icon, does not mean that this community have to do this as well. I used the thanks feature and it seems redundant. Also, thanks does not have anything to do with the reputation. Please don't make this community an fb for tech.

Comment: After this past year staff should have approached the user base instead of this terrible role out. I dont think SE is listening to its user base. SE runs off the people and the continue disregard sooner or later it's gonna really hit your wallet. I hope you guys do the right thing and remove this than any "thanks" be added as rep to the users that gave an answer.

Comment: Since the "Thanks" feature offers no benefit to the poster, why bother restricting me from thanking myself?  If my past self posted an answer that current me appreciates, I should be able to offer a thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure a lot of people add "thanks" comments (e.g."thank you very much!" or "[A longer technical comment]. Thanks for the excellent solution!", etc), *despite knowing fully well* that such "thanks" isn't needed/discouraged/need-to-vote-instead/may-get-nuked-soon. Why? Because, for a lot of people, "thanking" is not only about Internet points or some "reaction" count - but it's *truly* thanking the person that helped them directly & personally. Replacing *that* with a "button" isn't going to persuade them (they'll add a comment regardless of the other "thanking" options available).

Comment: This is definitely going to affect the reputation of the user who wrote an answer. Instead of pressing Up-vote (this gives 10 reputation) and people simply say Thanks/Claps that doesn't going to affect the performance of the user who wrote the answer. So day by day the users who writing answers will be reduced which will affect the growth of SO only.

Comment: Oh no! Please keep it simple. That is the charm of that kind of platform, not having such emoji style crap. Seeing the votes up or down gives a notification and reflects the quality.

Comment: "'thanks' appears in 1 of 6 comments"; what an incredibly flawed search method. Maybe it would have been relevant if you had only searched for comments which *only* contain 'thanks'. I know that whenever I wrote 'thanks' in a comment I always followed up with actual useful information or a question. What's next? Reaction smileys? I like this site because it keeps the clutter out of the way. I'd prefer a big red banner on every page that said something like "this site is a Q/A library for quickly finding useful answers, so please stay strictly relevant to the question".

Comment: Thank you. There I said it. I honestly don't know why this site hates the phrase "thank you" in comments, considering the fact that a lot of comments posted by new users who don't know any better are just as useless as that phrase. Just ignore it. There are a lot of low-quality questions that haven't been closed and a lot of low quality and useless comments that haven't been removed. You can't force everything to be perfect.

Comment: I like many other users disagree with this feature. It can become very very **spammy**. Just look at the number of down-votes to your post.

Comment: @aminabzz This feature has been disabled a few months ago and it’s not coming back any time soon. What’s the point of your comment?

Comment: I thought it's still on the table

Comment: I'm glad that "thanks" went away and I hope it stays that way.  Honestly, what's the point of a "thanks" button if it doesn't give you reputation?  It's just de-crediting answers by having people "thank" you instead of upvoting.

Answer (score 1334):

This feature serves no purpose. It will only make things more confusing.

Either the answer is a good answer worth up-voting or it is not. There is no middle ground. Saying thanks for what - mediocre answers?

Seriously, why, o why, o why ... why are you wasting time on such things that bring nothing?

---

> Reactions don't notify the person who wrote the answer.

If the purpose of saying thanks is actually saying thanks to the person who wrote the answer, then I must say that not notifying the author is a bit of a strange choice.

Comment: I disagree that this serves no purpose. As the post stands, yes the potential uses for this have not been explored fully, but this is a good step for providing useful signals on the efficacy of a post, short of doing sentiment analysis on comments.

Comment: @cs95 *good step for providing useful signals on the efficacy of a post* --> we already have this since too long and it"s called voting.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, yes voting, yes. But votes are skewed by time and usually don't reflect that an answer has gotten defunct unless someone comments. This will help surface new answers, with fewer votes, but answer the question better than others do. Even the playing field.

Comment: Eh, notifications can be really noisy. I've uh... had to deal with a lot of them. If you take an action that only a small fraction could do and make it possible for everyone, the number of notifications can go up ... uh... exponentially... and that gets kinda annoying over time. Until we know how much these are used and how much impact they would have on someone's inbox, I wouldn't want to add the clutter to yours (or my own). Plus, for those who don't like the feature, it's much easier to ignore it if you aren't reminded of it constantly. :D

Comment: *This will help surface new answers, with fewer votes, but answer the question better than others do* --> I sitll don't see how the thanks will do this. It will not bump any new answer to the top and it won't reflect quality because it's here to *say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions* and not to *say "thanks" to others for taking the time to [give good and accurate] answer to questions*

Comment: @Catija I agree that notifications can be noisy and I am not saying that I want them (for this feature)... but if purpose of this is saying thanks, then without notification, there is no actual thanks... unless you go to that page and see that your answer got "thanks". It kind of defeats the original purpose.

Comment: @cs95 I don't see how this helps. You cannot sort by thanks. So it's unlikely to surface anything. If you visit a question with many existing answers and don't want to read them, then you wouldn't want to search for the one with more thanks assigned to it anyway. Furthermore "*votes are skewed by time*" the thanks are going to be even more sqewed. At the very least you can counter an upvote with a downvote. So you have a chance against outdated answers. Not with thanks an outdated answer can *only* get more thanks. It's unlikely that all people who thanked it will unthank.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar very much agree. I'm not sold on the thanks idea but I agree that without notifications, it's even more useless. I have more than 400 answers - should I go through each on a regular basis to get a warm fuzzy feeling? I think I'd actually get more frustrated by seeing that only, say, 50 (probably an huge over estimation) got thanked. So, the thanks button really doesn't do anything for *me* as an answer writer. It seems only useful to other people who would read answers.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't much care for this feature on new posts, only posts > 60 days old.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Sure. I revisit some of my old answers from time to time... it's fun to see how high they get in score... that happens often on Meta posts which have no notifications for voting (other than MSE)... I'm often surprised and grateful for it... that something I added to the ecosystem of the site was appreciated by others.

Comment: I understand that this is a sudden change and it's confusing and weird - to me, too... I have all sorts of concerns myself - but I'd like to invite y'all to ... give it a chance. See where it goes. We want to see the data on it and we'll definitely come back to it... but if it's useful to others - particularly people who can't vote - if it reduces the need to flag comments that just say "thanks" (because there are fewer comments) and if it's not harmful to things like voting... what's the harm? - honest question. Other than an immediate reaction, what's the harm if the bad things don't happen?

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites the way to say *thank you* is to 
[upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the tick mark on the left. You're free to switch later when a better answer comes along.

Comment: @Catija If people don't have enough reputation to vote, they certainly don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: "What is the harm" ... Well, there is already a problem with teaching new users that this is not a social platform and how they should use the site. Adding confusing features, like thanks will not make that part any easier.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar There's at least two distinct groups here. 1. Users who can comment/vote but don't know how to do it correctly. 2. Users who can't comment or vote but are frustrated by trying to say thanks and end up either a. leaving frustrated or b. they post an answer - which is even more work to remove -  which leads to them getting downvotes and a deleted post and, if they don't learn, possibly an answer ban. The ability to thank an answer may reduce the friction on all three of these.

Comment: Again, that's making assumptions that it will cause harm. We need to actually see that it does have that sort of impact - it's easy to assume that it will and you (and all of the other concerns here) may end up being the case but if we test it, the outcome may be completely different than what we expect - or perfectly accurate... but we can't know without trying... it could have low negative impact and high positive value to certain groups and that's worth at least trying.

Comment: @Catija You mean...kinda like Ask Question wizard?  Where gobs of dev time went, and it turned out to be barely marginal to some text on the ask page? Or the New Contributor icon, which doesn't seem to have served it's stated purpose, either?

Comment: @Catija, if you really have to implement this, do it for new users only (they need all kind of help) and have a look at UX suggestion from the answer of Wrzlprmft in their post

Comment: @fbueckert Well, this already exists on Teams, so porting it to Public wasn't a huge amount of work - don't get me wrong, there's definitely some work because they aren't identical - but it's on no sort of scale anything like building the question wizard. And... well, we learned a lot of good things from the question wizard that went into the new question asking form.

Comment: @cs95 if you want to surface newer answers which had less chance to get upvotes, then allow for multiple votes to be cast, even with a price tag attached, like the bounties have. (I proposed it once and was downvoted into oblivion.)

Comment: I completely agree with the "this serves no purpose" part as it seems like having this would reduce the number of flags but not the time needed handling the flag queue. By this I mean that the workflow for a "thanks" flag would be "Read, delete, dismiss flag as helpful" which is not much compared to detailed custom flags, or ..... I mean, it could help a little but not near the level predicted by the blog post (it really makes me wonder if the mods even asked for this - esp. the new counsel of elders thing).

Comment: @LinkBerest "Counsel of elders"? It's just the Mod Council and there's no minimum tenure required to be on the Council. This was planned back in December, so... no, it has nothing to do with them and this isn't even the sort of thing the Council would do.

Comment: @Catija Zoe posted some pretty good comments on another post, so I will not repeat. But the core problem is that you (SE) needs to educate users better about existing features and rules - not add more features that needs explaining.

Comment: If posting comments in answers is a problem, then explain that when someone tries to post their first answer. If users are frustrated, that is more because they cannot comment, not because they cannot say thanks. And I have doubts that number of thank you comments will be reduced, because not all comments that contain thanks are actually just saying thanks for an answer.

Comment: It doesn't only serves no purpose, it is plain harmful. I explained that in [my dedicated answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398422/12139179).

Comment: I wouldn't say it serves no purpose.  "...the percentage of 'thanks' comments have [sic] continued to slowly increase over the last few years."  The obvious purpose is to cut down on "thanks" comments.  I'm not sure why that's important, but that's clearly the purpose.

Comment: `This was planned back in December` [@Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?answertab=votes#comment776001_398371) And then in June, six months later, “Ta-da! Surprise!” “Hey, this is fun!” “Isn't it? No?”  Was there any forewarning to SO users? Were any SO moderators consulted? P.S I haven't cast any vote, I wanted to UVote one comment beneath the announcement but couldn't. :(

Comment: too bad. I can't do "thanks" to your answer :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif Some people can't upvote, because they have less than 15 rep.

Comment: @TheMaker They cannot leave "Thank you comments" either.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, I hate "Thank you comments". I was just saying that this feature isn't horrible.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar They can leave "Thank you comments" on their own posts.

Comment: @TheMaker Is leaving "thank you comments" so horrible problem that it deserves another feature that has potential to confuse users and to reduce voting? Furthermore, is the inability to say thanks on other answers (for <15 users) such an issue...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar No, not really. I think "thank you comments" are not as bad as people put them.

Comment: @10Rep This restriction is made to avoid vauting fraud and it's *very* easy to get 15 Rep. One good answer is enough or 7 good edits. This won't take you more than one day in the site.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I agree. I am not a fan of this new feature, but I think we should try it out, and then dismiss it.

Comment: @Catija as in "inner council" or "trusted members" or ... (a turn-of-phrase referencing the mods elected as trusted, not their age itself, because I couldn't remember the name and didn't want to call them super mods). Why wouldn't asking them about this be within their functions? if its dealing with flag handling, curation, and moderation - doesn't this seem like just the thing they would be asked about? (or I guess *what do they do?* would be the question). The fact that it started before that started would make me ask this even more because it gave plenty of time to have that conversation.

Comment: @LinkBerest I didn't say they shouldn't see this and give feedback. I was refuting your statement that implied they were the source of this "they asked for this", which isn't true in the slightest. It's possible I misunderstood your comment, though.

Comment: It's not even clear "Thanks" is _supposed_ to be a middle ground between no-upvote and up-vote. It's just confusing.

Comment: This place is losing my interest each and every day. Look at the last time I answered or asked a question, it shows how much interest I have lost here.  This feature makes me lose more interest.

Comment: Instead of this "thanks"-thing, I'd rather appreciate the concept of an "Inverse Bounty": The option to spend 100 of your own reputation in order to remove 100 (or maybe only 50) of the reputation of someone who wrote one of these *really* bad answers.

Comment: @Marco13 I'm not sure that's a good idea as that might make some people afraid of answering. Even if the answer they planned on posting is good, they might be afraid someone would think it's bad enough to use an "inverse bounty" on, so they won't post an answer that would have been good.

Comment: @Marco13 Also, I think that it's a bad idea in general to allow a single (non-moderator) user to remove that much reputation from someone at once, because maybe someone might use the "inverse bounty" not because the answer was bad but just because [Tim Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/349538). For downvotes it's not a big deal since downvotes only remove 2 reputation at a time, but I don't like the idea of risking someone losing 50 or 100 reputation at once just because of a mistake or because someone does something weird.

Comment: @DonaldDuck The comment was not meant to be *entirely* serious (and of course, nothing even *resembling* the concept of an "inverse bounty" would ever be implemented). The main point was that we now have a feature (that is not well thought through, to say the least) which allows some sort of "useless expression of appreciation", whereas I see a larger problem in the cases where a bad question receives a bad answer, and the mutual upvotes of asker and answerer seem to "validate" the Q/A. One could also argue that we need better tools to separate wheat and chaff.

Comment: I am glad that there is a real UX team that is implementing these features based on real issues seen and not moderators.

Comment: This Thank you feature is not useful.
Now I noticed people are giving me thanks reaction rather than upvotes. I want upvotes. My reputation will not increase if it keeps happening. And In the mobile web version, thanks rection is not showing.

Comment: Agreed, idiotic approach and stupid feature. Upvote already serves the purpose and in a better way! Have people started perceiving or wanting social media like FB and Instagram in every online platform? Because that would be a sad and worrisome situation for not just people on SO but humanity in general.

Comment: The only reason I use it is if the answer is the solution to my problem, but has actually nothing to do with the question asked. Then I first thank the author for solving my problem and immediately downvote for the off-topic answer..

Comment: @Teharez Don't do that. If you thank a off-topic answer, the answerer **_might_** get the wrong impression.

Comment: "Seriously, why, o why, o why ... why are you wasting time on such things that bring nothing" - the obvious reason is "because those inventing new policies at SE are incapable of anything more intelligent."

Answer (score 642):

What an unbelievably unnecessary thing. We already have voting!

> the percentage of “thanks” comments have continued to slowly increase over the last few years

Likely because SO is getting more and more users, and they're not properly taught how the site works.

As other answers also point out: [content or people?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391959/7395227)

Comment: I understand your reaction but it also somewhat misses that a huge number of users don't have the 15 reputation needed to vote. Voting is amazing. I want more people to vote and to show what answers are great but if you can't vote, it's incredibly frustrating to not be able to indicate your appreciation... and people do try to vote. Thousands of votes go uncounted every day from people trying and having their votes rebuffed because they lack the reputation.

Comment: @Catija The question asker can accept the best answer, and come back and upvote other answers later.

Comment: The question asker isn't the only person who might want to vote on an answer.

Comment: @Catija Yes, it's a problem that votes go uncounted. The solution to this would be to let users review all their previously cast votes when they reach the required reputation (15 and 125), and recast the vote if they voted correctly, or retract (do nothing) if they shouldn't have voted.

Comment: That's only helpful for the tiny number of people who a, make it there and b, want to take the time and don't just burn through all of their votes for days doing so.

Comment: so let people vote at any rep level, and when they reach that magic rep number all their votes go in as real votes.

Comment: @Catija Then honestly, maybe their votes deserve to go uncounted.

Comment: Votes don't go uncounted though, they're just not visible when you're not looking for them. For example, you can easily create a SEDE query with top low-rep upvoted and downvoted posts, which was personally interesting for me because they did not seem to correlate with actual votes. And actually, quite a lot of them were downvotes due to the higher rep requirement which this feature doesn't address.

Comment: @Catija So I have to put up with seeing clapping hands everywhere? Please add a configuration option so we can turn off seeing them.

Comment: @ErikA If you have 10k, you don't even need SEDE. There's a [10k tool for it](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback).

Comment: @Catija the users who can't upvote aren't even _close_ to being able to comment. This will only affect askers with <15 rep, and even then, if thanking becomes the new form of accepting, it breaks the rep system. What happens when rep growth starts stagnating, and nearly no one upvotes? Explaining the difference alone would end up being a clusterfuck. Introducing rep for thanking would end up being another farming vector, as well as making "votes" public (mentioned in a different answer here for t hose out of the loop; thanks are public). This change doesn't address the comment problem.

Comment: We can't convince people downvotes mean "this post has problems" and not "this post is bad and you should feel bad about yourself", we somehow seem to fail hard at making people understand answers aren't comments, and lots of people don't vote already. This will just make it worse. The main concern for me is for new users who actually want to contribute to Stack - if they can't get the rep, they can't contribute. "Thanks" means exactly nothing in that area

Comment: @Zoe I know the question talks about reducing comments - and that is something we'd like to do - but for me this is less about reducing comments and more about increasing people's ability to show appreciation for something that may have just got them unstuck at work or saved their project but they can't do the right thing of voting. It's easy to feel extremely locked out when you can't do anything and trying just gives you a note that isn't particularly encouraging. Accepts have always been optional and (personally) I don't like them or their impact much.

Comment: @Zoe I'm extremely concerned about the impact on voting, both up and down and you can be certain that's top of mind for this test. Voting is already lower than useful - many people forget to vote, even when they can and I really want to do more to increase voting and would love to do it in conjunction with this, somehow... but if this causes a drop in voting, I'll be really concerned and want to look at the possible causes and mitigations.

Comment: This is still going to have a significant impact on new users trying to get rep, and especially those who need the rep to contribute more. Is it really worth losing potential future moderators over thanks?

Comment: @Catija If the voting has decreased more since last summer, that might be a consequence of people refusing to vote as a means of strike.

Comment: Also, we've lost a lot of the core userbase into the void, codidact, topanswers, and other places. If nothing is done to reverse that, or to try to refill the core userbase, SE itself is going to be screwed in every possible way. The protests raised here, if ignored, risks causing more people to leave, leaving a weaker core userbase to deal with moderation. All hail Spam Overflow in that case. Voting is already low, yes, but making it _even lower_ with a "substitute" feature is not going to make it better. It instead pushes away the users that could be new core members by halting rep growth

Comment: This should be fairly obvious - reduced influx of new users with access to the relevant privileges, as well as more passive users and users leaving leads to a massive problem that no amount of clicking a "thanks" button will fix. A general sense of satisfaction doesn't give the privileges to help keep the site spam free and on-topic.

Comment: Additionally, mods are already more inactive than before. I've had a flag pending for about 20 days. You might now think that more mods are needed, but if more people get pushed away or prevented from becoming a mod, there's going to be no one left to run, and no one with motivation to deal with flags. Post quality and spam can always be handled by the community eventually, but diamond mod matters can't.

Comment: You say a second problem is voting, but  we aren't failing because users can't thank each other - as Andreas pointed out, we're failing to educate the new users on how the site works. Start addressing that instead of adding a useless "thanks" feature that only serves to take another hit at vote frequency.

Comment: @Zoe At this point you're writing so many comments they should be in an answer - please? I think most of what you're saying is not relevant to the post it's on but I'd hate to lose your PoV.

Comment: @Catija I'm not currently in a state of mind where that's a good idea. Besides, I got my point out there, and for now, that's good enough.

Comment: what's funny is SO ***wanted*** to get more and more new users. and now they are not happy with the results? funny.

Comment: @Catija *"Thousands of votes go uncounted every day from people trying and having their votes rebuffed because they lack the reputation."* I know, I know! let's abolish the reputation altogether!! (serious suggestion).

Comment: @WillNess There are people who have suggested getting rid of many things that we consider integral to our system - reputation, voting, comments, downvotes (only)... and... those are huge changes that would impact the entire ecosystem of the site, how we function, how we send signals to people about all sorts of things... quality, experience, accuracy, value... etc. This is a (relatively) small change that may yet have huge impact... If the reaction to reactions is like this, imagine the reaction to changing any of those!

Comment: @Catija by "serious" I meant "sardonic" as in "not even sarcastic at this point". "just shoot me" kind of "serious".

Comment: @WillNess The power of text based communication.

Comment: You overlooked one thing. - It's not the percentage of "*thanks*" comments, it's the percentage of comments with "*thank*" in it which were counted for the statistic. That's a big big difference and is not appropriate. Comments with "*thank*" in it can indeed have a sense. Only the comments which have the purpose to say "*Thank you*" should be counted. I explained that in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398422/12139179) as well.

Comment: @Catija From a user perspective: I will not even know that someone "thank"-ed me. At least with a comment, I will know (I can feel warm and fuzzy for a while..) and I can have it auto-removed. What's the point of thanking someone, if they never know? I for one will comment and explain to a new user that their tanks will never be seen by the person they're thanking.. because it's only right to inform people. And then what?.. maybe they go back to commenting and my comment is now also cluttering the pages adding to "unbelievably unnecessary".

Comment: @Catija ..most of my comments on this site is explaining to new users how this site works. If you could address that problem, that it's difficult to find the right information, then you'll have a lot less comments, at least from me. I find it to be somewhat counterproductive to add another feature that needs explaining. Adding a tooltip to a "thanks" in a comment in an answer, with a link to information, may very well reduce clutter. At least for those users who bothers to read the help. I'm not the only one that's saying this, but somehow I feel that not enough people are.

Comment: BTW, this new feature was mentioned 6 months ago. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339283/334566

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, on Twitter...

Comment: True, that's ... less than ideal. But at least we had the opportunity to discuss it on that MSE post I linked.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I think I must’ve missed that, or forgotten about it.

Comment: I would think people.

Comment: @PM2Ring Which nobody knew about because it wasn't [featured]. At least it didn't have a sign saying "Beware of the leopard."

Comment: @KevinB I _kind_ of like that idea. Occasionally I upvote an answer on an SE I'm not a part of (because I forget it goes to `/dev/null`). It'd be nice if those three people on Seasoned Advice got upvotes if I ever _did_ join, but the chances are slim. Here's the worry I have: it's going to provoke more cycles of battle between vote rings and vote-ring-detectors.

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky A few of us noticed it, and discussed it in chat rooms. The general reaction at the time was "Seriously?", but I guess we were fairly emotionally burnt-out at that stage, and didn't have great expectations towards anything coming from the company.

Comment: Can't we have a little warning that shows up when a comment is likely a thanks and say: "If you want to say thanks, please upvote the answer."

Comment: @Catija - "I understand your reaction but it also somewhat misses that a huge number of users don't have the 15 reputation needed to vote." - If they don't have the 15 reputation in order to vote on a contribution, they also don't have the reputation required, to submit a "thank you" comment.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm not sure I follow. There's no reputation required to use the thanks feature. All that's needed is an account.

Comment: @SecurityHound They can, if it's their Question. The reputation requirement for comments are on other users Question-threads.

Comment: @Scratte - So this is just for the question author?  What about everyone else that says “thanks” in a comment or an incorrectly submitted answer

Comment: @SecurityHound Sorry. I just responded to what seemed like an understand that no users < 15 could comment on anything. They can't vote, so I'm assuming the alternative for those users is to leave a "Thank you so much!"-comment. I don't know about the number of other users that leave this type of comment. But in my opinion it's a non-issue. One "No longer needed"-flag, and the comment is auto-removed.

Comment: As @DDiamond mentioned, can't we just have a warning when someone clicks the thanks button saying "If this answer helped you, please upvote the answer"?

Comment: "Content or People" -- the thing I like the least about this feature is that reactions are attributed to users. It just doesn't feel like it fits in with the rest of the site and it seems like it would be very easy to track users or figure out who voted for what.

Comment: @Zoe: thank you for using the word "clusterfuck" in a comment. I wonder how often "clusterfuck" is used in a comment, as compared to the uses of "thank you" in comments? "Clusterfuck" reminds me of the halcyon days of my youth. And, of course, it gave me the opportunity to use the phrase "thank you" (thrice! Thank you!) to screw with somebody's misuse of statistics. What a clusterfuck..!

Comment: I thought some people think that when they vote they will lose some rep just like to set a bounty that's why they use *thanks* instead

Answer (score 515):

Now that I'm calm and joking about it, let’s explain why this feature won't have the desired effect:

- People like to type "thanks". They like it so much that they type it as a tag to most posts.
- The buttons aren't prominent enough. This could have been addressed by the same tool-tip, no?
- There's a readily available solution: using [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) on the comments so that posts containing `th?anks?` are reminded to use the upvote button. ("Why this is included on the list?" you may ask: because current rejection of the feature should have been an expected effect, yet is not a desired one, and this solution was not only proposed, **SO already has content filter in comments, which was used for +/-1 comments.** See [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953) about it.)
- Anonymous users say tons of thanks already via upvotes. They represent at least 80% of all votes. Last time I checked, that number was about right, although these anonymous votes are not displayed and don't change anything on the website. It's functionally equivalent to this feature and invisible, yet users continue doing it.
- "Thanks" comes from people that already have access to the standard voting mechanism. Remember, commenting anywhere comes with a 50 reputation requirement, meanwhile upvoting just needs 15.
- Allowing yet another avenue for saying "thanks" erodes the message: if the post was useful for you, upvote it!

Comment: What do you mean by, "Anonymous users say tons of thanks already via upvotes, they represent at least 80% of all votes"? Aren't 100% of votes from authenticated users with 15+ votes? And, simultaneously, aren't 100% of votes "anonymous" in that their names aren't attached to their votes publicly?

Comment: @JeremyCaney when you aren't logged in and try to vote, those are called anonymous users votes. In sede it's on the table anonymous-feedback.

Comment: @Braiam: I had no idea! It seems weird to me that an anonymous user can upvote a post, but a low-reputation user can’t. I assume those anonymous votes don’t impact the contributor’s reputation?

Comment: As an aside, I wonder how many “Thank you” and “Me too” answers we could avoid by giving low-reputation users _some_ mechanism for expressing their views without resorting to abuse of the answer feature. To me, that’s also the best argument for the “Thank you” feature—though I’d rather just give them the opportunity to vote, even if it doesn’t yet count toward reputation. Sometimes people just need a way to feel heard, or to draw attention to a post or answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney too little. In a month, there are about 500k votes from anonymous users, about 1.5m from registered users that have the up and down vote privilege. I doubt the amount of post/comments deleted because they are "thanks" amount to a sizeable proportion of that.

Comment: @Braiam: Thank you. That helps put it into perspective. It’s easy for me to be myopic when I’m focused so narrowly on one small piece of contributions.

Comment: Don't forget that the regex should also cover "thx".

Comment: @RyanLundy a comment needs 15 characters at least, so "thx for your answer" is totally fair game :(

Comment: @RyanLundy our personal favorite is 'tanks in advance'

Comment: @TylerH Think of it as a Blitzkrieg of gratitude.

Comment: Don't forget about the usual: TFYH

Comment: @10Rep To post a comment you need at least 15 characters.

Comment: @Braiam Some people just spam exclamation marks.

Comment: The regular expression would also have to cover variations and deliberate and non-deliberate misspellings, like [*thans* and *thnx*](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html).

Comment: Your third bullet is so spot on and should be the main point. They totally should have added a thanks detection and make it so that the comment doesn't send if there's thanks written in it with a popup reminding to use up votes for thanking, and comments for whatever comments actually exist for.

Answer (score 273):

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers. Although it’s less common on questions, the percentage of “thanks” comments have continued to slowly increase over the last few years

Now in addition to the "thanks" in the comments (I doubt they will disappear), we will also have the like and I guess people will slowly forget the upvote and accept feature.

Not sure if it's a good initiative. Sounds like we are slowly converting this community to a social website.

> we're introducing this clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions.

If I had to say "thanks" then I should logically upvote the answer. Many people simply take the time to provide a *bad* or *wrong* answer. Why do I have to thank them for taking the time to answer?

---

People might also find me *impolite* because I didn't say thanks to someone who provided an answer to my question or I myself can feel upset because the OP didn't say *thanks* to my effort. Well, a lot of emotion for a website focused on  **content** and not **people**.

Comment: Would be nice if the thanks button also adds a upvote.

Comment: @BDL would be nice if we simply consider the upvote as the *thanks* action.

Comment: I am getting few thanks! but I got 2 with only 1 upvote, grrrr ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just had the same: 5 thanks and 2 upvotes. For a feature that is intended to remove frustrations, it's certainly very frustrating. Oh, wait. I forgot. The company doesn't really care about the frustrations of those who answer or moderate.

Comment: Can we get another icon to indicate "this answer is not useful"?

Comment: @10Rep you can make it a positive place by fixing a lot of issues we are raising each day not by adding extra stuff to make this place confusing. You are probably still new to this site but we want it to be a formal website focused on good quality content and there is no room for emotion and personnal stuff.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This feature is so frustrating!! I got a comment saying "thanks", and he didn't bother upvoting + accepting until I told him to. **And** he didn't even click the thanks button, proving this feature is uselss.

Comment: They already forget about it. I was helping out for only one single week(before this feature) to see what are the general issues in a specific area, the ppl dealing with. In this one single week I collected 500 points and I think 50-75% of the cases I got nothing, only accept or only one upvote. And sometimes I provided a very detailed answer or I answered additional questions too. I wasn't collecting points for years, and I can say this from experience that it's mostly a waste of time, because users doesn't respect your time you spend helping to them. This feature will make it even worse

Comment: Giving a thank you reaction without an upvote actually gives users who can't downvote a way to express their frustration with unhelpful answers in a relatively harmless way. It could also be used by higher rep users for frustrating but technically helpful answers. I don't think this use would do any more good to the site than the designed one, but should be considered.

Answer (score 240):

This definitely has the *potential* to send a lot of [phatic noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression) to ground with less effort and frustration than the current "delete thousands of comments" approach. So, I'm glad it's being tried.

That said, there are a few things y'all need to be watching for:

1. Reduction in voting

   This is the big one - voting is already far below where it should be, anything that further reduces it is a problem. This might show up as existing voters voting less, or folks who've newly earned the privilege not voting at all.
2. No reduction in "thank you" comments

   Obviously if the feature doesn't have the intended effect, it's a problem; 'nuff said!
3. *More* comments

   Any time you put a visible number somewhere, folks will fixate on it to a degree. *Hopefully* that doesn't happen here, but if it does... It could spill out into the comments. Be particularly alert for arguments or "PSAs" popping up - authors trying to address "thankers" or others complaining about them. There don't need to be a large volume of these for them to be a problem; as Jason has observed in the past, nasty comments tend to hang around for a long time, souring the mood for everyone.
4. Incongruous usage

   This is relatively minor, but... If the number of "thanks" doesn't correspond to other measures of usefulness for a post then there's probably something fishy going on... And not necessarily something wrong with this feature, even! Be on the lookout for this, and ready to investigate - anomalies in usage can tell you an awful lot about the behaviors you're working with!

There are probably ways to mitigate #1 & #3 if they do show up, but the longer you wait the harder it'll become to alter folks' usage patterns - so be alert & ready to jump in.

A few other things to consider for the future, if what's being tried now works out (or can be made to work):

1. It should be fairly trivial to detect when someone's posting a "thank you" comment (I had pretty good success with just a simple regex). Consider popping up a little warning pointing folks to the reaction button!
2. There are currently a fair number of "thank you" *answers* being posted & deleted - this might help reduce that too, but if not then consider warning on those as well.
3. Add it to questions, with "Good question", "Needs details" and "I have this question too" reactions - new users frequently lament that they're unable to provide feedback to askers (that their question is helpful or in need of clarification) or *potential* answerers (that an answer to a given question would be appreciated by folks other than just the asker).

Good luck!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krjxyEme5vM

Comment: you nailed it once again. IMO reduction in voting will be the main problem, new users don't know how to accept and upvote and don't even care, I've seen that on many many posts

Comment: Yeah; it's *already* a problem. In theory, a feature like this could be used to *correct* that problem - imagine a little pop-up tooltip telling folks who've earned the voting privilege that they can now vote in response to them using a reaction, thus making reactions effectively "training wheels" for voting! But... If the mere existence of the feature hurts voting, that'll have to be addressed first.

Comment: Since you had inside information and this was one of your babies: did you ever measured the effect of preventing +/-1 in comments? What were your findings?

Comment: Sure did, @Braiam - results here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953

Comment: Upvoted for "voting is already far below where it should be".

Comment: I guess I should link [Shog's own proposal on "reactions" in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309718/241919), which I highly supported...

Comment: _"training wheels" for voting_ -> sounds like a good idea to only let it be used from 1-X rep rather than forever in my opinion

Comment: Upvoted for "Be particularly alert for arguments or "PSAs" popping up". There are so many "This should be the accepted answer" comments around... Now there will be "Why is this answer getting all the thanks?!?"

Comment: I have the sense that _"Add it to questions, with 'Good question', 'Needs details' and 'I have this question too' reactions"_ is the most interesting positive statement on this topic.

Comment: Wouldn't "I have this question too" map to the existing "Watch this question" action? Maybe all we need is to provide friendly names to existing actions.

Comment: I seriously doubt this will have the desired effect because it doesn't address *why* people leave thanks comments. It's not because they want to leave an anonymous token of good will — it's because they want a **non-anonymous** way of saying thanks that makes a personal connection. They want 'credit' (for lack of a better term) for the gratitude. So long as the thanks button is anonymous, it's just a less-potent up vote.

Comment: It isn't anonymous, @mark - not in the way votes are at least. Buuuut... It isn't a direct, attributed message in the way that comments are either. Most importantly: none of this is obvious from the UI. That will probably be an issue.

Comment: Upvoted for allowing us all to learn about [phatic noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression)

Comment: _"Add it to questions, with "Good question", "Needs details" and "I have this question too" reactions"_ This would be interesting! For "good question" we already have the upvote, and I also upvote questions for "I have this question too". "Needs detail" right now is a downvote plus a comment. In this experimental idea, it would be interesting to also see an answer reaction of "this solved my problem", because that is a very specific sub-type of upvote.

Comment: Lotta forums have this two-step voting thing where you select a vote and then a reason... Personally, I find that infuriating, @nathan - but splitting it up, decoupling the "vote action" and "provide quick feedback" steps, that I dig.

Comment: @metacubed That's a reasonable point. People favorite/bookmark posts for all sorts of reasons. I have a few where I have the same question and all the current answers suck, but also a few where people keep reposting existing answers so I can keep an eye out to flag them.

Comment: This button serves no purpose whatsoever and I'm not even sure what counts as a success criterion: Do we want it to be clicked a lot? Or not at all? I suspect it fundamentally does not matter at all.

Comment: Hard to say, as there's no hard criteria here or on the blog @Sklivvz. It's an a/b test between two appearances of the same function, so the stuff I outline here can't be tested directly - but they can be observed. I'd be looking hard at the first two: interference with voting is a fail, *some* interference with comments could be considered a success (but, would need further research).

Comment: I thought of something which wanna share here since you suggested adding reactions to for users without voting privilege. Why not just let them use the same voting buttons but count them differently?! Instead of decreasing/increasing vote count on the post, up/downvote by newcomers can be counted towards number of thanks (or something similar). Count# can appear in the same place as this feature but it'd be still associated with voting buttons. This way, newcomers practice voting as well as being able to give feedback without commenting. Two birds, one stone.

Answer (score 234):

We already have a "thank you" button. It looks like this:

> [image: upvote]

Adding yet another button is only going to make things more confusing - and result in people "thanking" but not upvoting (or accepting) contributions - robbing people of their reputation points.

People already seem to find the concept of accepting and upvoting the answer that solves the question. Why are we making this more complicated?

Comment: I disagree that the upvote button is a thank you button. Upvoting means roughly "this answer is correct, high-quality, and relevant." "Thanks" means roughly "I appreciate the time you took out of your day to write this answer." The two concepts are correlated, but still independent.

Comment: I see what you're saying @TheGuywithTheHat - but does the ability to thank users for content that *isn't* high quality or relevant something that brings value to this site?

Comment: I think the distinction is important because I believe that it's the reason why there are so many "thanks" comments. People who are not used to the site want to say thanks, and don't see an upvote as a way to do that. I don't think that it's important for them to be separate actions, but I think it's important for there to be some way to convey both, regardless of how it's implemented. Before today, the only way to convey the second concept ("thanks") is to write a comment.

Comment: I'll be very interested to see if the presence of such a subtle button does anything to offset the "thanks" comments. But even if it did - I feel like a "use the upvote button!" when such a message is detected could be more useful to teach people how the site works...

Comment: Those who write incorrect answers also take their time out of their day. Do they deserve "thank you" as well?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes! If someone genuinely tried to help me IRL, I would thank them for their efforts regardless of whether their attempt succeeded. Here on stack overflow, someone who makes a bona fide attempt at an answer deserves thanks in my opinion. We have upvotes to reward quality and correctness. Thanks can be a reward for effort.

Comment: @TheGuy you can have your own opinion, but in my opinion misleading someone who is in need of help by providing wrong answers deserves no thanks, rather deserves punishment of some sort. Also such a "thanks" is no use for the site considering the purpose of the site, which is to have good quality answers to useful questions.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: I think The Guy with The Hat's point is that you can have well-meaning answers that might otherwise be correct, but miss the mark in some way, or really good, in-depth answers on a topic that end up falling out of date. (For example, some great answers to rules questions on RPG.SE were once correct, but were made wrong by errata.) I'm not saying the answer is to have a thanks emoji as post reactions, but as The Guy in The Hat points out, the meaning expressed of "this answer is correct, high-quality, and relevant" is not the same thing as "I appreciate the time/effort you spent".

Comment: (...All that said: I don't think the "thanks" emoji reaction is really the best solution to the issue, because I think a major reason why people leave "Thanks" comments is to personally express that sentiment to the answerer - and an emoji next to their post is expressing a fraction of that sentiment at best.)

Comment: You got me, I clicked that button. It just showed the image on a new page :(

Answer (score 216):

I was searching for an answer that already got a "thanks" to see how exactly it looks in practice.  First one I found:

[image]

So doesn't seem to work too well in preventing the comment.

Comment: you don't know who made the *thanks*, maybe it's not the OP

Comment: @TemaniAfif I actually do know (from the activity log) and in this case it was the OP.

Comment: Oh, so it's not anonymous. It makes this even worse as a feature ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think it makes sense that it is not anonymous if it is meant to replace non-anonymous comments. What I see as a problem is that it seems to be anonymous at first glance while it actually is not.

Comment: another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424251/8620333

Comment: So.. the thank you button was basically used **instead** of an accept?

Comment: @Scratte it was used in addtion to also saying thanks in the comment which defeat the purpose of having such useless button

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes. I see that. But I also see a missing green check-mark. Of course, I do not know which post this is, so it may have another accepted answer.

Comment: you can see the person who thanks in the timeline.

Comment: @Scratte I did not notice that when posting but you're right... It is so far the only answer to that question. (sorry for not linking but I don't want to draw unnecessary meta attention to some random question).

Comment: And I decided to answer a question in my break and now we have another example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447886/2209007

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks for contributing to SO; have an upvote for your valuable effort.

Comment: You're welcome. But tbh I don't really do it for the upvotes. It just showed to me that the solution that SO implemented is not an actual solution to the problem of a shared comment section between people being nice human beings to each other and comments adding to the answer itself, which is something this post outlines as well.

Comment: Thank you for this post! In addition to making the polite human gesture of _saying thanks_ I also made sure to upvote. Sometimes as programmers we tend to think anything should and could be improved. Much like the proverbial hammer user that sees everything as a nail (a.k.a [Law of the Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument), look it up it's relevant!), a programmer can end up seeing everything as a button.

Comment: Clearly, this "feature" is an abject failure.

Answer (score 184):

Bad feature. Confusing. Will cause users to skip upvoting.

My suggestion - detect when users write "thanks" in comments and instruct on how to upvote.

Consider even <strike>making the upvote reputation requirement 0 (so all users could upvote)</strike>

[image]

Comment: all users could upvote isn't a great idea. We have enough work with sock puppets with 15 being the limit. Otherwise, you're right.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question. what is sock puppets?

Comment: not a dumb question: people who create alternate account(s) just to vote for their main account. Happens a lot... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)

Comment: Because fake internet points mean something! (i've never quite understood the obsession with them/why people create fake accounts to upvote themselves)

Comment: it also grants privileges, like comments, downvotes, deletion.... more powerful spammers.

Comment: Or upvotes from those with under 15 rep could be like the upvotes of anonymous visitors (ie, they don't give rep to the recipient.)

Comment: I will thank you if you remove your final paragraph!

Comment: @curiousdannii That'd still become "potential earnings" as (many) people tend to vote on high-score posts.

Comment: 'Fake internet points' looks good on resume

Comment: @Caius Jard: Minimum-effort HR people use fake Internet points as a filter (so they don't have a review what is *actually* posted (at least before the filter is applied)). So naturally minimum-effort job applicants will try to game the system.

Comment: @PeterMortenson hah, yeah I often wondered about that too.. "Would I hire Jon Skeet? - Nah; he probably spends way too much time on stackoveflow to *actually* do any work, right?" 

Answer (score 158):

It's a step in a wrong and scary direction. This would be the beginning of seeing the icons below on SO:

[image]

<sub>***We've already seen terrifying examples on [Teams](https://www.lisahpark.com/reactions) and [Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383038/add-reasoning-on-what-the-job-reactions-mean).***</sub>

Stating the obvious:

- Stack Overflow is not a social network site.<sup>1</sup>
- **Generally speaking,** downvoting and upvoting do not indicate being mean or nice. Most importantly, they are ways to reflect the quality of posts.<sup>2</sup>

---

---

Let's assume an answer which is not a quality one nor is the correct answer  to be qualified for upvotes or getting accepted. In the meantime, it's not an awful answer which you would downvote. If anything, you actually appreciate the effort.

***So, that's when you use this new feature?!***

#### No.

I think the right thing to do is leaving a comment to explain the issues that you see with that answer. Of course, you can thank the user. There's nothing wrong with saying *'thank you'* in a comment (but not just saying *"thank you"*).

---

---

<sub>1.  [David Arenburg's explanation on why SO differs from typical social networking platforms.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398410#comment776179_398410)</sub>

*"... SO initially was focusing on the content (a high quality data base), rather on people (a social network). People on SO can't make connections, send private messages, say "thank you" and etc. The comments section wasn't meant for that neither. The chat rooms are the closest thing to a social network, but they were mostly intended (I think) for extended discussion and clarifications in order not to clutter the comments section - certainly not to what certain chatrooms became eventually. That new feature focuses on people rather on content."*

---

---

<sub>2. Addressing some comments on this point of mine: Generally speaking, downvoting and upvoting do not indicate being mean or nice.</sub>

**Comment:**

*"This is something obvious to you, and to most people who "succeed" (by some measure) on Stack Overflow. But I would suggest that it's not obvious to every newcomer that upvotes/downvotes are supposed to be impersonal evaluations of the question/answer's utility. Having social-network-style colorful cutsie reactions might emphasize the impersonality of voting."*

**My response:**

I understand your point of view but to solve a problem, one should not create another. Problems with this "cutsie" reactions are laid out in most of the answers here. We can emphasize on these actions being impersonal evaluations in other, much less problematic, ways; again, refer to suggestions here.

In the meantime, your concern is mostly about downvotes and being nice, etc., while this feature is a try to reduce thanks comments which are different issues (there may be relations, but we should not deviate from the actual purpose of this feature). And I want to say that a colorful UI would be the end of SO. Even imagining finding answers in a website cluttered with all kind of noise is painful. I am not giving this much thought, but maybe SO can hide the actual number of downvotes for newcomers on their posts and cap it at -1, but notify them that there's an issue with the quality of their post causing negative feedback. Even giving them a grace period on reputation loss. We had an experiment like this before, but it was for all the users and not just newcomers. Again, this is something off the top of my head and not directly related to this post.

We all can (should) sit and discuss different ways to make our communities more welcoming. Although, I want to point out that majority of SE users are trying their best to be nice and welcoming but I understand that some standard actions may have a harsher impact on newcomers. We don't need to obliterate what we built to address any issue. Through discussion, we can find better methods to decrease number of "thank you" comments, improve newcomers experience, and any other issue.

Specifically about this feature, **I believe that community has spoken and showed that they are not fond of this. Obviously, downvotes on the announcement are not targeting the SO employee or the company. We are simply expressing that this feature is problematic in our eyes.**

Comment: "They are just ways to reflect the quality of posts." But they also give or take rep from the contributor. If that isn't an implied thank you or don't thank you, I don't know what is. Voting is also thanking. Of course SO is not such a social network as the others and having all these buttons to react to a contribution would be terrible.

Comment: +1. *Stack Overflow is not a social network site*

Comment: *"Stack Overflow is not a social network site."*- welp, once it was true. These days, the following is more accurate- *"SO is whatever SO management wants it to be at the moment"*. In other words, there is no common truth about what is SO at any given moment.

Comment: I'm curious about your definition of social network... Isn't SO one, and from the very beginning? (even though specialized for developers, pros and enthusiasts). (Not saying that SO should look like "well-known canonical examples of social networks"). It's a place where users exchange information / discuss, among other interactions.

Comment: @Pac0 it means that SO initially was focusing on the *content* (a high quality data base), rather on *people* (a social network). People on SO can't make connections, send private messages, say "thank you" and etc. The comments section wasn't meant for that neither. The chat rooms are the closest thing to a social network, but they were mostly intended (I think) for extended discussion and clarifications in order not to clutter the comments section - certainly not to what certain chatrooms became eventually. That new feature focuses on *people* rather on *content*.

Comment: I know several social networks where you can't make connections or direct messages. But indeed, the point that this feature is focused on people rather than on content is horribly true.

Comment: The idea to imagine of Stack Overflow as social media platform is awful. I'm not a fan of social media, either. Adding such features would ruin the seriousness and credibility of this site.

Comment: @Trilarion I shouldn't have said "just".

Comment: I'm not sure whether to upvote since I agree with you, or downvote since that potential future UI is scary. :-(

Comment: This is a slippery slope criticism. And it's fine to make this criticism, but I really don't see this change as going in this direction at all. While we should expect it to evolve, Stack Overflow isn't exactly slippery.

Comment: @AaronHall Not sure I follow what you mean. I always appreciated your feedback. Care to elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: [Been there, done that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383038/add-reasoning-on-what-the-job-reactions-mean).

Comment: @AaronHall: Most of us already see the current change as having gone down half the slope :-(

Comment: @AaronHall That's exactly what all comments and answers are trying to say. Rolling out such features unannounced has been going on for a long time now.

Comment: @AaronHall Also, https://www.lisahpark.com/reactions ???

Comment: _Stating the obvious: ... **Generally speaking**, downvoting and upvoting do not indicate being mean or nice. They are ways to reflect the quality of posts._ This is something obvious to you, and to most people who "succeed" (by some measure) on Stack Overflow. But I would suggest that it's not obvious to every newcomer that upvotes/downvotes are supposed to be impersonal evaluations of the question/answer's utility. Having social-network-style colorful cutsie reactions might emphasize the impersonality of voting.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I understand your point of view but to solve a problem, one should not create another. Problems with this "cutsie" reactions are laid out in most of the answers here. We can emphasize on these actions being impersonal evaluations in other, much less problematic, ways (like renaming the buttons that [T.S.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398389/6461462) suggested).

Comment: @ZevSpitz In the meantime, your comment is mostly about downvotes and being nice, etc., while this feature is a try to reduce thanks comments (totally different issues). And I want to say that a colorful UI would be the end of SO. Even imagining finding answers in a website cluttered with all kind of noises is painful. I am not giving this much thought, but maybe don't show the OP (if they are newcomers) actual number of downvotes and cap it at -1 (we had an experiment like this before), but notify them that there's an issue with the quality of their post causing negative feedback.

Comment: @ZevSpitz We all can sit and discuss so many ways to make our communities more welcoming. I want to point out though that majority of SE users are trying their best to be nice but I understand that some standard actions may have a harsher impact on newcomers. But we don't need to obliterate what we built to address one issue. As I said, we can discuss and find the best way. Specifically about this feature, community has spoken. Downvotes here are not targeting the SO employee or the company. We are simply expressing that this is problematic in our eyes. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I quoted your comment in the answer; I should've asked before doing so, but let me know if you are not okay with that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is my favorite kind of social networking site -- it's anti-social, just like me. These thank you buttons feel like social interactions are now desired, and I'm not a fan.

Answer (score 126):

I don't really care or feel strongly about this feature, but again, I (still) just want this question answered:

**When will Stack Overflow the company actually start to discuss new features with the community *before* releasing them live on the main site out of the blue?**

The company has been talking non-stop about how important community involvement is, from last autumn and beyond. Numerous posts have been made about this from October until today, by Sara Chipps, David  Fullerton, Prashanth Chandrasekar and Teresa Dietrich.

And yet you keep dumping poorly considered features on top the community, out of the blue, over and over. Not even on a test server or meta, but live on the main flagship site Stack Overflow, with no prior discussion. The recent fiasco with showing random links to other random SE sites was also deployed just like this reaction feature.

Notably, these features weren't on Teresa's roadmap either. So who is actually in charge of development on the site? Random devs can develop & release new features at their own whims and initiatives?

Comment: To just make a stand: "*Thank you*". ;-)

Comment: I'd thank this post, but alas.. the feature isn't implemented on meta ;)

Comment: While I don't like this feature either, I also don't see any problem with testing it this way to see what effect it has. This sort of thing can't be tested on a test server, since there would be no users, and is testing on meta is pointless since most meta users know better than to leave thank you comments in the first place.

Comment: I don't really agree. SO is not owned by the community. It's not an open-source project, it's privately owned. It would be nice to see a roadmap of upcoming features and to be involved in discussing which ones are worthwhile, but this high-level stuff is for SE to decide ultimately. They can consult and still implement something that isn't popular too

Comment: @Mr.Boy Of course they can do whatever they like, but then _kindly stop lying to my face about caring about community feedback_.

Comment: @Lundin caring about feedback doesn't mean they have to run everything past you for permission. You can give feedback on the features during the trials. If a feature isn't a lot of work then they migth as well trial it.

Comment: @Mr.Boy How exactly does `analysis -> design -> implementation -> test -> user feedback ->  discard` make sense compared to `analysis -> user feedback -> discard`? Companies shouldn't care about time, money and disappointed customers? So if I run a travel company, I should silently send the plane travelling from NY->LA to Rome, Italy instead? Because it's a popular tourist destination so the customers ought to appreciate the silent change of destination. If they don't like it, we can always book them on another plane back. It's my company after all, I send the planes where I like.

Comment: Depends how much work is involved. Sometimes implementing a feature is quicker than talking about it.

Comment: And whether they think it's worthwhile use of their money and resources is precisely the kind of thing that's not the community's concern.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yep, sending all my passengers to Italy instead of LA was no effort at all, I just gave the pilot an order. Therefore it was a good call. The extra fuel cost is on me, none of their concern.

Comment: There were experiments before, and you know which were met without instant rejection: the ones that say "hey there, we would be doing these changes tomorrow, cool?"

Comment: I like their approach personally, _it's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission_. I'm happy for them to try things out, as long as they react quick enough and take feedback into account (which they seem to do well so far). On the "thank" subject, I don't understand what would make me click "thank" instead of "upvote", a rather confusing and superfluous feature in my opinion.

Comment: @sp00m The main issue here is upper management of the company saying one thing then doing another, over and over. Where is the community involvement? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 120):

In your analysis will you please share the effect these thanks have on downvotes.

My gut feeling is that users that see a "thanks" on a post are less likely to cast a downvote and if that is true then we lose an important quality mechanism that is already much under pressure. An UX that further discourages the brave voters is a trend I do not fancy.

That can be a quantitative analysis based on some number crunching.

Can you also consider in your analysis the "new" comments that will pop-up (who downvoted my thanked post, who thanked without upvoting) as well as Meta Posts where the most die hard fans of old-style Stack Overflow have to discuss with / support users that are faced with this new feature.

That can be part of a qualitative analysis of the effects of the new feature.

If you can include and combine this with the approach, data-points and analysis you've already planned I'm sure we can both reach a fair conclusion about this new feature at the end of the test period.

Comment: WUT? 4 upvotes, no thanks?

Comment: They could solve the problem of "why this and not that" by making reactions exclusively available to only <15 rep and anons. But one thing you're on point, this needs more investigation (it's pretty half-baked atm).

Comment: @cs95 That would render it completely useless, since at that reputation level, you can cast upvotes.

Comment: I wish I could thank that answer more than once.

Comment: We need a "a brave voter" badge.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Something to relieve the otherwise uneventful lives of our Moderators: You can now go out looking for Thanking Rings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre out of curiosity: are moderators notified internally before a feature is implemented/released? or they are *surprised* like us?

Comment: we got notified an hour before that post came up, and we definitively weren't consulted.

Comment: I was surprised way more than you, @TemaniAfif. No, we were not consulted in any way.

Comment: @Spevacus Thank you for those lovely thanks.

Comment: The analysis is wrong regarding another point:  It's not the percentage of "*thanks*" or "*Thank you*" comments, it's the percentage of comments with "*thank*" in it which were counted for the statistic. That's a big big difference and is not appropriate. Comments with "thank" in it can indeed have a sense. Only the comments which have the purpose to say "Thank you" should be counted. I explained that in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398422/12139179) as Critical Addendum as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre We were given advanced notice on this new feature 6 months ago, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339283/334566

Comment: And it was rightfully ignored so far. But fair enough. Personally I'd prefer more useful features like ... more winter hats.

Comment: I oppose the "thanks" feature, but if a person is discouraged from down-voting upon noticing many "thanks", then - that person is rethinking their position. That's not a bad thing in itself. So -1 on this answer.

Comment: Thanks rene. I kinda want to downvote this to emphasize on the importance of downvotes :)

Answer (score 119):

Just rename the actions:

1. "Accept answer" to "Accept answer and thank"
2. "Upvote answer" to "Upvote and thank"

Problem solved

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: also "Downvote but thank"

Comment: Can we rename the close flag to "thanks for trying"?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "Downvote and thank for nothing"

Comment: @MartinBraun If you're going that way then "Downvote and thanks but no, thanks"

Comment: Even "Upvote and thanks, but no, thanks" could be useful, when you eventually realize you should work on X, instead of Y.

Comment: Ultimately, just remove the vote buttons and have "thank you/"thanks but no" buttons instead. The first one gives you a certain amount of kudo's, the second one takes them away. With more "Thanks!" you can comment, edit, moderate ... Hey, wait a minute ...

Comment: @usr2564301 "Thanks, I hate it"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Also "Vote to delete and thanks". Plus "Upvote but no thank" and "Accept answer but no thank".

Comment: If they rename it this way, more people will be motivated to _add_ a thank you comment, because someone is telling them to "thank". So -1.

Answer (score 118):

[image]

Neither of these really seems a very good 'applause' icon. The left looks more like a "wash your hands" reminder. The right is clearly praying to me.

I rarely thank people by applauding them, come to think of it. If you must, then 'thumbs up' is the conventional 'like' icon on forums and Facebook and pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Yes I thought its the prayer emoji  

Comment: Honestly, the left one looks to me like doing the hand signal for "timeout" (forming a "T" by placing the hands perpendicular to each other)

Comment: I've seriously thought the left icon would symbolize "wash your hands" due to the Corona pandemic.

Comment: When I saw the right icon in it's tiny grayed out form the first time, it looked to me like the middle finger signal. I couldn't work out why Stack would put such a thing there.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, the right icon is the praying emoji. It does look like an high-5. Which may be why it was used in this experiment. I can foresee the religion-focused websites having troubles with it. Not that they will be angry. But would be pretty weird to have a praying emoji on a question. Would it mean that you're going to pray for the answerer? For the questioner? For both?

Comment: Clapping hands: 

Comment: Alternatives: ❤️  ✨    ‍♂️ . Last one is my favorite.

Comment: Never knew you could put emoticons in comments. That seems a bad feature too!

Comment: @Scratte Merry Christmas everyone.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I saw it once again before by new users in "*Thank you*" comments. IMHO it's inappropriate. But that would be a whole entire thing on its own to discuss. I guess they implemented it for chat rooms.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I don't use them on main at all. I agree. I think it's too flashy. And since I don't support this new feature, my comment here is really just meant as a joke. Though, I'd still vote for Father Christmas ;) However, the new feature seems to be an attempt for users to send a warm fuzzy feeling, perhaps the red heart. I'm divided.. :/

Comment: That robot is so childish, I almost will it's condescending :/

Comment: Yes, I like that so much thought went into this feature, they didn't even bother to find out the names of the chosen emoji. This is next-level hooliganism! ;)

Comment: Thumbs up or something similarly neutral should be used. Not a fan of religious icon.

Comment: I mean I'm a fan of praying but even so I don't know it's appropriate here :)

Comment: My first thought when seeing these icons was "This code is so bad that I'm washing my hands of it" and "This code hasn't been tested, so pray it works".  Come to think of it, those might actually be useful buttons to have ...

Comment: My theory is, there are 2 arbitrary icons offered in order to avoid a downvote pounding by trying to close the sale on a minor point / alternative choice.

Comment: I saw something different and indecent when it appeared below my answer, not praying, but something much worse. It is a very small icon.

Comment: Pray that we don't muck up your site any more.

Comment: My first thought when I saw the  icon with a tooltip saying it was a thanks button was that it was supposed to mean something like "God bless you for helping me".

Comment: Either a thumbs up or an upwards pointing arrow...

Comment: I'm not fond of the icons or the feature, but I guess the 'folded hands'  here are supposed to symbolize the Japanese thank you, similar to Indian 'namaste'

Comment: Agreed. The silhouette of the left icon is very unreadable at small sizes. The already standard clapping hands emoji  provides a much more familiar and arguably more readable applause icon.

Comment: I would take the one on the right to mean "I pray for anyone who tries to make use of this answer".

Comment: Ah yes..... Now I can pray to a random guy on the internet

Answer (score 102):

### I do not consider this feature as useful. In fact, the opposite is the case: I think it is harmful for the whole community.

It will automatically lead to that users will use the upvote feature less than before (the thing you wanted to improve). If you can express your agreement with a hand sign already, why would you upvote then?

You can deny it or not - one main reason why people answer questions is to gain reputation, since it is still treated as kind of currency around the sites (e.g. you need to have X reputation points to gain Y privilege, etc.).

And if you haven't got the possibility to get something a least little back, then why would you consider to make an answer?

I see this problematic for me as answerer as equal as questioner.

Of course, helping an OP is the main goal. But it is just a good appeal to write an answer, if you can get more from it.

I'm just honest. Don't beat me for that.

Sometimes I sit on an answer for about 2 to 3 hours including research, etc. (yes, it's true). And the only thing I get is a useless hand sign?

This probably will have an indirectly influence on that fewer answers will be posted and the OP will probably miss important information, either explicitly or implicitly related, which is bad.

---

If you think an answer is useful and you like it, then just upvote it. We don't need symbols to express "*You did it well, honey*" and "*Thank you for your effort*". We aren't kids at the playground.

For the reason of that new user don't be able to vote, I clearly say:

15 reputation points is low enough to be able to use upvotes and has its sense that no bot or sock puppet accounts can cast upvotes. No need for frivolous symbols.

---

### Critical Addendum regarding your stats:

Your statistic is saying

> "*Percent of comments on Stack Overflow with "thank" in them.*"

Well, I usually do that, too. But I do always express further question(s) or critic(s) in these comments as well.

It is not appropriate to count *all* comments with "*thank*" or "*thanks*" or "*Thank you*" in them. You need to only count the comments which are useless and have the only purpose to say "Thank you", not the ones who serve a real purpose and make sense.

So, IMHO the statistic is tainted and can't be used to reason this feature.

---

#### It even does not work in practice:

To showcase that the feature does not work as expected in practice, I've created another separate [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398487/12139179). I want to clearly separate both concerns from each other.

Comment: "Critical Addendum regarding your stats" I posted an answer asking for the length of the comments that contain thanks and how many of these are deleted.

Comment: @Braiam AFAIU the max. length doesn't matter. They counted all comments which contain literally just "*thank*" and of course are equal or beyond the minimum character limit for a comment. Good concerns in your answer BTW.

Comment: Cool - 5 more comments with Thank(s) in them _that have nothing to do with or could be replaced by_ clicking a clapping hand

Comment: @PatrickArtner This seems to be the plain and sad true, indeed.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio We are talking about the minimum length. "Thanks but <lengthy explanation on why it doesn't work>" is more useful than "thanks, it worked"

Comment: @Braiam I meant the same thing. That is what I meant also in the answer. Maybe my wording in the previous comment was ambiguous or incorrect. I apologize. But that does not change what I meant. As far as I did understand it with "Percent of comments on Stack Overflow with "thank" in them.", the length doesn't matter at all. Each and every comment containing "thank" is considered in the statistic, which is wrong.

Comment: I guess `includes "thank" and excludes "but"` (maybe also excludes "though") would be much more accurate.

Comment: @Stephan Every comment including "Why", "But", "How", "Where", "When", "What", "Though", "Although", "Despite", "In which way" as well as of course the "?"  sign by default and comments above a certain threshold of characters should be excluded. Maybe 50. Such algorithm shouldn't be too hard to develop. Thus, I don't understand why they used it that way.

Comment: And here is the evidence supporting it all https://stackoverflow.com/a/62479801/1704458

Comment: this is good answer.

Answer (score 101):

## You're focusing on the wrong group.

100% of people who can leave thank you comments, provided they're not OP of the question or the answer it's posted on, can also vote. The comment privilege is unlocked at 50 rep. Upvoting is unlocked at 15.

In the comments [on a different post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398369/6296561), Catija pointed out something we already knew, and have known for a long time; lots of people don't vote, even if the post helps. Do you maybe now see where the problem is?

People aren't properly educated on how to use the site. That's why we're getting tons of NAAs and off-topic questions - the systems aren't good enough to properly educate the good-faith posters, the people who look at posts and then don't vote, even if it helps. Adding a thanks feature only risks distracting from votes. To quote the [tour](/tour):

> Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.
> The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.

What about posts with 3000 thanks, but has 2 upvotes and has been locked there for a few years? Is that good or bad?

By further distracting from the already semi-forgotten-about voting system, people risk getting less and less rep. Personally, I don't care. I have well over 20000 rep, and got all the privileges of any importance that can be gained through rep.

And before I end this section, as I said, most people who write "thank you" comments also have access to voting. Why do you think they write "thanks" comments instead of upvoting?

I actually have no idea, but that's an idea of something to look into, instead of focusing on a parallel voting feature that likely will end up being ignored and result in no fewer "thank you" comments.

## You're screwing new users instead.

*Everyone* on this site had 1 or 101 rep (association bonus) at some point. How are you going to explain to new users that they're not getting rep because people are thanking too much instead of voting? And how are you going to deal with the site systems when users are struggling even more to get rep?

I'm concerned about new users who want to make contributions to the site. I'm concerned about the users who have just unlocked their first queues and would like to do more. This change risks turning away future moderators because they can't get enough rep. This has several horrible effects thanks to previous issues thanks to your (= Stack Overflow, to be clear, not the announcer. I try not shooting the messengers) actions.

We're already losing core users to Codidact, Topanswers, other sites, other services, or just outright leaving without a "replacement". If you push away future mods now by denying them rep needed for privileges, the only thing you'll get is Spam Overflow. 20000 thanks means absolutely nothing if you're still stuck at 553 rep, but want to contribute towards moderation of the site.

Admittedly, it was already bad, and it's hard getting upvotes. Some tags have different voting cultures as well, but adding a rep-less "thanks" feature isn't going to help. [Stop wasting your time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398371/6296561) and focus on what really matters. The problem isn't that users can't upvote, it's that they're not getting the proper introduction to the site. 15 rep is relatively easy to get, and it's even possible to get without posting (through suggested edits).

On one hand, you claim the reason for this is comments, but also that it's to help new users interact with the site. The problem is that you can also get users who now focus on that button instead of upvoting. [People already don't know about the accept feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398466/6296561) in spite of it being outlined in the tour.

We also get posts here on meta on a somewhat regular basis complaining about downvotes, and how downvote feedback should be mandatory. Some of these also directly state they feel insulted by the downvotes. We've been over that topic so many times, and stated that downvotes aren't personal. People don't get the message. Adding another feature means another thing to keep in mind, and another thing to teach users about. If you can't get people to understand and properly use the existing features, that is NOT a sign you should add another parallel feature - that's a sign you need to add more documentation, and get people to understand the site.

I still agree some things need to change in the voting area, but this is not it. Instead of helping with the vote issue, you're solving a different problem that can easily be solved by motivated users, and making the vote issue worse. If you want to solve the "thanks" comment problem, focus on the comments, NOT how to best distract users by giving them alternatives.

The alternative to posting a "thanks" comment is upvoting. If you also introduce thanking, which is a meaningless gesture the way it's implemented, there's now two alternatives to "thanks" comments. If you don't document them, most users won't use it anyway, and keep posting "thanks" comments.

> This feature is available to all registered users, regardless of reputation (unlike voting, which is only available for users with 15 reputation or more).

Voting has always been available to everyone. Only those with 15 or more rep change the score and award rep. Upvotes and downvotes without enough rep is still stored, and the resulting score is [shown to 10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback). From a rep point of view, both these features are equally useless. They don't give rep, they don't notify the poster, and the gesture is equally empty. **A general sense of satisfaction doesn't grant moderation privileges.**

## Your statistics are wrong

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers

Thank you for pointing that out. See what I did there?

People use "thanks" in different forms for all kinds of things. Here's one random example I just made up:

> Thanks, but this doesn't address the issue. <400 more characters explaining why>

That isn't a "thank you" comment even if it contains "thanks". Some people also use "thanks" as a salutation, and some times, people talk meta about "thanks" in comments on main.

## In summary,

This feature will most likely result in:

- Less voting (thanking doesn't count as a vote)
- Less rep growth
- Fewer users who can get the rep to become a core user

  - Couple arbitary time units down: more spam, less moderation on the site. All hail Spam Overflow
- Wasted time on a feature that has no impact on the biggest problems the site faces
- No decrease in "thanks" comments
- Increase in duplicates to this question on meta
- Increased confusion

... instead of educating users on how the site works, increasing voting, and reducing the moderator workload.

Bhargav has done a fantastic job on dealing with NAAs, but how much time do you think goes into that? I have a SEDE query that tracked down regex-matches "thank you" comments with a very high precision. Those don't hit the moderator workload - the hundreds of NAA answers posted on the site daily, however, do.

I also flagged a lot of NAAs until I decided to stop in protest of SE's actions. One of the things I often saw was "I'm new, I didn't know I couldn't post a question as an answer" (intent-wise - not a direct quote because there were a lot of comments like that). [Here's a selection of 100 comments containing "new to stackoverflow"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1253224/1542489/) (slowpoke DB; getting more rows causes slow results or a timeout).

I have no idea what scale comments asking about site features are on, but there are a lot. That is a problem - not being able to thank people without 15 rep isn't in comparison.

Around the time [the ask question wizard was made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/6296561), someone somewhere suggested an answering wizard, with the intent of cutting down NAAs and improving answer quality. That was ignored and never implemented. The answering experience, compared to the asking experience, is horrible.

While I'm trying to stress how important educating new users is, let's go back to voting; people seeing downvotes as unwelcoming can lead to them viewing the entire site as unwelcoming. If you properly teach people that downvotes aren't personal, and that they don't mean "this post is bad, and you should feel bad about yourself", you reduce some of it.

To draw a bit of a parallel, the first time you join a site or look at something, it can be terrifying. It's like a complicated game - the first time you look at it and get started, nothing makes sense or has any form of logic. When you get used to it, and learn how it works (for instance through a tutorial), it doesn't seem as horrible. Stack Overflow is the game. The tutorial is the thing you neglected to implement properly. The end result is what you're not getting.

Stack has problems, and they need to be fixed. This "feature" doesn't help.

Comment: "*Why do you think they write "thanks" comments instead of upvoting?*" - There's two things here... yes, to this but... also is it actually instead of... What percentage do both? As to why, the general understanding I have is that people like having a way to actually thank a person who helps them. They like being able to be recognized as having shown appreciation - this can be cultural or personal... but it definitely exists. I'm predisposed to saying "I'm sorry", others are predisposed to saying "thanks"... and it means something to be appreciated.

Comment: That said, what means the most to me when receiving thanks is when someone is specific about what I did that helped them. So, based on that alone, a general "thanks" reaction would be unlikely to be as impactful as someone taking the time to write a comment saying "*Thank you so much for your detailed and thoughtful answer - and for taking the time to post it so that everyone can appreciate it*".

Comment: I absolutely agree that doing a better job at teaching users about privileges, particularly voting, is something we need to do, and soon. We've started more training based on privilege unlocks - currently it's rolled out as we release updates to existing tools or release new ones - for example, the new info boxes for close reviewing and the one for the follow tool. As you say, I'm very concerned that voting is so low as it is and it leaves so many people feeling unrewarded for their efforts.

Comment: I would like to push back a bit on the downvotes thing. I know that downvotes aren't personal - I was a user for years before being hired and I've gotten my fair share of downvotes before and since... mostly since... but, as much as we repeat this mantra and tell people "it's not personal"... it will never actually be not personal to people. I have nearly 1000 downvotes on a single post and the only thing that keeps me from not dwelling on every single one is because I don't get notifications for every single one... I only see that it's been downvoted yet again when my rep change is +8.

Comment: I know it's easy to say "it's not personal" but that doesn't make it not hurt. If you spend time making something and later find it wrapped around a piece of gum and thrown it in the trash, it hurts! Even if you don't know who threw it away or why. Even if you're five and it was a really ugly piece of spaghetti art. Every question (ok, most) represents someone who is stuck with a problem. Even if they don't take the downvote personally as a downvote... they do take their post being downvoted or closed personally because it's preventing them from getting a solution to their problem.

Comment: All that is to say... I don't see that we could ever "train" new users to not take downvotes personally. We can help them get more specific guidance on how to write great questions or answers in a number of ways to prevent those downvotes from ever happening... we could do more with mentoring or a sandbox phase where people can workshop their posts... but I don't think that teaching people to not be hurt is something we should be leaning on - ever. It's not a "winning" solution.

Comment: @Catija I think you're focusing on the wrong thing here. We're not suppose to train people to not feel hurt about the fact that their work wasn't good. We're suppose to train them in how to use the site **and** that a downvote means that they need to work on how to make better contributions. If no one tells them how to or what's expected of them, they just keep failing and that's not very motivating. They need: Better guidance and less confusion. They need a Stack Overflow tutorial!

Comment: @Scratte I agree that a better tutorial ("better" because the tour is... at least in the most minor away a tutorial) would be amazing. I still don't think that we will ever get the majority of people comfortable with getting downvotes and that the better goal is helping them better avoid getting downvotes by doing a better job with creating better posts from the outset. (And before anyone accuses me of planning to get rid of downvotes - I have zero interest in that in 99% of cases)

Comment: @Catija The tour is not a tutorial. It's a brief introduction. There are also no warnings about all the ways that things can go wrong if one does't pay attention. Example: I have to actually explain to users that they only have **one** chance for the edit-into-the-reopen queue in comments directed at one user at a time! It doesn't scale, and for all those that do not get one-to-one hands-on advice, it's a less than optimal experience for a user to have to go through the help center to find out just what they need to do. Do they need to read all the pages? Can they focus on just 3? Which 3?

Comment: "We're not suppose to train people to not feel hurt about the fact that their work wasn't good" - I don't think we should either. It sucks when it's not good enough, but the point is to take it as feedback on the post, and not as an insult. " have nearly 1000 downvotes on a single post and the only thing that keeps me from not dwelling on every single one is because I don't get notifications for every single one.." - but does every downvote have the same effect as an outright toxic comment? Some people associate those two, and that's what I keep trying to push back against.

Comment: Is it possible to detect text selection? If it is you could suggest people who do select text or click links in an answer to upvote it. The time spent on reading an answer could also be used to make that suggestion. There are many ways to "teach" new users how you want them to behave. Voting is not very warm and welcoming I guess that's why people prefer to "talk" and say thank you. That makes total sense to me.

Comment: @cglacet It is, but if it ends up being too intrusive, all that will happen is that someone will make a userscript or a uBlock rule that nukes the popup. [Banner blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness) is also a major issue. They should be running research on the best way to resolve that, preferably by educating instead of nagging (ref. banner blindness), but we instead get a useless "thanks" feature with no impact.

Comment: @Catija Maybe the new feature should be enabled only for users who don't have permission to vote?

Comment: I don't feel it would be too intrusive because it would only show a few times (maybe 2-3) so the new user is aware of the "rule". It's like a dynamic tutorial.

Comment: @cglacet we also technically have this already. There's a banner on the top of the page that shows up for low-rep users from time to time saying (roughly; from memory): "Welcome back! Don't forget to upvote helpful posts". Its impact is apparently minimal.

Comment: Our eyes are used to ignore static content, I don't recall seeing this one in particular so I couldn't tell. But I'm pretty sure a small and dynamic message is more noticable than a big static banner

Comment: It only shows for low-rep users (I don't remember how low qualifies for the banner), so that makes sense. Would still be interesting to see an experiment on that

Comment: Evidence : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62479801/1704458

Comment: There's quite a bit of evidence at this point, including evidence posted as answers to this question.

Comment: Re *"semi-forgotten about voting system"*: Do you mean *"semi-forgotten-about voting system"*? Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yeah. I can't spell for crap :D

Comment: I rarely vote, but it's not because I don't know how the system works, but rather because the times when I actually care (when I'm downvoting a highly upvoted post) is when votes are least effective, I don't like that votes are shown on my profile, I have extremely high standards (for upvoting at least), upvoting is binary (+1 for good and also +1 for absolutely amazing doesn't really work for me) and I don't like using my own reputation for voting (for downvotes / bounties). And no, that might not make sense, but it's more about how I feel than what I know is logical.

Comment: Can't people comment on their own question's answers regardless of reputation?

Comment: @einpoklum yep, hence "100% of people who can leave thank you comments, **provided they're not OP of the question or the answer it's posted on**, can also vote.". Take one of the questions with tens, if not hundreds of "thank you" comments - only one of those can be from the question OP. Everyone else, provided they're not commenting on their own answer, must have 50 rep, and therefore be able to vote.

Answer (score 87):

I don't like this feature. We don't need it. ️

Stack Overflow is already complex enough, with users frequently confused already.

Could you implement something more helpful, like [fixing Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/6471538)

Comment: It's not only that we don't need it. It turns out to be harmful. It will automatically reduce the amount of upvotes and with that the appeal to write answers.

Comment: Unless a "Thanks" also gave a small reputation reward (say +1). That way, Mr Skeet would (most likely) already have an extra 100K or so.

Answer (score 81):

I have got an upvote, an accept, a "thank you" reaction **and** a "thank you" comment, all from the same user. Seems the users like to use all the available methods to thank me and this feature just adds more clutter.

[image]

But that was already pointed out in the other answers. I would also like to point out that all the additional buttons on the left, are making a noticeable gap between the post and the comments, if the post is short.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking would happen. It won't lessen the noise it will just generate more

Comment: That user seems very happy :) So it's only natural to use all available means. Perhaps you'd even get a hug, if that was an option.

Comment: Your comment about the additional vertical whitespace is important, but it sort of gets lost in the rest of your post.  Perhaps post it as an additional answer?

Comment: @bta I edited the picture to point it out

Comment: @Scratte we must be thankful it isn't. Hugs transmit some quite nasty diseases that have recently found their way onto humans.

Comment: Oh wow. Since these users are so eager to thank in every possible way, we should consider adding a "donate" button that forwards to our Paypal or something :D

Comment: Next up: 1 rep = 1 dollar. We can make money of these "thank you" comments :).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fact that a thankful user said "Thanks" to you and also gave you a Thanks reaction.

Comment: More gap = more scrolling.  Hulk hate scrolling; make Hulk mad.

Comment: Other than the weird gap, I'm not entirely sure what the concrete harm being done here is.

Answer (score 71):

### We have *always* had a way to say "Thanks":  Upvoting.

[This is expressly called out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) in the guidance for when to comment and when *not* to comment.

> ### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - ...Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;...

---

This experiment has validated two glaring issues that ***must*** be addressed at the highest levels.

1. **FAQ pages are not just *ignored*, but their existence seems to be trivialized when convenient.**  You can put the prettiest prose there as much as you like for as long as you like, but if no one reads it, it doesn't matter.  Worse, this experiment validates their frivolity; it basically affirms that, because people *are* saying thanks, that must mean that we should find a way to encourage it.

   The decision to conduct this experiment is a tacit acknowledgement that any FAQ page can be ignored or overridden at the drop of the hat, which...to be honest, sure, the company can do that anyway.  I just think it's a <s>bit of a</s> jerk move not to have a discussion about something that is going to literally change established policy before changing established policy.
2. **The experiment ignores critical feedback from the community.**  You can do a search both here on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=thank+you+in+comments) *and* [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/175248), and you will find a myriad of discussions or FAQ topics talking about how to encourage people to upvote content or pay it forward, rather than simply saying "Thanks".

   From my perspective, **we've *already* talked about this**, and we don't *like* those kinds of comments.  We don't want to *encourage* more of this behavior.  We want more people to pay it forward, instead. If the company is adamant about [listening to its community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/175248), then this effort is an example of coming across as incredibly tone deaf.

---

I can appreciate that someone in the company may not like or agree with the tone that I've taken in this response.  In light of that, I have chosen this tone *anyway* because of the example being shown before me.  If you are serious about listening to the community, my belief is that the tone I've presented here will be one of strict condemnation rather than harassing.

Answer (score 70):

I dislike this feature. It ironically just adds noise.

### How to opt out of the experiment:

My [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) already hides Reactions (in Teams) which also blocks this Thanks experiment, and I have just added in a new function to **revert the new tooltips in the voting container** to native browser ones.

Step 0 - Install a userscript manager browser extension:

- Recommended https://www.tampermonkey.net

Step 1 - Install/update userscript by clicking on this link:

- https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ReduceClutter.user.js

---

Tested in Chrome, Windows 10, with Tampermonkey.

*[Report bugs for this userscript here](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues/new?template=bug_report.md)*

Comment: I'm going to add thanks here. I was waiting for a user script to hid this :)

Comment: But does it *remove* the darn-awful annoying stupid tooltips that **hide the content** of the page? Or just grabs the text and puts it into the `title` attribute? And which script does that?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel what do you mean? Did you install my userscript and found an issue with it?

Comment: Now imagine if there was a guinea pig-shaped icon to _opt in_ instead.

Comment: @SamuelLiew No, just seeking clarification on how it actually works.

Comment: Yes, no more instant bubble popups

Comment: So far I've had luck with not performing a hard refresh and so my old cache doesn't display them. I'll look into this script when that inevitable happens, though I suspect uBlock Origin element zapper or even Stylus would do as good a job.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow knew you would be the one to build a userscript. @TylerH with uBlock Origin you just have to "pick" the element (using the eyedropper icon in the menu) and then create the filter. I can add an answer if anyone needs more detailed instructions (zapper seems to have a problem per question sometimes): I can add an answer if anyone needs more detail but its currently working for me to remove this

Comment: How to protest and screw over the experiment: don't install the ReduceClutter userscript, write comments containing "thank", and use the thank "feature" instead of voting.

Comment: after adblocks, now thanksblock...

Comment: Can we make this a profile setting if this experiment "succeeds"?

Comment: Can you indicate what browsers it works in? Only Chrome?

Comment: @PeterMortensen works fine in Firefox

Comment: Moderator of a site who creates user scripts to block new features of the site - chancellor Palpatine says "Ironically" for this answer.

Answer (score 56):

Other answers have mentioned that this feature could be harmful, and here is proof that they're right.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444191/4284627) has already been mentioned in [luator's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398424/4284627) with focus on the fact that the OP used the new thank you button *and* added a "thank you" comment, but I would like to mention something even worse.

The OP seemed to have used the new thank you button *instead* of accepting the answer. It's so far the only answer and was obviously useful for the OP, and yet it's not accepted.

[image]

The OP may or may not also have used the new thank you button instead of upvoting, we will never know for sure since upvotes are anonymous.

In case you're wondering how I know it was the OP who used the new thanks button and not someone else, it's visible in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62444191/timeline):

[image]

Maybe they wouldn't have accepted the answer anyway, but the fact that they used the new thanks button and didn't accept the answer is not a good sign. I also saw the same thing happen again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62648522/4284627) so this isn't just about one question (in that question too the OP also added "thank you" comments, but they have been deleted since). That second question now has an accepted answer, but it got accepted only after [I asked the OP to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/110789679).

Comment: well, it's at least a sign that the "new feature" dialog works.

Comment: I think it is a problem in general. Many new users don't know that they *can* and also *should* accept an answer as soon their problem has been solved. SO is not teaching OP's enough about this. - I regularly need to hint OP's by myself to accept an answer if their issue has been solved by answers with clear and unambiguous reaction from OP, which is annoying. I see others do that do. It is not our job to do so.

Comment: I think I mentioned this in a comment on said post, but.. in defense of the user, they may just be holding off a few days to see if a better Answer comes along, as mentioned in the help center: ["Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). However, this quote is immediately preceded with no thank-you comments in bold, so..

Comment: I will also suggest to remove the "thanks button" for the OP since is useless for him. 
He just has to upvote the answer or mark it as best answer, thanks is useless in this case.

Comment: @Dwhitz I definitely agree. But it's useless for users with the upvote privilege too. So we should remove it for them too. Which leaves us with users who have less than 15 reputation and anonymous users. And if we want them to be able to give public feedback as well, we might as well display [their feedback from the upvote button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259583/349538) publicly instead of creating a new button just for that.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I completely agree, but since it's something that SO company want to keep for the future, that was my proposal. If it's possible, I would remove it too! It's just a noise around a question and the SO flow that is not so clear and trasparent for the new users. Adding layer of complexity instead of clarify and simplify the UI&UX it's a pity.

Answer (score 54):

I don't think it's a good idea. We already have voting, so yet another button is not needed. It just clutters the UI.

Also, if I received such a "thanks", (for which I had to look for since there are no notifications), it would really not mean much. A button press is way too cheap to mean anything.

On the other hand, a "thanks" comment with more than just that word is more personal, and something I both like giving and receiving sometimes. That's a real, personal, social interaction, a button will never be able to replace that.

Comment: Thanks for this very thoughful answer. It's very similar to what I thought. Comments that just say thanks can be deleted without further ado but comments that go on an provide useful feedback stand on their own and cannot be replaced by a single button.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think that replacing comments with feedback is a goal by any means. I would hope that doesn't stop - I certainly do that often. I won't post comments that are just "Thanks, this is great" but I often say thanks at the opening of a comment when asking for more information, particularly if the answer got me part way there.

Comment: @Catija The two basic versions of comments with "thanks" in them have been identified here (+1 Thanks and Thanks, and how about .....). Where the stats given based on distinguishing the two, or lumping the two together?

Comment: @user7412956 That's a good question - from what I understand, it's a simple query that looked at all comments for the word "thank". I'm in the process of requesting a deeper dive to check against things like whether the person who wrote the post was the one saying thanks - as in thanking someone for making a suggestion to improve their post, someone writing a comment that would be single-flag deleted, and something that could take a guess - likely based on length - of what comments included suggestions to improve the post. Also checking if the comments are paired with votes or not. :)

Comment: Them's gonna be some hefty SQL hi-jinks.

Comment: @Catija Would be better if a SEDE link was shared, but based on recent events, it seems that it was intentionally ommited. Also based on the fact that the post is locked and no comments are allowed. Feels like the start of converting StackOverflow's open community into a closed social network...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel We'd be searching deleted comments, too, which wouldn't be in a query y'all could replicate.

Comment: The goal is understandable, but I think it'll do very little to cut down on "thanks" comments for exactly the reason pointed out in the last paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 54):

Since this is a test:

- What are the criteria to consider it successful? (remember, before setting up an experiment, you have to already had this established, otherwise the experiment is flawed)
- What are the current numbers for the following:

  - Complaints from users whose comments are deleted
  - Comment flags handled by type
  - Comment flags raised by [Andy's bot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354723/792066)
  - Comment flags raised by Community (-1)

I would like if the test also considered the length of the comments, since it was part of one of the [latest tests to address undesired content in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953).

Comment: Is there a control group?  I see this feature and assume everyone else does too.  I've heard this sort of thing can get you [fired](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2012/12/11/there-are-four-ways-to-get-fired-from-caesars-1-theft-2-sexual-harassment-3-running-an-experiment-without-a-control-group-and-4-keeping-a-gambling-addict-away-from-the-casino/)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 control group is probably the SO population before the change.

Comment: that's not a control group

Comment: @Braiam Great catch - it looks like there's no control group. The only variations in this test are different thank you icons. This means there'll be no way to tell whether the "thank you" feature improved things or not. I can't understand why a third variation wasn't included with no thank you icon. It seems like the SO team already made up their mind about it :(

Answer (score 53):

**Preface**

This feature announcement is [the most unpopular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=votes&page=2836) one since the removal of hot meta posts (ATTOW) with little less than 100 answers, which is a feat in itself. There is also a [controversy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398507/why-was-needs-more-emoji-deleted-by-an-employee) regarding one of the answers here. On the one hand, those who believed in SE Inc. not caring about their input got another confirmation. On the other, SE Inc got their fears of bringing features on meta is like going to war<sup>0</sup> reinvigorated.

I think we can all agree that the announcement is a disaster. None of this was necessary. What follows is yet another attempt to explain what went wrong, what could be developed, and what procedure could be adopted to build a constructive dialog with the community.

**What went wrong? Research**

One of the main reasons the announcement was met with a barrage of criticism is that many took issue with *how* the data used to justify the feature was acquired:

> “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers

Literal interpretation of this statement suggests only the following criteria were used:

- Comments should have a "thanks" string in them, and only in that form.
- Measurements should be done in relative values as "percent of posts".
- Only posts with comments should be considered.
- Only comments left under answers should be considered.

A lot of us know SQL to at least some degree, and this seems to constitute an overly broad query that, as many others pointed out if used, will result in a lot of false positives. I would assume otherwise, but the abovementioned are the only criteria published.

Here is a small SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1255178#graph) for the last 5 years created using these assumptions (the result is pretty close to 1/6 on average). Maybe I missed something, but unless the query had a criterion of *"percent of total answers"* and not *"percent of answers posted"* the results do not look as bad as they are announced:

[image: 5-year "thank" comments graph]

> Of note is a spike in the number of such comments since June

**What should have been done? Procedure**

1. Asking the community at large first. I do understand that getting a feature on meta can be [very scary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387939/why-are-stack-overflow-employees-forced-to-participate-in-meta-and-why-couldnt), but in this case, the reasoning does not apply, as testing the feature on SO was [planned for some time](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jL0t4sCXjGMJ:https://www.lisahpark.com/reactions%20&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=en) (cache dates as far back as April 3rd) and asking the actual users affected was only the **5th** (and the last) point on the bucket list.
2. If not, starting by asking what *existing* proposals we can implement instead of introducing a new feature. I realize that the product team has to develop features by nature, but that does not mean that the feature *has* to be new. And adding something *suggested* by the community, even if in a different form than originally proposed, goes a long way in building trust and well-meaning relationship with said community.
3. If not even that, at the very least roll out the feature to the target audience<sup>1</sup> and gather usage data - if these groups show a tendency to change the behaviour, roll out the feature site-wide and *include the testing results in the announcement*. For example, a target group can include:

   - users with < 15 reputation points who literally [cannot upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
   - users with "low engagement" (i.e. under a certain amount of posts *and* low number of votes cast)
   - or users *who post comments with "thank" in them* under a certain character count threshold
4. If not all that (which was likely the case here), after receiving so much negative backlash and even [community moderators acknowledging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398507/why-was-needs-more-emoji-deleted-by-an-employee/398637#comment777610_398637) that the way the feature was introduced was less than optimal, at least either:

   - put a disclaimer on the question stating that you understand the concerns and reassure people that the feature will be closely monitored (not the *formal* statement at the end of the post)
   - update the question from time to time with interim results of "monitoring usage and other data" - let users see that you *care* about the feature

     All in all, a backlash is a normal reaction to an unpopular decision which dies down after a while, and the goal here to let the community see that you *actually think* that the feature is useful and are ready to defend it (**not by engaging in comments**).

**What could be implemented instead? Validation**

As a lot of answers mention, even a *client-side* validation of the comment *suggesting* the user reconsidering posting the comment if it contains "thanks" and is relatively short would be a both easier to implement and more welcomed feature<sup>2</sup>:

```js
const buildFailureNotice = (length, min) => {
  return <div class="failureNotice">Please do not use comments just to thank someone, vote the post up if you have the privilege and accept if you think this is the best answer. Add {min-length} more chars to go...</div>
};

const validateThanks = (component, callback) => (e) => {
  const boundCallback = callback.bind(component);
  
  const min = component.minLengthForThanksValidate;

  const { target } = e;
  const { value } = target;
  const { length } = value;
  
  const thanksRegex = /\b(thanks?|appreciated?)\b(?!.*?\b(?:but|though)\b)/i;
    
  boundCallback( length < min && !thanksRegex.test(value) || length >= min, length );
};

class InputWithThanksValidation extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isThanksValid: true};
    this.minLengthForThanksValidate = 40;
  }

  changeValidationState(status, charLength) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isThanksValid: status,
      currentLength: charLength
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { minLengthForThanksValidate : min } = this;
  
    const { isThanksValid, currentLength } = this.state;
    
    const validationFailureNotice = !isThanksValid ? buildFailureNotice(currentLength, min) : "";

    return ( 
      <div class="thanksValidated"> 
        <textarea onInput={validateThanks(this,this.changeValidationState)} id = "comment" placeholder = "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”."></textarea>
        {validationFailureNotice}
      </div>
    );

  }

}

ReactDOM.render( < InputWithThanksValidation / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const simulateTyping = (setValOverride, element, input) => {
  const ev = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
 
  input.split("").forEach((char,c) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { value } = element; 
      setValOverride.call(element, value + char);
      element.dispatchEvent(ev);
      
      if(c === input.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(()=> setValOverride.call(element, "") ,4e2);
      }
      
    }, 1e2 * c);
  });
};

(() => {
    const tested = document.getElementById("comment");
    
    const inputs = [
      "thank you for your answer.",
      "Thank you, but it did not work",
      "@User, thanks! Though, this does not answer my question",
      "The answer is obsolete, please update it. Thanks!",
      "THANK YOU SO MUCH, I AM SHIFT STUCK!",
      "Is it faster than @User's solution?",
      "I appreciate you taking the time! That said, you have a typo"
    ];
    
    const setVal = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, "value"
    ).set;
    
    let accumulatedOffset = 0;
    
    inputs.forEach((input,i) => {
      setTimeout( () => simulateTyping(setVal, tested, input) , accumulatedOffset );
      accumulatedOffset += (1e2 * input.length + 1e3);
    });
})();
```

```css
body {
    --white:#fff;
    --black:#0c0d0e;
    --orange:#f48024;
    --black-200:#bbc0c4;
    --black-300:#9fa6ad;
    --black-350:#9199a1;
    --orange-300:#f7aa6d;
    --blue-300:#6cbbf7;
    --fc-dark:#0c0d0e;
    --focus-ring:rgba(0,149,255,0.15);
}

input {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 1vh;
}

thanksValidated {
  width: 80%;  
}

textarea, .failureNotice {
  width : 50%;
}

textarea {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  height: 5em;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .6em .7em;
  border: 1px solid var(--black-200);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--fc-dark);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 1.15384615;
}

textarea:focus {
    border-color: var(--blue-300);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--focus-ring);
    outline: 0;
}

.failureNotice {
  border : 1px solid;
  border-color: var(--orange-300);
  color: var(--black-350);
  font-size: 75%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**Aftermath: was it worth it?**

The feature was introduced on June 17th and turned off on July 17th. If its goal was to reduce number of comments with "thank" in them, it [failed spectacularly](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1253292/trend-of-thank-comments-posted-for-the-last-period-under-post-type?word=%25thank%25&metric=day&offset=-45&type=answer#graph) as shown by the graph below:

[image: thank comments since feature introduction]

---

<sup>0</sup> It is not accidental that responses from CMs tend to contain terms "shield", "panic attacks", "hostile", etc - they are all related to dealing with an enemy force, not engaging in civil conversation.

<sup>1</sup> From my standpoint, 1 on 1 interviews are not enough when considering a feature that will affect a product that has millions of users. The key here is *not enough*: after all, I am not going to argue against sociology here. But the fact that 2 of 5 research points consisted of 1 on 1 interviews and *none* addressed the community is concerning at best.

<sup>2</sup> Given the obvious nature of the suggestion, I would assume it was pitched and discussed during the "Ideation" step of the research and deemed unworthy. In that case, it would also help to provide some *reasoning* behind why a button was chosen - it *may* have alleviated some tension as well.

Comment: "Asking the community at large first" - this has fallen on deaf ears for years now. No matter how many people say it however many times, they simply don't care. They do listen to the community occasionally. But it's far & few in between (and usually *after* a shitstorm happens). When the reaction is overwhelmingly negative, `"shield", "panic attacks", "hostile", etc` are used to vilify the community when they endorse the management decisions & site "features".

Comment: @P.P - well, I can't disagree with you as that it seems that way. Although, SE Inc is in a very peculiar position - most companies do not have to deal with the pressure of a strong and vocal community and I think that the procedure of 1. Discuss with the team -> 2. Develop a prototype -> 3. Test on a control group -> 4. Roll out publicly -> 5. Announce seemed like second nature. But that's true when you deal with a community of customers, not *contributors* where the opposite is the better strategy. And this is where things got awry. From what I can gather, responses from SE tend to show...

Comment: ...(as far as one can attribute intent to another person) a genuine lack of understanding that decision making in community-centric democratic environments ( and SO does exibit most relevant traits of such an environment for me: elections, self-moderation, voluntary engagement, reliance on consensus rather than decisions, etc ) should be *inwards*, not *outwards*. Sadly, the situation is not improving, that's true. What I think we can do here is use every opportunity we have not to make SE *reckon* with the community but to *understand* the need for it. My belief is that we are locked in...

Comment: a feedback loop of SE Inc *by nature* not realizing that things work differently for open communities, that one has to expect a backlash for an unpopular decision, etc. and the community assuming the worst (and why wouldn't it - after all, the worst thing one can do to a active contributors is to "ask them last") about the company. The way this feature was introduced did not help at all to change that perception.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: I meant to say "[..] when they **don't** endorse the management decisions [..]"

Comment: I don't deny that it's a tricky situation balancing the Inc's business goals with the community's desires. My opinion is that making money & engaging with community about features/site changes isn't mutually exclusive. It's often imposing new features under the guise of "this is what community wants!" without even talking to the community first that annoys most.

Comment: @P.P - and I agree that they are not. I also do understand the collective frustration and tiredness of such conduct (the first time I saw the announcement, the only thing on my mind was - "really?"). But I came to think that this was albeit ill-guided but an attempt to do good. Something in the post looked familiar - and I am glad that the original announcement did not get lost - it convinced me that this was not an attempt to impose a feature, but a genuine attempt at solving a problem fundamentally flawed by trying to *develop a feature* instead of looking through existing proposals and...

Comment: ...solutions. I am cautiously optimistic about the way the feature was presented, though - this time it is in test mode *and* it is admitted that the conduct should've been drastically different - that's definitely a start. That said, the feature was already live on Teams as far as [November](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391723/how-can-i-revert-my-reaction-to-a-teams-post) and the plans to roll out the feature on SO were in place as far back as April (likely earlier), so that's why I added points from 2 to 5 of what could be done if asking community first was not an option...

Comment: Now this feature announcement is the most unpopular one ever, even more unpopular than the one about hot meta posts.

Comment: Your code has a bug, it considers "than" as a synonym to "thanks". For example it won't let me post the comment "More than what?".

Comment: Also another bug in your code is that your regex is case sensitive. For example it will allow all-caps comments like "THANK YOU!!!" without any problem. It would be better to make it case-insensitive by adding `i` at the end, like `/your-regex-here/i`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Re:unpopular - yeah, it broke several records - never seen an announcement with more than 1000 downvotes and 99 answers before. Re:bug - well, I did not think too much about the implementation for a test, but thanks for pointing that out - will address (one more example that if asked, we could provide a lot of ideas...).

Comment: Although that does not mean I shouldn't have seen that `thank?` will result in false positives like `than` - thank you for noticing :)

Comment: Great code snippet :) Note you need no `(?:T|t)` if you use `/i` modifier, `/Thanks?(?!.*?(?:but|Though))/i` would be enough. However, I'd add word boundary check, ``/\bThanks?\b(?!.*?\b(?:but|Though)\b)/i``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thank you (oh, the irony) - this is a remnant of the version prior to Donald Duck noting that an insensitive match could be used. Happy to incorporate the change shortly, what may be better than to show that the community can build this from scratch, review and debug? :)

Answer (score 48):

Even as I admire your efforts in keeping the noisy comments down to a minimum I have to disagree with this experiment. Considering some [basic research](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1252707) into when this type of comments appear one can conclude that the tiny button under vote buttons will not solve this problem. It might reduce the amount of comments containing "thanks", but it is not the solution.

## It's OP's fault

Most such comments come from the original poster. The comments are posted by the same people who leave "Thank you in advance" at the end of their questions. OP just wants to personally thank other people for taking interest in their question. They can post such comments even at 1 rep.

The problem here is that new users are not educated properly on what to do when someone answers your question. They don't know that these comments bring nothing of value to the site; it is just an act of courtesy to thank people for their time.

Askers do it usually after upvoting/accepting, but many do it on all answers that they get and they only accept the best one.

I have been a victim of this many times on my own answers. Sometimes I leave the comment for a few minutes to make the OP feel welcome before nuking their comment. I think that many people don't have the heart to press that flag button when OP posts thank you under your answer. After all, it feels nice to be appreciated.

## Thanks, fixed!

The rest of thank you comments can be divided into two parts.

1. Someone posted a comment informing you of a typo or something you need to fix and you would like to let them know that you received it. "Thank you" comments are perfect for this and they are used in such a way by even very high reputation users (>100k). The difference here is that we know "Thank you" comments under 50 UTF-16 code units long can be easily nuked. When we reply we expect the person to remove the original comment and nuke ours. It's a self-cleaning process.
2. Someone searching the net for a solution to their problem and finding an answer. After trying they feel obliged to confirm that the solution worked for them. Thus, we arrive at "Thanks, it worked for me" on old posts. It's a tiny fraction and it can be easily fixed, as already suggested by multiple answers in this thread, by regex with a popup informing them that the upvote button should be used instead. If you have the privilege to post thanks on someone else's post you also have the privilege to upvote.

## What is the point of the new button?

For the author of the post it will be pleasant noise. We don't gain anything from thanks, just as we don't gain anything from "thanks" in comments. Only this time we can't actually remove this noise if we want to.

For the thanker, this will mostly go unnoticed. They don't want to press an anonymous button, they want you to feel how they are personally thankful for your answer.

Don't we already let people press buttons? We have anonymous feedback. It is only to make people feel better. It serves no purpose and is hidden from normal users of the site. How is the new button different? My recommendation would be to light up the upvote button even when the upvote is not counted towards the score.

Comment: "[...] comments under 50 UTF-16 code units long can be easily nuked." <-- I disagree. Saying "Thank you, but it still causes the same error." is 46 characters long and has a lot of important information. Saying "Thank you, it now works. I'm upvoting and accepting your answer." could be removed after some time, and has no meaningfull content despite being 64 characters long.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Please read the context. I meant comments only saying "Thanks, I have updated the answer"

Comment: Your criteria was based on length. While putting meaning into code is impossible, there are comments that have a short length but lots of information that's important. And long ones that are just fluff. Also: "When we reply we expect the person to remove the original comment and nuke ours." <-- this nuking can only be done by the moderators, who already have a lot on their plate. You're just adding more for them if you expect comments to be removed like that. But there are situations where this makes sense (like, say, for a comment about something to fix that no longer applies can be flagged).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I purposefully said short comments with Thanks in them, which we can nuke ourselves without moderators. I never want to give moderators more work than necessary. I agree that short comments can have meaning and are useful. I don't encourage deleting comments based solely on the length. You must have misunderstood that paragraph. I was talking about letting the other person know that we read their comment by posting easily deletable reply-comment. If the comment is short and has a keyword in it, we can delete it without moderators help.

Comment: These "thank you" comments do bring something of value to the site. A heartfelt thank you message means a lot more to me than an upvote.

Comment: @Flimm Sure, but once you read it you can delete it. How many times will be you coming back to read the same comment?

Answer (score 48):

No.

Once again SE Inc. is addressing the wrong problem.

The problem is not that people do not have a way to indicate whether an answer is helpful or not. They do; it's called upvoting.

The problem is that people are posting useless "thanks" comments, most likely because they don't know what upvoting is.

Put this "feature" in the bin. Replace it with a snippet of JavaScript that checks the content of a comment field when submitted, and if said comment contains nothing more than "thanks", [suggests to the user to use an upvote instead and prevents them submitting the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398451/1997232).

Comment: *"suggests to the user to use an upvote"* - as [I thought](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398451/1997232), this solution is way more appropriate than what was done.

Comment: Note that many comments start with "thanks", then go on to say something useful.

Comment: I would be hesitant to *prevent* submission unless the check is *extremely* specific (i.e. it doesn't catch all that many cases). There will always be issues with outright preventing something based on a broad regex or something, like people needing to find a hack to put "problem" in the title of a question (like for one that's about the travelling salesman problem). Maybe just show a warning and give them a choice (e.g. post anyway / upvote instead). Or maybe the benefit outweighs the downside.

Answer (score 40):

I think that the way how it is currently expected to be implemented creates a wide open door for abuse.

The proposed design makes it possible for anyone to create a hundred sock puppet accounts and immediately cast "likes" in any quantities they want. And this kind of violation would be much harder to catch than [voting-fraud](/questions/tagged/voting-fraud). And even if caught, what are you going to do? Suspend the (1-rep) abuser? Ha, they will just create the next hundred of sock puppets and keep doing what they did.

Be prepared to observe totally weird things like poor quality / spammy answers (including, but not limited to, all kinds of rants and senseless jokes) sitting at -10 score and having thousand likes.

Heck, be prepared to observe this even without any abuse, from legitimate "thankers" (which will be even more painful because there will be no way for you to stop that. There isn't any reason to suspend them and undo the damage).

You know, even upvotes from 15-rep users may be harmful (give a read to Atwood's [Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) if you haven't yet). And now you are going to multiply this risk by 10,000.

---

The idea to reduce useless "thanks" in comments looks tempting and in theory I could support tricks helping in that. However, the price we have to pay for getting it the way you suggest seems too high.

You know, my primary reason for visiting Stack Overflow ([explained eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/839601)) is to learn from properly (cu)rated content, and thinking about how post quality rating may get totally skewed... it just makes me sad. Very sad.

Consider implementing this in a way that carries less risk of damaging content rating. One thing that comes to mind is to somehow limit visibility of these "likes", for example, showing them only to those who cast the like and to the post author.

Another thing I would strongly recommend to have is public visibility of likes in user profiles and (especially!) in Data Explorer. This way you could leverage power of broad site community to discover and fight potential abuse.

In order to minimize impact of possible abuse, I would additionally recommend that user deletion would make all of their likes disappear - immediately and unconditionally. For the same purpose, consider implementing "likes invalidation" tooling similar to one that is currently used for invalidation of fraudulent votes.

---

Another way to address that would be to focus on more important need of users having reputation between 1 and 125. This problem is somewhat similar and can be technically addressed using essentially the same code that you already made for "thanks" feature.

Having [association bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/association-bonus) you probably won't notice part of this issue because it allows you vote up everywhere but you can easily see the other part at sites where you have insufficient reputation to vote down.

Imagine that you visit some question that you have already seen in the past (simply visited it, or bookmarked or followed). Imagine that in the past visit you already spent some effort, evaluated the question and answers and decided for yourself which are useful and which are not.

Unfortunately, because insufficient reputation didn't let you vote up and down, when you see it again, there is no way for you to tell how you evaluated it before so you have to repeat cumbersome reading and checking things to find it out.

If system somehow recorded your past evaluation and displayed it to you this would save you quite a bit of effort, wouldn't it.

FWIW "thanks" feature currently partially aids in that because users with reputation between 1 and 15 can (mis)use it to record positive evaluation. But since the experiment had so thoroughly failed it will likely be removed so that problem described above will get back to us again.

This information wouldn't really need to be publicly visible in the post, because you evaluated things for yourself, not for others - merely listing it in Votes and reactions tab in your profile would perfectly suffice to serve the user need (though tab would likely have to be renamed to something like "votes and evaluations" to prevent misleading users about its purpose).

Incidentally, getting rid of showing it publicly would also remove possibility of abuse.

Comment: If a thanks has no value, why even bother with catching such fraud? I actually really loved this idea in a different implementation... where someone could say thanks as many times as they liked (could set some limitations, say, one per day), sort of like claps on Medium... and not even require being logged in to use it... I hear so often about people who end up using the same post over and over because they forget what it said, so this would let them react every time they had to reference the post again... heck, I've even heard people end up finding an answer they wrote when problem solving.

Comment: @Catija because it may have no value for _us_, but it's still a metric that someone could manipulate to interpret however they like.

Comment: ^^^ @Catija exactly this. How do you expect site visitors to use the answer that has -10 score and 100 likes?

Comment: Why would anyone use an answer that has that many downvotes? That seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Catija how do you expect site visitors to know that downvotes matter while likes are insignificant? For someone inexperienced, these will likely look just like equally important numbers

Comment: The fact that it's greyed out and at the bottom of the list is usually a good signal that it's bad. And the number size is hugely different. [Score is huge compared to reaction count.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLkEF.png) I understand your concerns. I share some of them... but I would like to see what actually happens - this is good for us to keep in mind and maybe we can find some solution like not showing reactions on negatively-scoring posts... but let's ... just... see what the testing shows. :)

Comment: @Catija showing likes on zero / low positive score posts may be even more damaging, because in this case inexperienced visitors won't even have a visual hint that quality may be troublesome, all that they will se will be multiple (possibly fake) likes

Comment: Yep... and I just said that... "*maybe we can find some solution like not showing reactions on negatively-scoring post*". :D I agree with you. I just want to see what the impact is.

Comment: showing thanks only to the thanker and the OP sounds like a great immediate adjustment to make to this; great idea.

Comment: @Catija "*Why would anyone use an answer that has that many downvotes? That seems like a terrible idea.*" some people who visit the likes of Reddit and Imgur and similar platforms that have upvote/downvote for posts accept a negative score as a just "Oh, it's just not popular". A post can make a good point but be downvoted because it's dissenting from the majority. Its like...voting on meta: negatively scored posts aren't necessarily *bad* but simply more people disagree with it. [Also negative score doesn't exactly prevent using certain things anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546).

Comment: (melancholically) this can increase engagement and new user registrations if they make a profile setting with an option to hide likes. Could be even greater success than Dark Mode

Comment: ^^^ PS. Prom what I recently [learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351385/ceo-blog-some-exciting-news-about-fundraising/351435#comment1176799_351389 "'Engagement is measured by a post, comment, or vote'") this thanks reaction indeed looks like attempt to somehow boost engagement metrics

Answer (score 38):

This is a mistake.

It's already hard enough to get users to realize that the *way* to say Thank You is to *accept* the answer.

Providing another way to say Thank You will merely reduce the already abysmal acceptance rate. And that, in turn, will reduce the already fading incentive to answer in the first place.

Comment: To be fair though - the accept answer feature is sometimes less than useful, thanks to its ability to pin less than useful answers to the top, no matter how lowly the community thinks of them. And makes it harder to a question at the whim of the asker.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I quite often see that OP's accept(ed) hilarious answers, which partwise not even answer the question at all, while elaborate answers are "unpinned" dipping in the dark. How can that be? It's unbelievable.

Comment: @matt I think we both are one of the only ones, who see this new feature actually as harmful, not only just not necessary or confusing. This provides a quite different view on the feature. +1

Answer (score 38):

Wow, thanks!

[image]

... but no thanks.

To be less flippant though:

- I'm not that troubled by "thanks" comments.
- There are other ways to reduce the frequency of "thanks" comments, without such a profound change with so many ripples of effect on interactions on the network.
- Comments which include "thanks" and more text are actually often useful and certainly not a problem.
- You should have brought up the question of whether this was a problem, whether a solution should be worked on, and what solution that should be - here or on Meta.SX, before going ahead with the experiment.
- I'm not being contrarian. When you do good things - like the [CommonMark transition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) (and maybe tables!), I'll be (among) the first to support them.
- I'm worried that this is a "can't fail" experiment...

Comment: To your last bullet: it is very important to define precise goals for something like this... As you note, "thank you *but*" and "thank you *because*" comments can be pretty useful! When GitHub rolled out reactions, the observed effect was no reduction in comments containing emoji... But a significant reduction in comments that were *nothing but* emoji. The equivalent on SO would be "thank you...!15" or some such - if THAT can be tracked, separated from the larger group, testing efficacy here stands to be interesting.

Comment: @Shog9: +1 on that. But - even with concrete criteria, it could be that failure in the criteria will not result in rolling it back, just in tweaking it this way or that.

Comment: Yeah, your last point is my biggest concern - saying "we're going to try this" but having a "but we're not getting rid of it no matter what" feels too much like when DOCs was launched (it will just reverse all goodwill that's been built up as its basically lying - or at least will feel that way to people who just started thinking about maybe trusting SE a little)

Comment: I think @LinkBerest meant [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Comment: @Scratte yep, only 10kers can see that page though: [its the last failed experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation)

Comment: @LinkBerest: Ah, yes. I couldn't bring myself to go there during the experiment because I felt it would be overly redundant with SO itself.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't understand how that's comparable. We already have voting. GitHub doesn't (so I've been told).

Comment: The systems are not directly comparable, @scratte - you kinda have to figure out what each action means within its system, and then find an equivalent. For example, you could say that voting on SO serves a purpose *on SO* somewhat akin to that of a PR review approve/request changes on GH.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm going to guess that PR means a Pull Request. And that makes sense to compare, **except** I do not hope that random user stopping by a repository are able to make an approval of such. As for the GitHub reactions, it seems to be on comments, which we also already have with the tiny-upvote. So.. you could say that GitHub implemented the tiny-upvote that we have, and then it sort of doesn't make sense to lean on the success of that.

Comment: This is why I say you have to look at the role of the feature within its own system, @scratte.

Answer (score 37):

The system deletes "thank you" comments immediately when 1 single flag is raised.

No mod intervention required most of the time.

Comment: How are those comments identified? Do you have a source?

Comment: @PeterMortensen staff posts on Meta say it's by RegEx. The same mechanism used to confirm single flag deletion also prevents offensive language by preemptive filtering.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's in the [comment voting/flagging FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/269301): > Comments containing certain "trigger" keywords are deleted instantly after a single flag, regardless of upvotes. The list of trigger keywords is kept secret, and may differ per site.

Answer (score 34):

Your effort could've been spared by asking the community for good solutions of the "Thanks"-commenting problem before implementing anything, just like [Andreas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7395227/andreas) pointed out in a comment.

I like the idea to change the tooltip of the upvote to "Thank and upvote", just like [Caius Jard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard) pointed out in another comment. This should be applied to upvotes for comments, too.

This is probably not enough to reduce the thank-comments significantly, so additionally you could display a little blocking popover when commenting that is short and contains "thank", "thx" or whatever, too.

This popover would recommend the user to upvote the post/comment, instead. It would also contain a button "comment anyways" to bypass the block.

Comment: Changing the tooltip to include "thanks" deserves its own discussion too. The reason why people post all these "thanks", or fluff, is because they misunderstand the site. I'm worried adding "thanks" to the tooltip further pushes the conception that you need to "thank" (and that upvotes aren't enough), but I might be wrong.

Comment: "display a little blocking popover when commenting any answer that is short and contains "thank", "thx" or whatever, too." Isn't there already a canned response to that?

Comment: @Andreas No, there isn't ...

Comment: On the main sites, not meta sites.

Comment: @Andreas I just tested it on a random answer on the main page and removed my comment again. It did not suggest me to upvote there, either. Maybe the feature exists only for new members, but based on the statistics it should suggest this to everyone, everytime.

Comment: mhm. Strange. Somebody posted such a canned message on a duplicate of this meta "question", and I remembered I'd gotten a similar one once I was replying with "thanks" to somebody that pointed out an issue in one of my answers.

Comment: The comment box already has a placeholder with the following content: "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.". Maybe adding something for new users, where they have to click a button to be able to write a comment? Would that satisfy what you wanted?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You already have to click a link to start commenting. And yes I know the avoid-hint, but apparently the problem is either this is not read or rejected by the user. Blocking popover that requires an additional interaction has a little bit of a nagging character, but it can help to move more people into upvoting, instead.

Comment: @MartinBraun The idea would be for users below 100 reputation. Those do tend to just say "Thank you". And the link you have to click is, literally, a link saying "add a comment". Adding this information in there, before they click, could be a good idea as well

Answer (score 34):

I'm not in favour of this idea, but regardless I would like to point out that the icons chosen (on my system at least) are effectively unreadable and so give no clue as to their intended usage:

[image]

Comment: I could see this one as "washing hands" due to Corona pandemic. ^^

Comment: Seing it in real use it looks like a face-palm to me. Now _that_ would be useful for many questions.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Perhas "I am washing my hands of this entire affair".

Answer (score 32):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464818/equivalent-operation-to-remainder-operator-for-handling-values-below-the-minimal/62464951#62464951) is another example of that the feature does not work as expected:

> [image]

The OP didn't use the new feature. He accepted, probably upvoted and said "*thanks*" instead by comment. No triggered "*Thank you*" reaction.

Either for him it was just more personal to say "*Thank you*" by comment or didn't know about the new feature. Either way, this is an alarm sign.

---

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62481228/timeline) is an example that the new feature is redundant, this time just the Activity Log of the answer:

> [image]

After feedback communication between answerer and OP, s/he said "*thank you*" by comment, accepted the answer and triggered another "*Thank you*" reaction.

These are one of many examples that it doesn't work in practice as intended.

I personally think it is just more usual to say "*Thank you*" in personal, not through a reaction button.

---

Furthermore, the feature is only implemented for comments on answers. What about ["*Thank you*" comments for comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465154/questions-regarding-c-syntax#comment110471502_62465154)? (Note: Link is broken/The question has been deleted. But I still let the link alive for moderators and developers.)

> [image]

Here the question was closed. The OP thanked helping hand Tom for the information by another comment.

Side note: That the specific question has been deleted does not change anything at the fact the comment was thanked by a comment. The question also had been kept closed but undeleted.

It does not make sense to implement the feature in such an inconsistent way. Either your idea is proper or leave it.

---

I have another answer, which focuses my personal opinion about this feature [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398422#398422).

Comment: "Either for him it was just more personal to say "Thank you" by comment..." - Exactly. If I want to thank someone, I am not going to click a button that doesn't give anything (ie reputation) **and doesn't even notify that person**.

Comment: @MichaelT It is something about being a human with feeling empathy for someone who has helped. You can't make the people to robots.

Comment: @MichaelT And yes, that seems to be a brain-fart, when the poster is not notified about the action.

Comment: Thanks! ... for catching this example.

Comment: @einpoklum I updated another one.

Answer (score 31):

So, if I'm counting correctly, that would be **a 6th way to show thanks**, after upvoting, leaving a comment, accepting the answer, giving it a bounty and sharing it.

I know it's meant to *replace* leaving a comment for thanks, but it's not going to replace that (as discussed in other answers) and even without that there are still many ways to show thanks (especially upvoting).

Have you considered **changing how some of the existing mechanisms work** or are presented instead of adding *yet another one*?

Some examples of things you could do: (some already mentioned in other answers)

- **Replace the vote triangles with something else** (what is a triangle even supposed to mean?, rhetorical question), like thumbs up or thumbs down (which functionally work the same).
- **Rethink the bounty system**. For example, have how many bounties you can give depend on your reputation, but have bounties not actually use your reputation. It could also be made more prominent. It could be a button on the answer instead of (or in addition to) on the question. If you're rewarding an existing answer, it's kind of like a "super-upvote", yet it's shown at a completely different place from and works very different than regular upvotes.
- **Rethink the acceptance system**. For example, just get rid of it entirely and, if you really still want the asker to be special, give a small reputation or ranking bonus to any answers upvoted by the asker. Possibly won't help with this issue, but I'll take any opportunity to get rid of a flawed system that probably adds little more than clutter.
- **Rethink commenting**. "Add a comment" was temporarily replaced by "suggest improvement" on some sites. I think that idea was far from perfect, but it could be iterated upon and people have suggested variations and alternatives.
- **Make the buttons for voting more prominent** and more clearly something you can click on. A featureless gray triangle doesn't really scream "click me". And the fact that it's at the *top left* of the post might also not be ideal (since you're usually at the *bottom right* after you're done reading it). Not that I'm proposing putting it at the bottom, but the current layout is certainly something to think about.
- [**Decrease the reputation required for upvoting**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?answertab=votes#comment775689_398369), and possibly make it not give reputation if the vote was cast by a low-rep user (or delay giving reputation until the voter gets the required reputation), to prevent abuse.
- **[Check for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398381/1711796) ["thank you" comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398489/1711796)** and suggest to users that they upvote instead when they try to post such a comment.
- [**Educate users better about how to use the site**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398369/1711796).

Maybe not all amazing ideas, but there are probably many feature requests here on Meta suggesting how to improve the existing "thanks" mechanisms. The point is: let's fix what we have instead of adding new things that serve the same purpose.

Comment: changing the add a comment to suggest improvement is a great suggestion, as well as the educate users better

Comment: So many good suggestions here! I especially like the one about rethinking the acceptance system.

Answer (score 30):

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers.

So your metric is *comments containing "thanks"*.

> we're introducing this clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks"

But your solution is for *comments consisting only of "thanks"*. This seems really weird, as that has nothing to do with the metric used to justify the new feature.

Good comments that additionaly contain a "thanks" are not an issue. Skipping the "thanks" e.g. when asking to clarify something can appear a bit rude (dare I say 'unwelcoming'?), so it is not always an option to comment without the "thanks" and click the button instead. I'm quite sure there will be just as many comments containing "thanks" as before (and I'm ok with that).

What also bothers me is the placement of the icon. The feature is supposed to fix an issue with comments. But the icon has been placed next to the voting feature. It's already hard enough to get new users to actually vote on an answer. Yet another button next which can easily be confused with a voting feature is not really helpful in my opionion.

I have the feeling new users would be much more likely to click on a button labeled with "say thanks" next to the "add comment" button in the comment area, because that is where they go to when they want to say thanks.

Answer (score 29):

> We hope that this test will have a positive impact on our community and reduce:
>
> - Friction for users whose comments are deleted,
> - The burden on moderators, and
> - The time active users spend flagging/deleting comments.

This is **a good problem** to discover, but you're solving it in an irrational, unbelievable, ridiculous way.

> Reduce friction for users whose comments are deleted

Great, <s>then just don't delete them</s>. If these comments don't belong in the first place, they **should not come out** in the first place. Make it harder to post, such as when "thanks" is detected, prompt the user to vote up or accept instead. This extra step of confirmation is beneficial in two ways: To reduce the number of useless comments, and to guide users onto the right track.

> Reduce the burden on moderators, and the time active users spend flagging/deleting comments

If these comments don't come out in the first place, then there's nothing to delete.

> ... will have a positive impact on our community ...

Decades later, two old people chat about their technical careers and lives.

- Alice: I have accumulated 100k reputation on Stack Overflow.
- Bob: I have accumulated 100k "thanks" on Stack Overflow.
- Alice: Pardon?

---

And... Can we anticipate more buttons like "Happy", "Sad", "Confused" should similar comments stack up in the future?

Comment: One button that *may* receive more support than this would be one to indicate that we think the answer, though possibly well-presented, is just plain wrong: ❌ Oh, I forgot, we have the downvote button for that (or those of us with sufficient reputation do, anyway).

Answer (score 28):

**The problem:** Users say "thanks" in a post, which on SO is considered noise and not-useful.

**The solution:**: Create a button that allows users to say "thanks"

The fatal flaw being that it assumes the "thank you" button is a substitute for the comment. There's no reason to suspect that's the case, and in fact they could become complements, someone both posts "thanks" in a comment **and** clicks the thanks button. Seems like that just adds noise...

The button says "say thanks for this answer". If the intent is to deter comments from users who don't understand the SO rules how does this additional button teach them that "thanks" comments are inappropriate?

Comment: Plus, some people don't even find the button. They put a thanks comment.

Comment: Users without the ability to submit a comment,ignore multiple prompts and statements,that indicate they should NOT submit an answer in order to get around their inability to submit a comment. What makes this feature proposal, such a horrible idea is the incorrect assumption, that it will prevent “thank you” commentary or those horrible useless “thank you” commentary answers. In my experience it won’t matter. This feature will become a reality in order to be more welcoming to users who on purpose Ignore our rules and submit useless “thank you” commentary. Just like the automatic reopen feature.

Answer (score 27):

Okay, I've read through **103** answers and I don't think anyone has said this yet...

In addition to this "feature" being absolutely useless -- **IT IS ACTUALLY DOING HARM!**

An answer of mine (that was upvoted and accepted by the OP 3 years ago) was spontaneously unaccepted and thanked on the same day.

Here's the [answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43837686/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries):

[image]

I don't know where the "accept" record has gone, but I was alerted to my rep loss by my rep history.

[image]

[image]

### TURN THIS HORRIFIC FEATURE OFF ASAP!

Comment: Are you sure the unaccept was not triggered by your rewrite (although I can't judge from technical standpoint, the change does not seem defamatory)? That said, yes, the switch to "thanks" does not make much sense (probably "thanks" was pushed by someone else?)

Comment: You can see from the time stamps that the -15 and the thanks were 1 minute apart. The thanks was from the OP ("Learning and sharing"). Then I commented 2 hours later. Then I edited 3.5 hours after the thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot the reactions are public - it is indeed the same person (I now also see you edited after the change, thanks for pointing out) - well, that's certainly an alarming trend...

Comment: I wonder if SEDE can somehow identify how many answers were unaccepted and thanked within a 12 hour span.  (I suppose it is possible that a FGITW would get the green tick, then a better answer comes along, so the OP changes the green tick and thanks the FGITW.)

Comment: Good question, I guess not directly - can take a look, though. Votes table only has an "AcceptedByOriginator" field as far as I know, so that probably is too much to ask from SEDE. Re:FGITW - yeah, that can happen (I think we can all agree that's still quite useless)

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to see Thanks and Unaccept votes in SEDE. It's also unclear what exactly pushed OP to unaccept this answer in particular. It could be a mistake or maybe they reviewed it once more and decided it was wrong. They could not change the vote so they unaccepted. Who knows? However, it would be good to see how much harm did this new feature actually cause.

Comment: @Dharman - yep, upon rereviewing available options I guess not... I guess someone with site analytics access might know that? I think we can measure possible harm by measuring "percent of upvoted and / or accepted answers since announcement" + "average score of positively received answers since announcement"

Comment: I mean, the fact that people can deduce other people's actions due to this feature not being anonymous alone is a massive problem.

Comment: I am surprised to see people ready to lose their reputation (-2) by unaccepting the answer and tried this new feature. lol.

Comment: @Arun it is actually -15 rep when the green tick is removed.  I don't have any concern for rep anymore though.  The larger concern for me is that a clear preferred answer is not signified and the page is not deemed to be resolved by the system.

Comment: @mickmackusa I mean -2 for them. Yes -15 for answerer.

Comment: Indeed.  Good point.

Answer (score 26):

I completely agree with the other posts in that you should consult the community before implementing these "features". Stack Overflow is not a social network; it's a professional website.

I just wanted to point out the contradiction. You have made the change, again without asking the community, of changing the points awarded per upvote to a question from 5 to 10, the same as the answer.

So why should one only be able to say "thank you" to an answer, and not a question too, given that now, for you, both have the same importance?

(I don't want this feature at all. I am just pointing out this flaw.)

Comment: Many professional websites implement these features, so that's not really an argument just an attempt to support your preference against such features.

Comment: @Mr.Boy And those websites would be even more professional without them

Comment: That's your personal opinion only. The features presumably add some value if they're used. If you see a site where every article has no votes, we can assume it isn't useful :)

Comment: Obviously it's my personal opinion, just like yours is and every other answer/comment here. *The features presumably add some value if they're used* That's not the point, the point is that Stack Overflow would be more professional without them.

Comment: It's not 'professional' to add or change features based on community popularity, one could argue. If you're going to claim this feature is unprofessional, perhaps you can justify that opinion. There's a big difference between an opinion "I don't like it" and a reasoned position.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I don't see your justification for your claim that this feature *is* professional. At best I see an appeal to popularity "Other places use it, therefore it's professional".

Answer (score 25):

Another reason why this is bad is that users could use it ironically.

You can downvote an answer and react "Thank you" ironically. Have an answer with downvotes and "Thank you" reactions, like "Thank you for nothing".

I can imagine this happening...

Comment: Some users in the community are real evil. This is so matching. I didn't thought about this. Good concern.

Comment: It's a real alternative to "I downvoted because..", just without the "because.."

Comment: @Scratte Except who reacts is [public](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227902/timeline) (unless that's what you meant...)

Comment: @Nick So are the "I downvoted because..", "-1. Bad answer", etc.. comments :)

Comment: With the  emoji, it seems like an excellent way to say "bless this mess". :)

Comment: I am starting to use it combined with a downvote meaning basically "thanks for trying, but this is not the way"

Comment: `"Thank you" ironically` and `thanks for trying`. Great. Two actions with an opposite meaning. SO useful.

Answer (score 25):

This new feature is torpedoing the up-and-down vote mechanism. If the answers warrants an extra praise then we can give it bounty points. This is how I handled Stack Overflow the past few years.

Answer (score 24):

For me, the most important takeaway that SE Inc. can learn here:

**do not return to your old habits of dropping stuff on us**!

It is that simple: SE Inc. has spent a lot of work and energy to get back to a more transparent "process", and emphasized repeatedly that it wants **us** users to be involved.

Now this. It feels like we are back in 2019 and you drop this on us.

Comment: Isn't this only a test?

Comment: @ZevSpitz it seems to be an A/B Test of whether to use Clap or Praying for thanks (they already added these to Teams & Jobs so I would hazard that rolling this back is not an option)

Comment: @LinkBerest, maybe they could make it an A/B/C test by adding U+1F595 to the set of options.

Answer (score 23):

The more I think about it the more I see the problem, but I still don't think this is the best solution to it. There is a better one.

First I looked at the numbers. The increase over time is not very strong but 15-20% of 75 million comments (that are still in the database) means at least 11 million thanks-comments generated, that's a lot.

Currently in the database are only 2.5 million comments with "thank" in it. That means that at least 8 million comments had to be deleted (probably not completely automatically??). That may have been a lot of work.

Of the 2.5 million comments with "thank" in it, that remain, are probably many comments that are longer and include the thanks only as a side thing.

Indeed there is a particular [dependence on length](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1253378/comments-with-thank-vs-their-length#graph) for the still existing thanks-comments. In particular one sees that at the length of 51 and 61 some thresholds kicked in.

[image]

But there are also comments with less than size 20 still present. They should probably have been deleted.

[image]

The problem with the proposed solution is that it competes with up/downvotes, clutters the UI, may be confusing to some users and may be too impersonal to be preferred over thanks in comments.

I think the idea should be instead to continue to do, what has been done so far, just more automatically.

We have this wonderful unfriendly comments detection software and from what I hear it works great. Now, automatically detecting pure thanks comments may even be less a complex task, so maybe even higher success rates could be expected. We would have even more training data than for the unfriendly comments robot.

With some training we could probably detect pure-thanks comments automatically while they are created (or right after the comment edit period times out).

We then could ask the creator to voluntarily time-limit their comment (to some reasonable time limit like say 1-3 days or less). That would mean that the thanks author is invited to self time limit its comment (due to the not being very useful nature, but still a thanks is something positive). Such comments would then be marked for auto-deletion and would also be displaying as "soon to be gone, please don't flag unless you need it gone immediately". If the author is not agreeing, he might be invited to explain why it should stay and then the decision is forwarded to a mod, who might delete the comment immediately or let it live. That way the decision is with humans all the time.

This should be much less work than is used now and would solve most of the problems as far as I can see them.

An alternative to time-limitation of thanks comments would be moving them to a dedicated comments section (maybe below the normal comment, in a lighter color, collapsed by default). See Zev Spitz's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/111794/zev-spitz) for details.

Just some comment on methodology of this test: In order to follow good practice, one should also state how a success or failure of the test will be estimated already when announcing the test (here probably how many thanks were given and how many thanks-comments were not created). That allows people to comment on it and prevents the conductors from arbitrarily moving the goalposts when making a final decision.

I hope that an alternative solution like the one proposed in this answer will finally be implemented. If not, I hope there will be at least some way to opt out and keep the UI more focused on the more important things.

---

P.S.: Indeed, already in 2014 in [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) Andy implemented such a system and could detect thanks comments more or less in real time. The technology was there and the idea was there for at least six years.

Comment: "*With some training we could probably detect pure-thanks comments automatically while they are created.*" my **only** issue with that is that they probably shouldn't be blocked automatically. It's possible to comment "thanks" then edit in "Can you explain X?", for example. However, that can be very easily solved by only (internally) marking the comment as a "thanks". Re-evaluate this on edit. After the edit window has closed - either immediately after, or the next midnight or next week or whatever, then the comment can be automatically swept.

Comment: It seems that the "wonderful unfriendly comments detection software" seems to detect friendly comments as unfriendly, so.. I really think this robot needs some tweaking.

Comment: @Scratte Making mistakes is not an argument against using the robot. Humans make mistakes too and they only claims it's as good as human flags are. In the end, a moderator has the last say and is the gold standard. Detecting thanks sounds a bit easier to me than detecting unfriendliness (which might come in more different ways). Also you can tweak the thresholds so that less positive cases are detected accompanied by even less negative ones. That would still help. They have the technology for it already in use for a more difficult subject, they only need to use it for this one too.

Comment: "With some training we could probably detect pure-thanks comments automatically while they are created (or right after the comment edit period times out)." - That has already been done. I [did it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/189134) years ago and tuned it to be very accurate. I could catch these comments as soon as they appeared in the API.

Comment: Another note on methodology - the announcement should state how long the test will take - even a shrug of the god is better than utter silence. Prevents the testers from running the "test" indefinitely and claiming they're still gathering data whenever asked way down the road.

Comment: @JohnDvorak That it did "We’ll be monitoring usage and other data over the next month". It's one month. And now they also posted some criteria about how to [judge the outcome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398909/data-validation-background-for-the-thank-you-reaction-feature-test?cb=1).

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the link. I must have seen it because I had it upvoted. Six years is quite some time. It's a pity that nobody continued with your work back then.

Comment: What if, instead of deleting "thanks" comments, all comments would be automatically typed as "comment" or "reaction", and reactions would be distinguished in the UI? 1. "Reactions" should be collapsed by default (even when there are no other comments), and only shown by pressing a "Show reactions" link, next to the "Show x comments" of today. 2. Different formatting for reaction comments even when expanded -- indent the comment itself, perhaps a lighter foreground color.  This wouldn't compete with voting, wouldn't add a vague icon to the UI, and not limit being personal or impersonal.

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's also a possibility. Will add it for reference. It's also mentioned in other answers. Problem would be to draw the line between reaction and comment. It's possible but you know, people are people and may see things different. "Why did the system classify my comment only as a reaction...?"

Comment: Yes, but I think there's far less drama around "The algorithm decided my comment was a reaction!" vs. "A user / moderator / other annoying person went ahead and deleted my comments, because they were personal!" And it still looks that way even if deleted automatically.

Answer (score 22):

Please remove this feature as soon as you can!

I answered 5 questions today, and of those 5 answers, 3 of them got upvoted + accepted. Great. But then the fourth and fifth one got a "thanks" reaction **and** a comment saying "thank you for your help!".

The things wrong with this feature:

1. It doesn't decrease the amount of "thank you" comments
2. It is robbing people of their deserved reputation.
3. It is completely and utterly useless, **and** answers that deserve to go to the top don't.
4. I have also seen a post that wouldn't be out of place on facebook. Apparently  one user thought SO was a social media, and he put a programming meme as an answer. This feature is confusing new users **even more than usual**.

So again, please remove this feature ASAP.

Comment: When I upvoted this answer, the system showed me a pop-up saying, *"You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!"* Can we have a pop-up when "Thanks" is clicked, along the lines of, *"Thanks for your Thanks reaction. If this answer has helped you, then consider upvoting it. Thanks."*?

Comment: @Adrian Mole Yes, that is viable, but some people dont have enough rep to upvote, and majority of the users that ask questions dont even bother reading those, at least in my experience.

Comment: @AdrianMole I noticed that popup too. Another useless feature. If I want to upvote more answers than questions because I consider them more useful then it's my own personal decision. Will SO really force me to what shall I upvote? It is **our** decision.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio IIRC, I don't think it is possible to cast your *entire* daily vote quota solely on either Qs or As. I think there *has* to some of both if you want to use them all.

Comment: @AdrianMole I vote on many questions and I like to do so, but what I want to say is, why SE constantly keep warning me about this if I want to upvote answers to these question/post for example. I notice this behavior specially here on Meta. Maybe because the question is so much downvoted?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio No, it's because of the "Not enough questions are upvoted.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Plus, from the 40 votes, **at least** 10 must be spent on questions.

Answer (score 22):

I think this option will reduce the number of upvotes. It will confuse new contributors and it is just a dupe of the upvote button. Also there is no minimum reputation to say thanks, so anybody can do it. **This button does not carry useful functionality and it is absolutely unnecessary**.

Don't add it to [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) please! And if you can, delete it from Stack Overflow too. It will be the only correct solution!

Answer (score 22):

I'm sorry for adding an answer when there are already 93 of them, but I skimmed and none of them really seemed to bring up my point.

The people who usually read Meta are SO power users, which is understandable. I've been on here a few times to read some stuff, but I'm mostly an average SO user in that I don't do anything special with the community.

From that perspective, I saw these new icons and was very confused. I upvote answers that are good and answer the question or help me in some way, so I saw the "thanks" button and didn't know what was expected of me. I found this post linked in the sidebar of SO and it also doesn't answer my question. When exactly am I supposed to upvote instead of thanking, or vice versa? Am I supposed to do both? It seems like thanking has zero implications other than a counter on the page, so what purpose does it actually serve?

Comment: Judging from this question/announcement here, I would say that the intended purpose was to replace thanks comments. So whenever you would have posted a thanks comment, you would be supposed to use the button instead (independently of any voting).

Answer (score 21):

I just don't see "Thanks!" comments as a problem. A quick flag gets rid of them and takes little to no time while boosting your flag count, leaving them there doesn't hurt anything, people who can leave said comments already have the ability to upvote, just seems... not all that great of a reason for this.

The implementation of it seems to miss the mark too. It's a tiny grey icon in an area you wouldn't expect to see this feature. I'd expect to see it right above the comments section and colorful with multiple reaction options, not all inherently positive or negative... and anonymous. It's not important enough to be displayed left of the post.

Comment: In other words... if we're gonna get reactions, give us reactions, not pseudo votes.

Answer (score 19):

I find this a nice example on how it doesn't work:

- OP has now 3 options to pick from (+1, answer, thanks). Ironically, marking as accepted might be even overseen
- They will leave the thanks comment anyway

Here's an example, see the up-vote + thank you, while not marked as accepted - which can be fine, but then check OP's comment:

[image: Answer score of 1, and one thank you.]
[image: thank u Stephan , you save my life.]

Answer (score 19):

It saddens me to submit answer #106, but here we are. Perhaps the decision to lock-out comments on the question (and force comments to be submitted as answers) is as wise as the decision to devote company resources to producing this feature. I hope I'm not adding duplicate commentary, but I barely have time for this, let alone reading through 105 answers. Normally I do read through everything first, but 105?

Here are some thoughts:

1. Are "Thank You" comments truly that large of a pain-point as to warrant this much attention?
2. I realize that the description given in the original post is not meant to be highly technical, but how strict / fuzzy was the search for "thank" in comments?

   - Was it whole-word only? Partial word? Would "thanksgiving" be considered a match?
   - What about comments that include "thank(s| you)" *and* contain additional, relevant info that falls within the acceptable use guidelines?
   - Was the poster of the comment taken into account? I often thank people for leaving feedback on my answers, whether positive or negative. Would that match your query? Clearly my comments of "thanks" on my own answers wouldn't be considered opportunities that someone could have instead clicked a "thank you" button, right?
3. How would this feature be adopted? Why would the group of people that are a) leaving "thanks" comments, and b) *not* upvoting instead of saying "thanks" be any more likely to use this feature? If the behavior you're trying to correct is due to not reading the rules, then how would the target audience ever find out that this new option should be done instead of what they have been doing? And if they read the rules in order to know to now use this feature, then wouldn't they already know that they should instead upvote and don't need this feature?
4. The entire goal of this feature is based on false logic. The stated goal is (slightly edited for brevity):

   > We hope that this test will ... reduce:
   >
   > - People upset when their comments are deleted,
   > - Time <del>spent</del> wasted managing/flagging/deleting comments.

   This line of reasoning has the implied assumption that "thank you" comments are bad / clutter. True, this is stated in the guidelines, but is that *really* the correct / best way to view "thank you" comments? Perhaps the S.O. community can adopt a less negative view of this behavior? Which would mostly cancel out the need for this feature.
5. I did read in one answer (or maybe it was a comment?) something about "anonymous" upvotes (upvotes that don't count). Perhaps this feature could be made useful by re-purposing it as a counter of people who wanted to upvote but either didn't log in or didn't have enough rep to actually vote. This scenario requires the following changes:

   1. People do not click on the "thank you" icon. It is merely a counter.
   2. If someone hovers over the "thank you" icon, a tooltip / label displays:
      **Anonymous upvotes / thank yous: xxxxx**
   3. If a person clicks on the "thank you" icon, it displays:
      **Please say "thank you" by upvoting this answer.**
   4. If a person upvotes and is either not logged in or doesn't have enough rep to vote, increase the "thank you" count *and* display a message stating that the upvote was being recorded as a "thank you".
   5. The default message / hint in the comment box is currently:

      > "Say thanks by [reacting] to [the] answer"

      Why is it assumed that people will understand what "react" means? And why say "the" answer instead of "this" answer? Either way, this hint should be changed to:
      **Say thanks by upvoting this answer.**

      or even:
      **Say thanks by clicking the up arrow to the left of this answer.**

      The more clearly you state the desired behavior, the more likely it will be that people actually follow it.
6. (new) Did anyone ever consider that maybe only a simple update to the default text / hint of the comment area was needed? The default is currently:

   > ... Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

   That is explaining what you do *not* want, but does not indicate what you *do* want (at least not with regards to "thanks" comments). Again, a little bit of clarification goes a long way. For example:
   **... Avoid comments like "+1". Please up-vote this answer to say "thanks".**

Comment: +1. I came to this question couple of times in the past but have not read all answers (100+ ..smh). I noticed we thought on the same line.. and I posted this couple of days back - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399904/7920473

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The feature **[broke the duplicate close vote dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398876/1048572)**: when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it does cast a reaction on the answer to the selected canonical target instead of closing the question. This is highly counterintuitive and does cause reactions that were never intended, nor does it become visible what happened (unless you get an error message because the accepted answer was your own).

Comment: So _that’s_ what it was! That’s why I had reactions on my profile that I don’t remember casting. I assumed this only happened when the duplicate was also closed by Community. Mystery solved.

Comment: Oh gods! I thought I was going senile as I thought Enter would submit the duplicate but all it seemed to do now was refresh the view. This is extremely bad.

Answer (score 18):

Possible bug report: I was told to thank someone else, on an answer that was mine:

[image]

Posted here as recommended [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398376/why-am-i-being-told-to-thank-others-for-their-answers-when-its-my-answer)

Comment: Oh you! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, it's clearly just a notification saying "Hey look, a new feature is available that you haven't seen before, here it is"

Comment: Well, to me it reads like a reminder or a call to action, but why does my own answer have a thanks button on it? Or vote buttons, for that matter

Comment: You didn't read the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398376/why-am-i-being-told-to-thank-others-for-their-answers-when-its-my-answer#comment775698_398376)? It's not a bug. You deserve it. Won't you feel better if you thank yourself? :D

Comment: It needs to be there on your own answers so that you can see how many reactions it has.

Comment: @Andreas if I do it too soon, I'm worried it might mean I'm starting to suffer from premature congratulation

Answer (score 18):

I think that the whole perspective of the "thanks" messages in the comments is wrong. You'll never be able to replace human thanks messages with a button or some counter. This is why regardless the up votes we can still see the "thanks" comments. Peoples like to say "thank you" in a human way, and not in a counter way. Instead of trying to eliminate the human needs to say "thanks" with a counter, change the feature so it will include an option for "thanks messages section". This way you can clear the "professional comments" under the response, and the "thanks comments" in a separate place (maybe some kind of small popup window beside the new button).

You might also make a bot that will move every "thanks" message that already exists into this section, or to add an optional flag to move these comments into the new comments section.

Comment: I completely agree with "People like to say 'thank you' in a human way, and not in a counter way". However, I'm not sure about a "thanks messages section". There isn't much interest in seeing a section only with people thanking. Also, the bot approach might not work well, since someone can comment something like "Thanks, but this answer doesn't work for me because [...]".

Comment: @D.Pardal I think this section have to be for more detailed "thanks". To explain how did this answer help them, etc.. And about the bot- I didn't say that it'll be easy to program one. I might even require some ML within it, but I do believe it is possible to create one.

Comment: I completely agree with this. Thank you messages are wonderful to read for whoever posted the answer, but maybe just noise for everybody else. It would be great if we can encourage thank you messages without cluttering comments. An emoji is not nearly as nice as an actual thank you message.

Answer (score 17):

There already are many answers. So it's hard to write one that still adds some value. But I'll try:

## This is *fractally bad*

(which means that it's bad on *every level of analysis*)

The problem with this kind of thing is that it's tremendously hard to argue against it, or to even suggest improvements. You can argue why it's bad on *one* level, but in the attempt to do so, would have to address all other levels.

- One could question the way how this feature was introduced on a *methodological* level - namely the fact that the "community" wasn't even asked about it.
- One could question the goals that are supposed to be achieved on the "community level" and the interactions here - but not without diving deeply into an analysis of the root causes of the problems that are supposed to be solved (one of them certainly related to educating new users about how this site works...)
- One could question the feature on a "process level", e.g. why users are not notified about a "Thank you" - but not without raising questions about technical drawbacks like notification spam, or alternative implementations
- One could point out the negative side-effects on a "system level", e.g having downvoted answers with many 'thanks' - What should that even mean?
- One could mention the possibilities for abuse and sock-puppeting on the level of individuals
- ...
- One could criticize it on the level of the UI, like the icons that are currently used (which, in the worst case might suggest that it could be fixed with other icons...  )

And this list could go on and on (see the other answers for further details on different levels). There is not really a "line of argumentation". The argumentation would rather have to be a "tree", for that matter.

---

However, I'd like to address one point (that was already mentioned in other answers), and which is on the lowest level, in that it also stands at *the beginning* of the process that led to the current situation:

**What is the *metric* that is used to justify the introduction of this feature?**

The initial post (and the blog post) seem to indicate that the underlying metric was not more than a plain, dumb word count. (And please correct me if I'm wrong). It's true that comments that only say "Thank you" should be avoided or deleted, and are pure clutter compared to upvoting and accepting answers. But **iff** this there was no deeper analysis about the *context* of the `thank` word, then it might just be that instead of writing comments like

> The question was about framework X and not Y

people nowadays write

> Thank you, but the question was about framework X and not Y

or instead of

> @otherUser : I fixed the typo that you pointed out

are now writing

> Thanks @otherUser: I fixed the typo that you pointed out

There is absolutely no conclusion that can be drawn from the mere appearance of this word. There is not even a reason to *assume* that any conclusion can be drawn from that. But even *if* there was a reasonable, correct conclusion to be drawn, we still wouldn't be at the point where we could argue about whether or how this conclusion could profoundly justify *any* actions *in general*, or the implementation of this feature in its current form in particular. This is just incomprehensible for me.

Answer (score 16):

My understanding of your assumptions and intentions is this:

- The *thanks* button is for those who:

  - can upvote and want to do more than that,
  - cannot upvote due to lack of reputation.
- A relevant portion of upvotes comes from users who only want to indicate that something is good (but not directly useful to them) and help [separate the wheat from the chaff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/separate_the_wheat_from_the_chaff#Verb). (I doubt that this is correct, but that’s only an experienced guess and the test should show this.)

If the above is correct, I see some [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) problems here:

- For users with voting privileges, the *thanks* button is a “super upvote” in some sense; it does not make sense for them to thank without upvoting. Hence the expected placement of the *thanks* button would be above the *upvote* button, not below it. Furthermore, to avoid confusion or people forgetting to vote, thanking should be coupled to an upvote. Either you automatically upvote when thanking or you only see the *thanks* button after upvoting.
- For users without the voting privilege, *thanks* is the only button that they reasonably would want to use. Yet, it is sandwiched by other buttons useless to them (assuming they don’t care about the timeline). Again, it makes sense to place it on top. Putting myself in the position of such a user (sorry if this reads a bit childish):

  > That answer is great, what can I do about it?
  >
  > There are some things on the left that seem important.
  > I guess that number is the score; let’s increase that.
  > That doesn’t work because I don’t have reputation yet; point taken.
  >
  > So what’s next?
  > I don’t want to decrease the score and if I can’t increase, I probably can’t decrease either.
  >
  > Whatever, I guess that entire bar is not for me yet.
  >
  > [Bonus, if we have the author of the question, who already accepted another answer:]
  > Ooh, I can leave a comment; let’s deliver a personal message of thanks.

Comment: note there is one category of users who can't upvote but are able to post thanks comments - these are question askers, because they can comment under answers to their questions at any rep level (in my experience this seems to be major source of useless thanks I observe in comments)

Comment: *"it does not make sense for them to thank without upvoting"* - Not strictly true, there's plenty times I've seen answers that I find interesting in one form or another that don't warrant an upvote..., like link only answers to great resources, they're the ones that get a "neat", or an "oh, that's cool".

Comment: @gnat: I know, see my very last paragraph.

Comment: @gnat, Wouldn't it make more sense to let askers vote on answers to their questions? Or does that make it too easy for the sock puppets?

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky It's already too easy and letting them vote would make it even easier. I can create two new accounts and get both of them to 15 rep without any external interference in under a minute, probably (haven't tested it).

Comment: @Nick: Is that really a relevant case that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I didn't say I _agreed_ with needing to account for it, I'm perfectly happy continuing with my personal dialogues rather than needing a button for it :p, just that it's not accurate to say it doesn't make sense to want to thank an answer without upvoting

Comment: The problem doing this, is that it teaches new users into that "SO is personal", taking away from the goal of making it a repository of content, not people. SO is not a social media. It teaches new users that on SO, you thank people.

Comment: @Nick "answers that I find interesting in one form or another that don't warrant an upvote..., like link only answers to great resources" seem to me like they _do_ warrant and upvote. They might not be the accepted answer, yet they were, as the tooltip suggests "helpful". If such are from presumably experienced users you comment should, instead, be a reminder to "flesh out" the answer. If it's from a new user, perhaps take the time to help them adjust to SO and comment and/or edit the answer to show what a good answer would look like from the information they provided. It's still a helpful one

Comment: btw, the thanking user is revealed by the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/750506/timeline).

Answer (score 16):

tl;dr: the system should notify the answerer when the asker thanks their answer, so as to make it feel more personal.

---

### From my perspective as an asker

I will admit that in the past, I have written "thanks" comments on various Stack Exchange sites. However, the only time I can remember doing so is when someone answers *my* question. I wish to explicitly and clearly let them know that I, as the question asker, have read their answer and appreciate how helpful it is. To reiterate: **I want to *notify* them that *I* appreciate them.** Upvoting does not accomplish this, because upvotes are anonymous. Accepting kind of accomplishes this, but I can only accept one answer per question. Accepting also feels very devoid of the *emotion* that I wish to convey. Commenting is currently the only way I can get my feelings across.

### From my perspective as an answerer

Most of my activity on Stack Overflow as answering questions. I don't do this because I want my number to go up. I do this because *I like helping people*. If I don't get feedback on an answer, I don't know if it helped, and if feels like a waste. If I get an upvote or two, that could be random people clicking on the question, seeing an answer that looks about right, and giving a quick upvote before moving on. When my answer gets accepted, it still *fells* very emotionless. The notification is simply a number:

[image]

On Stack Overflow, the best feeling that I get is when I click on my inbox and see something like this:

[image]

This says to me than an *actual human being* used my answer and I have made a *real difference in their life*, however small. To me, a comment of "thanks" on someone else's answer looks like noise. But on my answer, it's a connection with another human.

### Speculation

While I can't speak for everyone else, I would suspect that many people feel similarly. People aren't robots, and while Stack Overflow's model is good for the people who click a link from Google Search, it falls flat for the participants who have yet to become jaded by the lack of humanity on the platform. I suspect that many people write "thanks" for reasons at least similar to mine, or at the very least to not appear ungrateful.

With the current implementation of this new "thanks" button, the only way to notice you've been thanked is by actively going to your answers one by one. To see who thanked you, you have to click a fairly obscure button and then search through a list of all actions on the post, most of which are unrelated.

### Solution?

Just to throw out some ideas, I'm sure other people can think of better things.

- When the questioner thanks an answer, the answerer could get a notification like "Fred Smith has thanked you for your answer to How To XYZ."
- Maybe these notifications could be bundled together for highly active people, e.g. "4 people have thanked you for your answers yesterday."
- For people who just care about rep, maybe there could be an option to disable these notifications.

Comment: The pleasure of helping is a really good point - it would be really nice to be able to hear how something I'd taken the time to write up helped someone else out.  That would bring me happiness and increase my engagement with the site.

And I've really wanted to be able to say "thank you so much, this absolutely saved my life" on occasions when an answer with no existing upvotes on some highly niche issue has really got me out of a hole

Comment: Re *"I do this because I like helping people."*: That is good. This is why Stack Overflow Helpdesk could actually work (and relieve the tension with beginners on Stack Overflow), despite the scepticism here on Meta. Have you supported [some of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983/create-a-separate-independent-advanced-so-focusing-on-being-a-knowledge-library) [the proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396479/how-can-we-stop-failing-the-users-who-we-actually-want-to-join-and-remain-as-m/398120#comment774538_398120)?

Answer (score 16):

This feature seems useful in theory, but in practice it is completely useless.

> Using this data and user research, we're introducing this clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions.

Well, let me give a few examples of answers that helped the OP, and they didn't click the thanks button, but put a comment saying thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62473744/12708583

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62537680/12708583(check the post history to see).

Instead we could spend our time doing neccessary things, such as fixing the triage review, or restricting comments from having only "thanks" in them.

> to just say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions.

Is that implying to say "thanks" to a bad answer? The amount of time spent making an answer is not at **all** related to the quality of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is really helpful.

Comment: @RobertColumbia lol

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky At first I thought the hands were reffering to prayer.

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky Yes, I am indian, and in india, that is used as greeting.

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky some people actually do it - they put their hands against each other and then take a deep bow - that's why the emoji was chosen.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest that if you want to decrease the number of "thank you" comments and not decrease the number of votes, you should put the "thank you" button on the bottom in the comments section, not near the voting buttons.

Answer (score 16):

It is a very nice idea to decrease *thanks* comments for answers, but the way it is going to be done is not correct.

As you said:

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers

But now, we, the users, discovered that “thanks” appears in ***every*** answer without any exception!

Besides, it doesn't add any valuable feature to this website. Just adding another step for saying an answer is helpful.

Let's consider its usage in another way:

- We already had *accept answer* and it just is a feature for OP.
- We had *upvote* which is a feature for everybody who thinks an answer is helpful.
- Now we have *thanks* which **again** is a feature for everybody who thinks an answer is helpful.

What is the difference? Without considering reputation for upvoting, this feature is just another step for helpful answers.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with many of the other answers here that the "thanks" action **placed next to** the **"voting" actions** can cause people to say thanks instead of voting and is probably a bad idea.

I also think that saying thanks is redundant, that's what the votes are for - If the answer (or question) is useful, vote it up. If the answer or question is wrong, misleading or irrelevant, vote it down.

I suggested **moving the "thanks" action** to **next to the "comment"** action, since it is meant to reduce "thank you" comments. I.e. [add a comment](http://stackoverflow.com) or [say thanks](http://stackoverflow.com). Perhaps clicking on the "say thanks" should simply vote up (or do nothing if user already did that)?!

Also, why are there two strange variations - a **"washing hands emoji"** and a **"praying emoji"** instead of a "thumbs up" which I usually see associated with thanks?! In real life does anyone actually clap to thank someone who wasn't on stage?! - Don't you usually say it or sign it with your thumb?

Answer (score 15):

***IF*** this goes ahead, you should have to upvote or downvote before being given the option to 'thank'.

That being said...

I can't think of any useful behaviours to encourage from the thanks button though...do we want one thanks per question? That sounds like it should be the accept button. Should it be on every answer? Then there's no point on using thanks as a metric(?). It reminds me of [Goodhart's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law):

> When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure.

Why turn some harmless comments into a target by making people click on a button?

Answer (score 15):

My analysis:

1. Someone in the team feels like "You know what? Let me leave a legacy and create something people can see. Performance improvement at the backend no one really notices. So how about 'cool' feature on the front end?"

Or

2. "It has been long time since I pitched innovative idea, so let me try to put this one down to management. My "thank you" innovation"

It seems like there was nothing to innovate, so they did this. Because it feels everyone thinks these days you *have* to *add* something to make it perfect. How about *removing* something? How about not doing anything at all sometimes? I understand constant urge to "release" something so that market won't forget you exist, but how about a little wait for some "solid" innovation rather than just "brush here and there" things?

By the way, there was no great painting made before artists decided to put a brush down.

Comment: Note, that this probably was something that corporate (paying) users wanted, and they just figured "lets try it in public Q&A".

Comment: SE probably felt that if they don't do things like fixing triage, they will have more users at their base, ready for innovation.

Answer (score 15):

As a frequent question asker and serial thanker, this adds nothing. The reason I thank in the comments is because an upvote is anonymous and accepting is kind of impersonal. I want to identify myself as the asker and express my gratitude *in addition* to upvoting and accepting. Answerers are real people and taking the time to write thank you is a much 'realer' interaction than all of the other options.

Comment: The thanks reaction is public: one can see who thanked a particular post by inspecting the timeline. But indeed it doesn't change the fact that it may be seen as impersonal, and my experience so far shows that they're still leaving "thank you" comments anyway.

Comment: *" write thank you is a much 'realer' interaction"* - for anyone who is not aware how things works here. Take a tour, search meta "how I say thanks". I am used to look into people eyes in real conversation, should we make here eyes for each user so me feel "realer"?

Comment: _accepting is kind of impersonal_. This site is not a social media site. If you accept and upvote the answer, then the user who answered will be happy(I know I am). Plus, when you thank an answer, they still don't know who you are.

Comment: While I don't approve your attitude towards cluttering comment sections, this answer is pretty insightful so catch the upvote. But seriously, stop thanking in comments. Mods have enough work without it.

Comment: _"The reason I thank in the comments is because an upvote is anonymous"_ So is the thanking. You can't tell who thanked your post, can you?

Comment: @10Rep You can. On the post timeline. The little clock-thing under the voting and thank-you on the left side of an answer.

Comment: @Hold on, let me check

Comment: @Scratte Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 15):

I'm glad a lot of features are being planned for this site. May I ask when they will be enabled? All of them are greyed out, which is a typical indicator that these cannot be clicked.

- move item up: disabled
- move item down: disabled
- badge: disabled
- time machine: disabled
- clap hands: disabled

[image: Disabled]

Also:

- hard drive: disabled
- trophy: disabled
- checklist: disabled
- help: disabled
- conversation stack: disabled

[image: Disabled 2]

</sarcasm>

I have learned that disabled things look grey since I started programming with VB3. I know that the times of fancy colorful icons are over. I also appreciate the trend to more simplistic icons. But I really struggle with grey icons. There's only one thing that's worse: icons that are invisible until you hover over them.

In the example above, please note that this site already contradicts itself.

- The action items on questions and answers are grey when they are intended to be clicked. They become colorful when you should *not* click it anymore.
- The other icons (inbox etc.) are colorful when they are intended to be clicked and grey when there's nothing of interest.

If you wonder why people don't use the site as expected, that would be the place I'd look for.

Comment: Your "hard drive" is actually the "Inbox" :)

Comment: Good call. It can give the impression the buttons/icons were disabled **or** not important.

Answer (score 14):

I just read over the blog and had some thoughts:

> We’ve heard from our users that the inability to say “thank you” is frustrating—especially for new users who don’t have enough reputation to upvote or comment. Even when users gain these privileges, they still want to say “thanks.”

1. There is a preexisting mechanism to say "thank you" in the form of up voting and accepting answers.
2. If the problem is that new users can't get 15 rep - the bar for which isn't high; 1 accepted answer *or* 2 up voted questions *or* 2 up voted answers - to up vote then consider:

   - Removing that restriction to up vote *or*
   - Leave this requirement and expect users to unlock this not so hard privilege.

> As it exists today, Stack Overflow doesn’t provide a way for users to just say “thank you” and show others appreciation for taking the time to answer their questions.

How can you say that? It's almost as though the people behind these features haven't read the help center or know how the site works (yes, I'm being hyperbolic, well, to some extent):

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – **not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!** - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Further on, you state:

> We’ve heard from our users that the inability to say “thank you” is frustrating—especially for new users who don’t have enough reputation to upvote or comment. Even when users gain these privileges, they still want to say “thanks.”

Why do you keep repeating this claim? You ***can*** say "thank you". Hit the up vote.

> Based on this data and user research, we’ve decided to test a simple, clutter-free way to say thanks—a reaction button on answers across Stack Overflow.

How did you reach the conclusion that reactions is the correct answer? Surely it would make more sense to work on making voting more prominent or emphasising it further?

Answer (score 13):

If this would actually reduce the amount of "thanks" in comments it would be nice, but I am skeptical that will happen. I am however afraid that even if it does that it will have a negative effect on the amount of people upvoting, as the clapping emote is clearly the cooler thing to click (I just learned from the comments the other one means high-five, I always thought it meant prayer, as that is the only context I have ever seen it in, which seems inappropriate here).

Now getting fewer upvotes is a problem, and not just for your reputation. We measure the usefulness of a post by its upvotes, if fewer upvotes are garnered the system won't be as effective in pointing people searching for a question to the most useful answers. So my question is will the amount of "likes" affect an internal "score" of a question/answer, so will a Q/A with 500 likes be equal to a question with 500 upvotes as far as the system is concerned?

Also the users without 15 reputation **can** vote, unlike what the post is saying. The only *difference* being that their vote isn't recorded *visibly*. As per the tooltip of a < 15 rep user voting

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

As *cleared up* by Nick in the meta chatroom, these "recorded" votes are in reality just token votes that don't do anything at all, as explained [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account).

Answer (score 13):

If this is to try and "lower" the number of "thanks" comments we get, then make it so that when someone does put a "thanks" comment they are instead told to use the "thanks" button at least. Implementing this, and then not enforcing its use on "thanks" comments is completely pointless.

I've seen several users say "thanks" in the comments today, yet none had even a single thanks counter against them.

This is such a waste of Stack Overflow Development time that could have been spent on fixing/improving things that user *want*.

Comment: I agree. Just now I answered a questions and the user said thanks.

Answer (score 13):

1. **IF** the feature is meant to '***help***' for those who can't ***upvote***, the feature may as well be limited to only them. But I feel, it is pointless to have a feature only for some users.
2. Users (especially ***new users***) shouldn't get habituated to dropping a *Thanks* and then stop upvoting or accepting the answers. Because, the best way to show appreciation is to upvote it, it increases reputation of the user who have answered.
3. If a user has received 100 *Thanks* but his reputation is `< 100`, what does it convey? Though his answers are helpful, he didn't practially gain any reputation. He may ***at best*** have a *badge* for receiving 100 *Thanks*.

   But then, as a workaround, you may be introducing, say for every *Thanks* there is a `+2` or `+5` reputation, but doesn't it contradict with upvote again?
4. If an answer, apart from the accepted answer, is helpful, then the OP can drop a *comment* saying ***how it is helpful*** **along with saying *Thanks*** in the comment. In this way, the comment is useful for both appreciation and also for adding some insight to the answer, which SO is already doing now, by displaying a message.

Answer (score 13):

By now we have witnessed several cases where the feature didn't work. Users still leave comments because they want something more personal than a reaction to thank the answerer. And we're seemingly also bound to find answers which were not upvoted even though a "thank you" was presented by the OP in some way. As the days go by, I feel a steadfast assertion that this feature does not belong on Stack Overflow.

However, maybe there is a niche use case for this reaction that could prove useful.

#### How about having it only for Meta Stack Overflow?

Although I do not hold a strong opinion on this, here are the current reasons I thought so far:

- Unlike the main site, the voting culture on Meta is *very different*. Upvotes and downvotes represent a mishmash-combination of research effort, value, and agreement to the propositions at hand. It's a bit messy, all right. The "Thank you" reaction here may provide a more interesting signal than votes in some circumstances. For example, answers proposing things that the community clearly does not want are opinions all the same, and there is value in keeping them listed, even if representing a problem in themselves.
- We regularly face reports of users feeling emotionally distressed and [having panic attacks and nightmares](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387939) when bringing something to Meta. This applies to Stack Overflow employees too. Receiving a few "thank you" reactions might soothe the nerves of those who simply were looking for feedback and attempting to contribute.
- No reputation is involved here, so there are no problematic side-effects of people choosing to hit the thank you button instead of the upvote button.
- The community wants *more people on Meta*, so that the opinions expressed here become more aligned with those of the active user base. Presenting a simple, noise-free way of thanking users for posts on Meta could help that, precisely as an attempt to boost engagement.
- It's not like we don't have a bit more of leeway on Meta anyway. Comments in particular may be deleted all the same, but have a look around posts on Meta and the chances of finding some gems are good. Likewise, I suppose we might as well have the luxury to be more lenient on reactions as we are on comments. Relevant question: [What are the guidelines for comments on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355556)

Naturally, one would expect a trial phase all the same, to see if it helps at all to increase engagement on Meta and make the overall experience here more positive.

Comment: This is very sensible. Something like a "Yay" and "Nay" reactions to signify agreement and disagreement can be practical. A lot of first time meta posters assume that a negative score on their proposal means anything more than "I disagree with this" and, yes, that it's some sort of punishment for *daring* to post here. Also, it can serve a double purpose. I am personally using the thanks feature to "bookmark" *answers* so I can get to them easier. It is sometimes simpler than bookmarking a question and trying to remember why. So, you can react to a post to also find it easier.

Answer (score 13):

I think you should have noticed that we have already had something like this for questions for ages:
[image]
When I click the "favourite" button (which is more confusing in the new look than in the old one though), I say my thanks to the author of the question for making the question. I don't wish this gesture affect the reputation of the user, or notify them, and of course I also want the question to be listed somewhere so I can find it when I want to.

I don't really see a difference between this and the implementation of the "thanks" button.

By the way, I didn't really know what the button was supposed to mean and I had to start writing a question here before it recommended me this post. There is no "title" attribute on the button so I doubt people will be aware of its purpose, what it means, or when to use it. They will just click on everything that seems positive enough.

Call it favourite answers and stylize it so and there will be no issue.

Comment: While I too think that the thanks button is redundant, as far as I know, the favorite button is for bookmarking questions for later reference or checking for new answers.

Comment: Indeed it's not called "favorite" any more, but "bookmark".

Comment: @philipxy That explains why the icon was changed then. This makes me wonder why after replacing a "subjectively-oriented" feature (favourites) with more descriptive feature (bookmarks), another feature is introduced that goes in the right opposite direction.

Answer (score 12):

> A new feature test I did find
> Having never come to my mind
> Somehow to make it right
> Or fix it they even might
> Replace it please with the right kind

I *think* I can understand how many users, including those inside the company, who have used many social networking sites would like the idea of a non-binding thanks, or +1, option. I think it's also another method to encourage engagement by low-rep users and allow the audience (in current parlance) the opportunity to participate. It might even supply a new metric for statisticians to track.

I also think the idea is not implemented in a manner conducive to the overall corporate goals. In so far as I understand the goals anyway. I have two different trains of thought for this "test," which are independent. One is how to implement it, hopefully in a fashion to make it possibly useful, and the other is why to cancel the idea completely.

---

## Cancel the concept:

> Internet points for loss 'n gain
> The button is a regal pain
> Wild oats do not sow
> This concept must go
> Sure hope it never comes to reign

In the rationale provided, the statistical weight of "thanks" type comments suggested that such a mechanism would be useful as a *clutter-free way for users to just say "thanks" to others for taking the time to answer questions.* Not true.

1. Adding the new button/icon to the voting area is adding clutter to *every* answer, forever
2. Adding the count of "thanks" clicks is adding clutter to the clutter
3. Users currently adding the, supposedly disallowed, "thanks" comments are unlikely, in the main, to change their bad habits
4. If the user receiving the "thanks" is never notified of them, the rep of the user being thanked is not affected, the "value" of the answer is not affected for ranking in the list of answers, and there is no method to sort by "thanks", then the button, and it's count are completely "noise", or decoration (i.e.: clutter)

Another possible rationale for including this concept is to allow users, or audience, to "participate" in the site at ultra-low rep levels. It allows such to "participate," in an meaningless manner. Their record of participation will not exist if they are not users already, and if they are not users, it *removes* the inducement to join. Without the button, if enough answers are worth their attention, they might be induced to join so they *can* up-vote nice answers. With the button available they will think "they've done their part" and move on, never joining the site.

Similarly, for those users without the rep to vote, having the button available to "vote" with reduces their inducement to participate with, as [Help Center Reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) puts it, "The three most important activities on Stack Overflow are Asking, Answering and Editing" so they can earn the rep to cast a real vote.

To actually reduce the number of commenters saying thanks, delete, without apology, any and all such comments. Such a filter should be available, as it must have been used to find them for the statistic used in the decision process.

To raise the level of participation by low-rep users, lower the bar to participation. Perhaps allow voting as soon as they have posted either an answer or a question which has received an upvote, regardless of net votes. Perhaps even allow up-voting as soon as the account is created. It only take 5 rep to participate in meta, including decisions about the site, why should it take three times that to express the positive value of a posting?

Personal experience with voting: There are many sites which I am not a member of. Sometimes I land on one of them from a search engine, and actually find my answer. Out of habit I up-vote the answer only to be reminded that I'm not logged in. In my case, with rep from other sites I'd have the Association Bonus, and could instantly vote. For others who may not be high enough on any site to get that bonus, they join the site, try to vote again, and hit the brick wall of rep needed. So much for a positive first experience. On the other hand, if they get the prompt, join the site and cast their vote, they "thank" the poster, with real thanks in the form of reputation, and they have a positive experience with the site.

One final though in this section is that the law of [Unintended consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences) still applies to SO, as has been repeatedly demonstrated recently.

---

## Fix the concept

> To this button I do not consent
> The clutter some users will resent
> To control who gives thanks
> And avoid the many pranks
> A few changes you should implement

Limit who can use it. If it is supposed to be just for "thanks", it probably should only be on answers, and available to the user who posted the question. If it is a method to increase engagement with the unregistered, and/or lower rep users, then is should only be available until the regular upvote privilege is earned, if that should happen for the user.

Limit who sees it. It should only be visible to those who can use it, and the user who is receiving the "thanks."

Limit, even further, who sees the count. The user receiving the thanks should know how much they have received. The user who posed the question, when the thanks is on an answer, probably deserves to see the total as well. That might encourage them to write more "quality" questions if they see an increasing number of "thanks" handed out to those who've answered their question.

Make it less meaningless. If the thanks is cast by a user unable to upvote, it can increment the upvote score while not awading rep like a real vote would. If the intent of having the button is for others who cannot vote to say they like the answer, then it seems reasonable to increment the "vote" count for all to see. This will help with the sorting of answers (including the stale answers) based on votes cast, rather than the rep earned on the question.

If the option to use "thanks" is limited to non-voting users (and non-users), remove the clutter of the vote buttons, Can't use them, why have them?

The use of "thanks" should be just as anonymous as any other vote. As the author of the post, or as a random user, I shouldn't know who clicked thanks any more than I should know who clicked up or down vote.

No matter how it's done, don't add to the gamification by making any achievement badges connected to the "thanks" button, for casters or receivers.

If the button is made available to those able to vote, get aggressive in the removal of related comments. The script, regex, or other tool used to detect the comments for statistics should be good enough to weed out such comments. If, on the other hand, it's not trusted enough to automate comment removal. If it's not trusted for removal operations, it shouldn't be trusted enough to be the base for business and development decisions either.

Comment: If limericks then / Panache & effort shine but / Scansion? Minus one.

Comment: TLDR.  But upvote for effort!

Answer (score 12):

As the other answers say, I don't think there will be many situations where the "thank you" reaction is appropriate and an upvote is not, but, in my opinion, there's another big problem:

### People want to express their gratitude by words, not by a button

This is why upvotes failed as means of saying "thank you". This is why people use comments for thanking. This is why this system will (likely) fail its goal. **Users don't only want to *thank* the person that helped them; they want for that person to know *how grateful* they really are.** The problem is that others don't really care about how grateful some person is to another person.

So, how can this be solved?

There is another way to express how grateful person A is for person B: [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Instead of person A cluttering the comments, person A can talk to person B directly.

There could be a "talk to this answer's author" link next to "add a comment" which would create a new room with the title of the question's title or something similar. Or each time an user is about to post "thank you"  or "thanks" in its comment, a warning could appear saying

> If you want to thank the person that wrote this answer, you can do so via [chat](https://example.com/).

The user could press the "Add Comment" button again to dismiss the warning, for comments that say "thank you", but add something to the post.

Comment: I like your idea, but I think this will face even more resistance on Stack Overflow than the feature being proposed and tested officially.  It puts too much distraction on the person being thanked.

Comment: My one fear with making chat more accessible is that contributors might (ab)use it to reach out for technical support and ask variations on the original question. You already see this with some frequency in the _Low Quality Posts_ review queue, where people post answers hoping for individualized help adapting answers to their exact needs. Do you think that would be an issue? Or am I overblowing the risk?

Comment: *This is why upvotes failed as means of saying "thank you".* I think it also matters that voting something up isn't interpreted as a "Thank you" anywhere else online. It almost always means you think something is good but that isn't really the same thing as thanking someone for making it. Not even the tooltip for the arrow says anything about thanks. Having been in online communities with reaction buttons I suspect that this will work better than you think, though you do have a point that there'll always be people who want to *say* thanks.

Comment: @JeremyCaney That's something I haven't thought about. But if someone asked "variations on the original question" in SO, it would probably get marked as a duplicate, so I'm not sure what they should do in that case. I wouldn't mind answering small variations of questions I answered in the chat. Maybe that link could be hidden in highly active questions to prevent spam.

Comment: If you don't have 15 rep to vote, you don't have 20 rep to chat, so this doesn't really solve any problems.

Comment: @Catija We can make the private chat available to everyone.

Comment: The last thing I want is someone trying to open a chat with me.

Comment: why questions don't have thanks?

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion this is a bad decision. I know you are trying to be more modern, but Stack Overflow is a Q&A website and it's not supposed to be like any other social network...

Also, most Stack Overflow answerers help because they gain reputation (that's how humans are; they like top scores and trying to get badges, etc.) and that's exactly why Stack Overflow is still working. If people start clapping instead of upvoting, then you will lose a lot of users.

Comment: A regular challenge for the site is to help new user invest some time and get onboarded in the community. Currently, if you're under 15 rep you can't say anything but either post a question (and that's hard to post a good question, and a good user will often search and find his answer without the need to ask for a duplicate) or try to provide a full answer. Aprat from that, you can't even (up)vote as participation in in the site

Answer (score 12):

Broadly - and based off some of the conversations on twitter and here, I suspect this feature, if aimed at a new user kind of misses a critical thing.

While its still [september](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/S/September-that-never-ended.html) one of the goals of getting users who are *valuable* and contribute to the whole is to try to at least change some of our bright eyed, bushy tailed new users into folks who understand how things work.

For this to work - we need to build in a way to funnel people into the voting system they can. Many new users are frustrated they can't vote, funneling them into reactions *until* they can might be nice. Likewise - for a user *just* able to vote a reaction giving a reminder might be nice.

Its also worth asking - how *directly* does this stop someone from saying thanks if they don't entirely get the system yet. Would greylisting the word thanks help (with an are you sure popup that's just dismissable?)

Its not sufficient to add features to help folks new to us. Its also necessary to use those features to make those folks learn the ways we do things.

Answer (score 12):

Till now:

- I upvoted about 500-1000 answers
- I did say thanks in comments for about 5-10 times.

So for me they are different. upvote means it works, but thanks means i want to say thanks to the person that saved my day.

**BUT** my only porpuse of saying thanks is letting the answerer know it (notification). so for me the current button (which doesn't notify the answerer) doesn't make any sense

Comment: Catch my upvote, but **please** stop saying thank you in the comments.

Answer (score 12):

If kept, **this feature should only be available to users whose reputation is insufficient to upvote**.

Its purpose is in conflict with the existing controls. It was created specifically to give low rep users a way to show appreciation. For other users it presents a confusing choice between reaction icon and voting. Voting works. Reactions are a placebo.

Answer (score 11):

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers. Although it’s less common on questions, the percentage of “thanks” comments have continued to slowly increase over the last few years.

This requires a deeper analysis to truly understand. What percent of people leaving this kind of comment are able to upvote? You need 50 rep to comment and only 15 to upvote. The only exception is that OPs are allowed to comment on answers on their own question regardless of their rep, so the only case where this would even apply would be if they were the OP and had less than 15 rep at the time that they left the comment.

If there are lots of people with 50+ rep who are leaving "thanks!" comments in lieu of upvoting, then the question is why that's happening, and why a "thanks!" button would work better at preventing this. If that's the case, then perhaps an improvement to the voting mechanism would be in order.

Also, has the number of "thanks!" comments increased faster than the number of users and/or the number of answers? If there are, for example, 50% more answers and 50% more "thanks!" comments, that wouldn't really prove much.

You also need to see how many of these comments are "thanks, but..." comments (e.g. "thanks, but I was asking how to do this by using bitwise operations, not by using `if` statements"). These comments are *not* noise and would not - and should not - be eliminated by a "thanks!" button.

Also, what percent of these comments could be auto-deleted by the first person flagging them as "no longer needed"? If the percentage is high, wouldn't one solution be to encourage people to flag them as noise?

Answer (score 11):

Adding a button to stop people from saying "thank you" does not make sense. Some people say thank you and add more info. It is just a polite way of communicating. For example if someone comments:

"Thank you but I have tried that but it does not work".

If you really want people to stop saying thank you without any additional info let other users flag down their comments and notify the user that their comment was deemed unnecessary and if a user repeats the action for a number of times say 5 their ability to comment to be disabled for 3 or so days.

Comment: Ow.. punishing for wrong comments.. that's harsh.. but somehow I like the idea ;)

Answer (score 10):

### An alternate approach - separate out 'Thanks' comments

As others have said, I don't think this will work because it's trying to fight the human desire to express gratitude with more than just a button click.

This is my very rough mock of what seems to me to be the simplest approach to solve this:

[image: comments section with new 'add thanks' option and thanks tab]

The idea is just to allow a comment to be categorised as 'Thanks' and then to separate out the 'Thanks' comments into another tab (or have a show/hide Thanks comments toggle button, or some other UI way of keeping the two types of comments separate).

People are used to adding thanks comments below the original post, both on this site and other sites, so this seems like the best place for it.

Some code/regex to automatically recognises 'thanks' type strings in normal comments could then be used to trigger display of a message asking people if the comment is thanks, with buttons to close the popup of:

- No, this is a comment about the post
- Yes, thanks!
- Yes, add thanks and upvote

Or something along those lines.

#### Comments that are both thanks and continuation of the discussion

Edit:  Looking at the comments in the mockup it's interesting to note that there are a couple of thanks plus info comments:

- I've thanked the answerer (something I don't normally do) because I wanted to reinforce the behaviour of adding useful code comments
- and @dawson has a thanks comment that also includes some useful info about a common error people will make with this type of approach (as evinced by the upvotes on that comment).

So, the point there is that thanks comments can also contain information that improves the post too.

Possibly the answer to that would be an "It's both" option for the thanks popup that then asks the user to separate out the thanks from the continuation of the discussion.  That would also give us the opportunity to explain to the user why the separation of thanks comments and discussion comments is important.

### Bigger picture: Embrace the "thanks" comments

On a more general note, rather than trying to fight human nature, why don't we embrace the thanks comments?  1 in 6 users want to say thanks, so why don't we let them?

Stack Overflow often discusses how it there's a problem with it feeling unfriendly to newcomers. This is an opportunity to allow the site to be a bit more human.  Possibly being told not to say thank you is part of why it feels a bit inhuman sometimes?

I'd definitely get a boost from people saying "thanks, your answer really got me out of a hole at work", it would increase my engagement with the site.  That increased engagement might then cover the cost of storing the thanks comments?

Comment: I read this proposal as something like "meta comments". So there should be comments strictly on the question's content and "meta comments" which are more open.

Comment: Why do you want to keep useless comments? Normally those "thanks" are just ignored and should be removed at some point.

Comment: @Sinatr I discuss that in the 'Bigger picture: Embrace the "thanks" comments' section

Comment: This could be a good idea since the user who posted the answer might think it's nice to get "thanks" comments, but I think that the "thanks" comments should be hidden to everyone else since for everyone else they're just noise.

Comment: @Sinatr It's almost impossible to get rid of all the thanks comments. And Moderator time is wasted trying to remove these comments.

Comment: This could be a good idea, but some people complain about “thanks” comments cluttering up their inbox. I am not one of them, however.

Comment: I think categorising comments is one of the most promising features to improve them, but I would go one step further and add other categories it could be too (e.g. suggested improvements / additional information / meta / whatever else) and then get rid of the "comments" category. We could even make "thanks" part of something like "discussion", to give users a place to post more of what isn't technically allowed, but they keep posting anyway.

Answer (score 10):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

From [Robert's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398374) it's clear that a decision was made to make thanking public through the timeline. Why was this decision made while votes are private?

---

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Has any numerical analysis gone into the thought process behind this other than:

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers

And were any other avenues considered instead, such as:

- Automatically notifying users that thanks in comments was discouraged;
- Automatically sending notifications to users whos comments were deleted as no longer needed through a single flag due to the presence of a "Thank you"

---

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Can we expect a detailed analysis of the results at the end of the evaluation period ([à la Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff)) where you'll take into account meaningful questions and discussion before making a final decision on whether or not to continue with this feature?

Comment: When thinking about it relative to comments, they're public. People get to have their name attached to the comments so the answerers know who thanked them. There's a sense of community that can build by knowing someone specific liked your post. This is also how the feature currently works on Teams, though clutter on the timeline isn't great. I'd like to investigate alternatives that keep it public without doing it on the timeline. I understand that there's maybe concerns... we've talked about it internally more than once and decided this was the direction we wanted for the test.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the full query is described by what you see in the image - all comments containing "thank" - so this would catch "thank you" and "thanks" but not other spellings like "THX". I'm working on getting that data pulled so that we can know how many of these comments are truly thank you comments directed at the answerer and bearing no other valuable information and how many fit into other categories like the answerer saying thanks to someone suggesting a change to the post or someone including a "thanks" while asking for more information.

Comment: @Catija The button is close to the vote buttons and is functionally similar, so it's reasonable to assume it's also anonymous. It's a problem that you seem to only be able to find out it's not anonymous by checking the timeline. That's not something most users check (I assume), which also makes it a bit of a strange choice to include it there.

Answer (score 9):

I've been scanning this topic since its inception, and I think I finally have something actionable:

Instead of this "thanks" thing, use what you already have. **Add a way to see the net score when "anonymous" votes are included.** (This is also votes from logged-in users who don't have permission to vote, yet.) You already tell people that their votes "are recorded" when they are not able to vote on posts, but those votes are very carefully sent to a database table that most people do not even know about.

#### Pros:

- This does not affect the current scoring system.
- This continues to teach people to use the "vote" buttons. No one has to realize "Aha! Now that I'm `$rep > x`, I need to stop "thanks"-ing and start *real* voting."
- You have historical data. (Hooray!)
- Anyone can vote, so no more quibbles about inclusivity for the people who have `x < $rep < y`.

#### Cons:

- If anonymous votes don't go right to [Write-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)) memory, people might try to stuff the ballot box with bot submissions.

  - Mitigation: These votes *still* don't mean anything important to the site governance, post ranking, or usage. Same as this "Thanks" business.
- People will still argue about the UI.

  - Maybe a grey number replacing the "thanks" thing?
  - Maybe something you can only see when you click the "real" score to get the up/down counts?
- If this whole "thanks" thing was just a cynical ploy *to get more users signed up,* my idea doesn't help with that at all.

Answer (score 9):

The added text on the profile page (Activity tab) now makes the selector spill over into a second row. If you edit in the browser developer tools to remove " and reactions" text it fits correctly again. This is fullscreen browsing with Chrome on a macbook.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Answer (score 8):

### Positive reactions should count as upvotes

Personally, I think this feature makes sense: reactions exist on lots of other platforms (Slack, Twitter, GitHub Issues, etc.) and are now intuitive to a lot of people.

This can solve two problems:

- People want to say thanks (and this is apparently annoying because, for reasons I have never understood, we don't want people's humanity being expressed)
- People don't upvote enough (definitely an actual problem I experience, as someone who answers a lot of questions on a certain tag, and frequently get zero-voted-but-accepted answers).

The obvious thing is that a positive reaction should either:

- count as a upvote (if the user hasn't otherwise voted)
- automatically trigger an upvote

#### A gripe

Stack Overflow Inc had been doing a really good job of collecting feedback early on, giving the community heads up before rolling out features, etc. This feels like a step backwards. Specifically:

> If you run into any issues or bugs, please share them here.

You're not even asking for feedback about whether we even want this feature, or how it should work? Just "issues or bugs"? It feels kind of crappy.

Comment: If it should trigger an upvote, then there's an upvote button. So what's the point?

Comment: *"count as a upvote (if the user hasn't otherwise voted)"*, I liked this. And that also addresses the [comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction#comment775902_398401): with two de facto upvote buttons maybe now newbies start upvoting more.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Users below 15 reputation points are prevented from voting to make voting fraud harder. I don't think auto-votes triggered from a button equivalent to 6 lines below the up-vote button is going to change anything if users are already not noticing the huge triangle. As a bonus, one can un-thank a post at any point, while voting locks after 5 minutes.

Comment: I think for a lot of people there's a very big difference between a triangle (and its rather abstract notion of voting) vs the very friendly and familiar clapping (or heart or thumbs up or whatever icon ends up being used) icon to indicate "thanks, you helped". Voting is *cold*. Thanking is *warm*.

Comment: @SteveBennett I see. So when I've written an answer, I can be made to feel warm and fuzzy instead of getting the chills from the cold triangle.. (note that I do not think this will ever induce an auto-upvote)

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I'm saying that the *action* of thanking/voting feels warm/cold. How you receive it is separate. Now a question for you: if someone is clicking "thank", what semantic distinction do you draw between that and the upvote, such that upvotes should count for something and "thanks" shouldn't?

Comment: @SteveBennett Since there are multiple contributors in this comment thread, I only get notified if you @-ping me. The difference between the two for me would be: "Thanks, nice try" and "This is useful". Basically the thanks-button would for me be a mini-downvote. Unless they came from a <15 reputation point user, where I'd interpret it as someone not understanding how the site works yet, which obviously would prompt me to **comment** and explain.. if I ever noticed the thanks.

Comment: (First, wow - I've been around here a long time, never knew that about notifications) Interesting comment - I guess you're seeing the "thanks" as a deliberate choice (if they wanted to upvote they would, therefore the thanks must be sarcastic or expressing something other than genuine appreciation that the result was helpful.)

Comment: Yes, it should trigger an upvote, if the user has enough privilege and he hasn't voted yet, if he is reacting to it saying Thank you, what could be the problem for him to upvote? An upvote is necessarily *implied* in his *Thank you*

Comment: @JavaTechnical So what should happen when the thanks is retracted an hour or a month later?

Comment: @Scratte I don't find a point of retracting a thanks one month later, why should one *Thank* someone in the first place if the answer doesn't help? Thanks isn't a token of *excitement*, we cannot say *thanks*, and say *No thanks* after sometime, so it is an indication of true appreciation of *help* which is given only when we are actually *helped*

Comment: @JavaTechnical I doubt this feature will be used only one way. And since there is an option to retract it, considerations to what should happen is definitely warranted. As a side note: I would only use this feature as a "Thanks, but no thanks" or a "Thanks for your time, but it's but enough" or "Thanks, but you completely missed the point". I would **not** want that with an auto-upvote. If I wanted to upvote, I would upvote.

Comment: Hmm. I agree, but if users get habituated to just saying *Thanks* but not upvoting? Not all may think, *Thanks* in different ways as you said i.e. not all thanks can have *but...* s

Answer (score 8):

Am I dreaming?! I can not believe Stack Overflow added this useless feature. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Don't underestimate the huge amount of raw "thanks" comments what could be instead turned into a much more useful clicks of that pretty new button. This feature is so much more important than anything else, what it goes unplanned with highest possible priority directly into production today.

Comment: Perhaps explain why it doesn't make any sense?

Comment: @PeterMortensen other users explained well, I think there is no need to repeat them.

Answer (score 8):

Didn't there used to be a "this answer was useful" link or something like that for unsubscribed users? Isn't there still some data from that?

Another half-way house idea: have a 'private comments' thing: where thank-you comments are only visible to the OP?

Another voting idea is what Ars Technica has: you can upvote and then you get a choice ("Interesting, adds to story, agree, funny"), I'm not sure that there is an actual difference with how that choice gets processed, but it honestly does make the voter feel "better" to be able to signify the meaning of their vote with more precision.

Comment: All users can click the up and down votes. Only >14 rep users clicks count but all of them are stored... so we do track the clicks, yes. If "private comments" were anything other than preformatted text, this would quickly become an avenue for abuse... and even if it were pre-formatted, someone could choose to harass someone by filling their inbox with dozens of them every day. I like the idea of subreasons for voting but I worry that it would overcomplicate and water down what votes mean here... technically votes shouldn't mean "this is cool"... things can be cool and wrong...

Answer (score 7):

Great experiment! Can you tell us about the control group?

Answer (score 6):

This feature attempts to solve a specific problem: **make comments better**.

The SO team identified a specific problem (unhelpful comment overload) and introduced an unexpected and prominent change to alleviate the problem.

It may help to solve the problem, but I think the community wishes you to think bigger.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. For me personally, just this morning, I got a "thank you" comment on an answer, with no upvotes. I had to inform the user to upvote and accept, **and** he didn't notice the new button.

Comment: @10 Rep: Yes, this usability issue ought to be fixed.

Answer (score 6):

The top-voted answers to this answer are saying say, "This feature is pointless, people should vote instead".

Neither the OP here, nor the blog post, say what you said on your private web site -- https://www.lisahpark.com/reactions -- that it allows reactions by visitors who don't have enough reputation to vote. Or it is mentioned in the Meta post ...

> This feature is available to all registered users, regardless of reputation (unlike voting, which is only available for users with 15 reputation or more).

... but there it seems to be a description of the *behaviour* of the feature, not the *reason* for the feature, so it's easy to miss that or to fail to infer the purpose.

Perhaps if you posted this then people would have an idea of:

- Why this feature happened
- Why it happened without their input
- Why specific design choices were made (like "no inbox notifications")

> ### PROBLEM
>
> Stack Overflow users are not allowed to leave comments on a post until
> they reach at least 15 reputation points. This often leads to users
> abusing the Answers field and posting non-answers. We collected data
> on the content of comments across the site and found that although
> users are discouraged from saying thanks in the comments, it one of
> the most frequently added sentiments.
>
> #### Goal
>
> - Quell the number of non-answer posts
> - promote helpful, relevant comments
> - give users a way to share their gratitude
>
> #### Research & development
>
> 1. **Ideation** The Community Product team ideated on different solutions worth exploring and converged on Reactions as possible
>    solution.
> 2. **Quick creation** I organized a design team brainstorm activity where product designers and UX researchers from across the
>    organization gathered to work on different ways we could integrate and
>    develop the Reaction feature.
> 3. **Hallway testing** I performed 1:1 interviews with coworkers who are also Stack Overflow users. This was an inexpensive method of user
>    testing to gather quick insights.
> 4. **Product divergence and iteration** We identified different risks and needs between our Public and Private platforms. At this point the
>    Reactions feature was going to be distinctly different than what we
>    would deploy on StackOverflow.com
> 5. **User Interviews** A new design was created solely for Public Q&A. I recruited Stack Overflow users for 1:1 interviews to gather more
>    targeted insight with our main audience.

Instead when you posted it here on Meta you posted it as a *fait accompli*.

IMO users dislike it because it doesn't solve their problem or they feel it's the wrong solution to their problem -- and IMO the reason for that is that you don't explain what you detailed step by step on your private web site, i.e. problem it does or is intended to solve.

Comment: Excellent answer, but there's one small issue. It takes only 15 reputation points to upvote, but it takes 50 (not 15) to be able to comment everywhere, e.g., see the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) help page.

Answer (score 5):

I am (ab)using this feature, when my answer was the first to a question and it has one upvote, and then another answer comes which is slightly more brilliant and also gets an upvote. I want to upvote the other answerer but then my answer will be ranked lower, so I just click the clap button. The OP accepts my answer as it was the first and is the highest-ranking.

Thanks, team. What a terrible, anti-community feature. I'm sure at least a few other users will also abuse the feature in some way.

Comment: Yes, I've started received claps instead of upvotes now. Apparently, that means "this answer is not useful, but thanks anyway"?

Answer (score 4):

I like the intention.  Humans want to say thank you.  Comments aren't for saying thank you.  Nor are upvotes, because upvotes are anonymous.  An anonymous thank you may not be what people want to express.  Accepts aren't anonymous, but can only be issued by the question asker on one answer only.  Therefore, there is currently no way to say thank you, in particularly not for a question or for more than one answer.

The options are:

- To not provide users with a way to say thank you (status quo), denying them of a human preference.  This is a valid alternative, because Stack Overflow is not a social network.  It could be seen as cold or unfriendly.  Users may continue to circumvent this may saying thank you in comments.
- To provide users with a dedicated way to say thank you.  This may reduce the noise in comments.  As described in other answers, it may also be perceived as sliding in the direction of a social network.  Some users may want to keep human interactions out of programming Q&A.

I'm not convinced it will work but I like the intention.  I hope it will be effective and make Stack Overflow a more friendly place.

Comment: Maybe we could automatically classify comments (not only as friendly/unfriendly but also) as ontopic/offtopic but not exactly delete worthy and then emphasize the ontopic ones. Or we could delete them with a delay (as a compromise with the two options). Thank you comments remain for a day and are marked as such.

Answer (score 4):

We could say that you are working in many locations, in a very complex hierarchy, and on a very complex software. Actually making decisions and executing on them, *without breaking anything*, is harder than saying, for example, "question migrations are bad".

We could say that your company are under a hard pressure of the investors to make more $$$ quickly.

We could say that maybe having a free service does not monetize so well as we would believe from other continents.

We could say that we are saying easily, what you should have to do, but actually doing that - and facing their consequences - is not so easy than talking about it.

There are so many excuses for you!

But your wonderful "development" refutes them all.

Comment: Extension: if I would want a facebook, I would be on the facebook. But I am on the SO. No, I do not want a facebook-like SO.

Answer (score 4):

If (and this is a big *if*, pending the results of this very experiment) the reactions feature provides value by cleaning up the comments, please **allow users to turn the display of reactions off in Settings**. For a user who appreciates the Stack Exchange mission and focus, these reactions are an unnecessary and annoying fluff distraction.

If I don't care about reactions, it should be omitted from my view of the Timeline as well.

Answer (score 3):

Are reactions private? That is, if I see that there have been reactions to some of my answers, is it possible for me to find out who those people were?

Comment: They are not private. To find out who thanked, click on activity icon below new thanks icon.

Comment: Since you can only vote up, not down, it probably doesn't make sense :-)

Comment: @Cyrus just to add to that for a bit more completeness - you can see who thanked a post when looking at the post. However, you cannot see all the thanks of a person. You can, however, see all the posts you thanked in your profile.

Comment: No, they're not private, you can see who made the reaction in the timeline. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62444191/timeline)

Comment: I would never use this feature if my reaction was made public.  Mass serial downvoting is a problem.  New users who submit extremely low quality content, but happen to have a small amount of reputation, are known to serial downvote users.  I have been a victim of serial downvoting on unrelated communities that those users were active on due to commentary at another community.

Answer (score 3):

Some UX suggestions that I think are better ways to accomplish the same goal

### 1. Allow Shadow Voting for All Users Under 15 Rep

If the problem is that new users (under 15 rep) can't interact / vote - solve that problem explicitly by allowing them to vote.  Since there is a concern about people creating new accounts and sockpuppeting their own answers up, just allow them normal interactions and show them as having voted but don't increase the vote count or user scores.

You could even log these events and allow them to make an impact as soon as the user passes the Community Voting Threshold so **early engagement is still rewarded and encouraged, just not exploitable**.  New users would be trained on how exactly to use the system, with their reactions just weighted appropriately.

### 2. Use Reaction Icons for Voting

As others have mentioned there is already a way to thank posters.... **VOTE UP Questions / Answers**

Hopefully, all roads would lead to rome and someone who expressed thanks should also be voting up an issue, if they have the rep (even if it only happened on the backend).  Any potential increased engagement of thanking over voting is likely due to the familiarity with leaving reactions.  But then we're directing users away from voting.

**If you want to encourage a friendlier kind of voting, you could replace the up / down vote icons with thumbs up and thumbs down**

Example Voting with Thumbs Up/Down Reactions

[image]

Comment: The ugly emoji thumbs up/down button would make Stack Overflow no different to those other forums with crappy UI

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be a good idea. I was confused about the purpose when I saw this reaction icon on answer and that brought me to this post.

As many other previous posters I also think upvote can mean "Appreciate the effort and thank you".

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea...

The only way I can see this feature to work (even though I don't like it and would rather not have it) is to make the thanks button automatically also trigger an up-vote, as people are supposed to do for questions/answers they like. This way any thanks/like action gives people their acknowledgement and reputation.

Comment: There are issues with approach mentioned in other posts and comments to those posts. The "Thanks" can be retracted, while votes are locked. Also, it makes it very difficult to use it as a "Thanks for your effort, not no thanks for your solution".

Comment: There is a reason we made it >14 rep can't upvote; so this feature would be harmful.

Answer (score -9):

On social media in general, it has been recommended by psychological experts to comment instead of pressing 'like', as the ease and anonymity of 'liking' something leads to negative social consequences, such as malicious envy:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4710707/

With this in mind, yes, the upvote and downvote buttons can be viewed in the same fashion, but at least someone writing 'thanks' has put some effort in. It's more sincere than clicking a 'like' button, at least.

Comment: Oh gods, not the Daily Mail... Even *if* they are right, it's will be the wrong source.

Comment: Comments are supposed to be useful, if we allow "Thanks" as a comment, there will be so many "thanks" comments that you won't see the useful ones.  Also, how can you get reputation from a comment?

Comment: @Anonymous Nobody actually writes "thanks". This isn't a problem we have.

Comment: @metamorphosis That's what this answer is proposing.

Comment: @Anonymous Its only a problem if it's problematic, is what I'm saying. We don't have a problem with excessive 'Thanks' at the moment, so the proposed feature was a solution for a problem that doesn't exist. And it's rare for someone to Merely say 'thanks'. Hence a comment is more sincere, more useful, and more Human. No further comment.

Answer (score -12):

I'm ashamed to admit I was kind of excited when I saw that you could add "reactions" to an answer.  My mind was dizzy with possibilities.  Oh, it's literally just ONE reaction?  Thanks?  How is that different than an upvote?

Then I thought about it.  Even if there were a bunch of reactions, what would they be and how would they be useful?  Love? Funny?  Meh.

I do LOVE seeing SO experiment with features like this, but this is a miss.

Comment: "what would they be and how would they be useful?" Ask and ye shall [receive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398452/2573061)

Comment: Obviously, “love” and (especially) “funny” wouldn’t be useful in context of SO—though that does seem to be the assumption many respondents are making, likely due to how Facebook implemented reactions. But there are other sentiments that _might_ be more appropriate for SO like “Informative” or “Outdated” or “Confusing”. (It’s admittedly easier for me to envision these as _negative_ feedback.) I’m not convinced reactions are a good fit for SO—and especially as a _complement_ to voting—but if I were to evaluate them seriously as a feature, that’s the direction I’d be considering.

Comment: @JeremyCaney But if one was confused about a post, it makes more sense to post a comment clarifying what about it is confusing. Likewise, it makes sense to explain when something was outdated and what replaced it. Else it's kind of like a "Not really working - figure it out yourself"-message to both poster and everyone else. We already have that type of no-comment message with the downvote.

Comment: @Scratte: Oh, for sure. Though, I also think that a comment is _almost always_ more articulate and useful than a downvote, and especially if we want to mentor future generations of contributors.

Answer (score -13):

A lot of people seem to miss the point that new users are *not allowed to vote* on answers. This feature is not really to thank the author, but to provide a way for new members to feel like they are interacting with the site more.

It is basically a black-hole, to let new users feel like part of the community without anyone having to hear them. Which seems a bit... cynical.

**Why don't you just let new users vote on answers and questions, but not include those votes**. Same overall effect, less extra buttons to dilute the main vision of the platform.

Comment: That's already somehow the case. Even anonymous users can vote on questions, the vote is not counted, but reset as if the site cancelled it, on the UI. But you have some weird message that says "you know we don't show your vote and we cancel it but internally it's still counted!"

Comment: "Why don't you just let new users vote on answers and questions, but not include those votes." Wouldn't that be equally cynical? If you let people do something, you should actually use the result for something.

Comment: @Trilarion well that's a different matter... SE/SO has decided they don't want uninformed votes I guess. If you think that's wrong, you should raise it as a separate question on meta.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I plan to raise it as a separate question. This was just a comment on your argument that making new users feel like part of the community without anyone hearing them really is cynical. I fully agree and think that this is also the case already for the current practice of registering votes that do not count. I don't really see it as a different matter.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you :) I never knew new users couldn't vote... maybe they get a lot of angry noobs not liking the answers?!

Comment: @Mr.Boy It's not about uninformed votes. People can be plenty uninformed and still have 15 reputation. It's designed to prevent people from easily making dozens of sock puppets to inflate the score of a primary account. The socks need to post *something* and get two upvotes rather than just being able to sign up and vote freely. Socks are already a huge problem even with the existing limitations - removing the minimal rep for voting would make it exponentiailly worse.

Comment: Re *"It is basically a black-hole"*: [Shadow banning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_banning) by default? *"Michael Pryor of Fog Creek Software described stealth banning for online forums in 2006, saying how such a system was in place in the project management system FogBugz, "to solve the problem of how do you get the person to go away and leave you alone"."*

Answer (score -27):

I have to say, I think it's very slimy tactic that you have to register to 'thank' a post. It is absolutely against any positive point this feature might have brought to the site. Oh well, a golden opportunity was missed.

And this is yet again another possibly game-changing feature that hasn't been vetted with the team here. Such things are always immediately going to draw the ire of users here, especially the veteran users.

Comment: Sometimes registration is the only way to get access to something. How useful is thank from unknown user, who is potentially just a cafee machine from some botnet? Sure, it can make you coffee if you find it, that's all contribution.

Comment: @Sinatr, That said, it would appear that the culture of just throwing potentially identity altering changes onto the site without any even the briefest preview, consultation, feedback from those of us who do regarly take part in the upkeep, is firmly alive and well at StackExchange. It's as if they've done nothing wrong, even in the recent past, that might cause them to reconsider that way of working with the community.

Comment: The top-voted answer to the top-voted question on this site already has 13 thanks!

Comment: I can verify that you don't get a badge if you are a registered user and max out your allotment of 'thanks'. Also, very curiously, it resets at midnight, not *x* hours later. Definitely still in beta. I really think they ought to consider a notification for thanks, even if it isn't immediately, perhaps after a week?

Comment: @ouflak: "For some us, it's nice to see if we've helped somebody"  <- I feel I see that through the page view count.

Comment: I don't understand how this feature helps with unregistered users as you [still have to register to use it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398369#comment776582_398369). Unless you mean that it give a new reason to register (which presumably is part of the true reason SE is pushing this - it isn't to help curators thats for sure)

Comment: @LinkBerest, Didn't see that. Sleazy. Thanks!

Comment: @einpoklum The page view count doesn't reflect anything other than a users skill at writing a good title, and the number of people either fooled by it or lead by it :)

Comment: @Scratte, It doesn't even mean just that. When I thumb through posts to improve them, that counts as a 'view'. Often my changes are for poor grammar, sometimes the posts are irrecoverable. But I've still been 'reached'! It's a meaningless number.

Comment: Making this feature available to anonymous users would only facilitate spamming.

Comment: @D.Pardal, Spamming of 'thanks'? With no notifications? No comments? Just a click that registers a 'thanks' uptick? Who would even notice that? Nonsense.

Comment: Also, they did try getting [anonymous userfeedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) back when Atwood was here so they could have combined those two ideas (it was also at the comment space instead of near the voting buttons)

Comment: Yay! I'm downvote number 1000! My post above explains why. I have to say that I think it's really good to have that kind of engagement from the community on a topic like ths.

Answer (score -31):

How about: *don't* delete "thank you" comments. Most of them take up one line of space, or are otherwise brief. A "like" button cannot convey what's said in words - we have an upvote button  already.

Comment: Why do you want to keep useless comments?

Comment: I see the "Meta" is clearly out of touch with its user base with these net-votes - but this isn't news to me.

Comment: @Sinatr "Thank you" comments are not useless comments, they make the website more human and are motivating to answerers. I think we should find a way to declutter comments and hide thank you comments, but not ban or delete them.

Comment: @Flimm, are we talking about SO or something else (e.g. Facebook)? Here I say thanks by accepting answer/upvoting and you are supposed to do the same to me. No one here really need "thanks" comment. Nor it's a replacement for upvote/accepting. Every user who wrote a "thanks" comment should have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read some [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267490/1997232) posts. Another point is what definition of "more human" depends on culture, you'd be very suprised how un-human you or me are to some of visitors, but it's them who have to adjust.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree that "thank you" messages are not a replacement for upvotes or accepting answers, and I never said otherwise. I guess people are different. When people thank me in a heartfelt comment, talking about how I saved them hours of work, or how they would like to buy me a beverage, that means a lot, and I don't assume they forgot to upvote. If you don't feel positive feelings when you get them, that's OK, people are different.

Comment: @Sinatr When people recieve a good answer, it's human nature to feel grateful towards them. They feel they need to do something other than clicking two buttons on their answer, so they put thank you comments.

Comment: I specifically avoid any website that allows users to “thumbs up”, “like”, or any similar action.  I personally find any “thank you” commentary extremely offensive

Comment: Stack Overflow already has an "vote" button!

Comment: I'd love to point to the stark contrast between reactions to essentially the same post between this and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398929/10133797). Just confirms my idea on audience variance and Meta being out of touch with the rest of users.

Answer (score -34):

> **Clarification:** My intention here is not to advocate for reactions as an alternative to voting. Instead, my main point is that while there is an argument to be made for reactions, trying to combine them *with* voting provides a really confused user experience. They are fundamentally competing and incompatible forms of feedback.

---

I could imagine an argument for reactions as a more expressive ***alternative*** to voting.

Currently, upvotes and downvotes can be a somewhat *ambiguous* signal.

- An **upvote** *could* mean "This is a quality post". But, on a question, it *could* mean "Me too"—or, on an answer, "Thank you". (Those two sentiments being independent of quality.)
- More importantly, a **downvote** on an answer *might* mean "This is incorrect". But it *could* mean "This adds nothing new", or "This is a sloppy post", or "I don't like your tone".

If reactions were to be pursued, the challenge would be identifying a set of globally intuitive icons that adequately capture the range of sentiments users intend to convey via voting. And then you'd need to answer questions like whether users can have multiple reactions, whether all reactions are worth the same reputation, how to aggregate reactions into a score, &c.

**The problem here, however, is that this reaction is being introduced as a *complement* to voting, thus introducing a *lot* of ambiguity in terms of sentiment.**

Notably, as [@rene hypothesizes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398383/3025856), this could very well reduce the amount of upvotes since, today, upvoting is the primary mechanism of saying "Thank you".

And while users *could* upvote *and* react, I'm not optimistic about that given how many contributors seem to e.g. accept answers without upvoting them, or vice versa. Or, worse yet, say "This solved my problem" in the comments, but neither upvote nor accept the answer.

Comment: We don't need to distinguish reactions. Upvote is for helful/good/working code/nice idea/well spotted, etc etc .. and downvote is for not working/not clear/doesn't answer the question, etc  ... The number at the end will give us an overall idea about the post AND of course you need to judge it yourself.

Comment: People don't vote enough as it is. We should be encouraging people to use the existing quality control mechanisms instead of introducing new parallel ones with even less visible impact.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I'm not convinced that we need to, either. My main point was while reactions might be a more expressive _alternative_ to voting, they don't _complement_ voting. And, as such, trying to have both just adds a lot of confusion.

Comment: Don't use upvotes to say Thank you. You are meant to upvote if you think the answer is useful.

Comment: @Dharman: Do you actually think that's how people use upvotes? Personally, I try to restrict my upvotes to thoughtful and informative posts. But I suspect that plenty of users use upvoting as "Me too" and "Thank you".

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: That was the point of my post. Having voting _and_ reactions makes no sense; they are competing approaches.

Comment: I like the idea of giving more differentiated, quantitative feedback, and I would like to discuss this in a separate feature-request. I guess the difficulty would be to find a workable set of categories. I could imagine that after an upvote or downvote, there could quickly pop up like three subcategories of more specific things you can vote on (like "answer contains good example", ...). I would like to restrict that on technical things, not sentiments.

Comment: @Trilarion: That idea of using reactions to _annotate_ a vote is interesting; I hadn’t considered that. At minimum, I think trying to understand what information is encoded in a vote is a useful exercise for determining whether a more expressive feedback system might be valuable.

Comment: Other things could include required level of expertise (for beginners, experts...), age information (outdated practice), completeness (includes corner cases). But you would have to trade-off the usefulness of such additional quantitative feedback with the costs of gathering the statistics.

Comment: @Trilarion, People already do that somewhat in comments when they write "+1 for ..." I think of it as Slashdot-style moderation (+1 Insightful, +1 Funny, -1 Offtopic, -1 Flamebait, etc.). A "-1 Outdated" vote would be interesting, but it would annoy a lot of long-time users: _"When I wrote this, it was the **only way** to `foo` the `bar`, and now I'm getting DVs because version 6 has `bar.foo()`!?"_ Doesn't mean it's a bad idea. Just one with entrenched interests.

Answer (score -37):

I like it.

The issue with score is that it indicates popularity, not necessarily quality. A oneliner of code will generally win over three paragraphs of text and no code. The problem is that the oneliner is wrong. Not "using too many CPU cycles" or "won't even run" wrong, but "*is* going to cause headaches when [actually quite common thing] happens" wrong.

What I *hope* this will achieve, is that "thanks" will stand for "usefulness", i.e. the visitor could read what was written and it helped them along, but the answer in and of itself does not necessarily deserve an upvote, because it isn't actually *good*.

But I guess that it'll take years to measure whether this actually realizes that.

Comment: What makes you think thanks will be used differently than upvotes in that regard? There's no obvious difference in intent, and there's no incentive or guidance to use them differently.

Comment: How would a oneliner be wrong? If you run the oneliner, and find out that it doesn't run, or produces an undesired output, then it would be _wrong_.

Comment: @10Rep I don't know if you're deliberately missing the point, but I mean an answer that can be copypasted, appears to solve the immediate problem and then breaks when a not so rare edge case occurs. This happens an afwul lot, yet those answers amass hundreds of upvotes. I'd rather see such answers have hundreds of "Thanks" and a handful of upvotes of people who don't know better.

Comment: I wish I could down vote this answer more than once, no offense to the author, it is just how I'm feeling about it

Answer (score -38):

A lot of users don't have reputation.

No reputation means... no upvote or comment possible.

So, this feature **is** useful if and only if it is available for the 1-14 rep window users.

Comment: I have previously mulled over a feature request similar to this: Expose a _Me Too_ reaction for questions, and a _Thank You_ reaction for answers—but only to low-rep users so they (feel like they) have a voice without resorting to (ab)use of the answer feature. But this is also where I get stuck in gaming out this feature. Do you just remove it for 15+ users? Do 15+ users still see the results? That transition seems really messy. If you keep it, they compete with votes. If you remove it, it’s like an entirely separate (and inconsequential) shadow voting system for _most_ users.

Comment: It takes more rep to comment "Thanks" than to upvote, what the whole heck is this response

Comment: @makoto You can't do either if you're lower than 15 rep, that was the only point of the answer.

Comment: @Makoto: Right. So what do contributors do instead? They leave _answers_ saying “Thanks”. I don’t know if it’s a big enough issue to worry about, as those are pretty obvious and easy to clean up in the _Low Quality Posts_ queue, but they’re definitely a persistent chore for reviewers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that authors can leave comments on their own post and Question authors can leave comments on the Answers regardless of reputation points.

Comment: @Scratte yes, you're right.

Comment: @Caney - Users will continue to submit answer that “Thank” other users even with a “thank you” button which is the exact reason this suggested feature is a horrible idea.  The focus should be to avoid the commentary submitted as an answer instead of collect meaningless “Thank You”s

Comment: It'll jus' confuse new contributors...