# Why am I being told to thank others for their answers? - when it's my answer!

Tags: bug

Surely this should be being shown to the OP(?).

Or should I give myself a pat on the back too?

[image]

Comment: Sure, why not, you deserve it (unfortunately you can't react to your own posts)

Comment: Might be worth posting this as a bug report answer on [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1364007)

Comment: it's like voting, You simply cannot use them on your answer but it's there. The front end is the same for all the answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction)

Comment: I guess it's not possible to report that entire "feature" as a bug :(