# What is the say thanks for this answer inside of answer?

Tags: support, user-interface

I see “say thanks for this answer” near of answers.

What is the meaning of this?

[image]

Comment: Additionally, why does it require you to be logged in. Doesn't an upvote communicate "Thanks"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction)

Comment: Add new `thanks` tag please

Answer (score 7):

It's a reaction, a "feature" of social media centric sites.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).‎

Comment: That's not a comment on this answer - just a "Canned Comment" from the AutoReviewComments user-script.