# New "Votes and Reactions" Tab, Precursor to something bigger?

Tags: discussion, reactions, thanks

[image]
Following [the introduction of "thanks"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1364007), we also received a new tab in "Profile > Activity > Votes and Reactions" changing the preexisting "Votes" Tab and changing it to "Votes and Reactions" in which inside them they also  have one more new tab, "Reactions" in which "Reactions" currently only has "Thanks". Does this mean that we are getting more reactions? Will SO become a pseudo-programming social media site? What is next, dislikes that don't count as downvotes?

This so far as I can tell is only on Stack Overflow and no other sites or meta-equivalents. What is this preceding in SO? Are "thanks" and reactions only a temporary experiment to combat saying "Thanks" in the comments or is this step one of a transformation in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Reactions on SO main are, from what I understand,a cut down version of the ones on teams , which also has things like: 100, celebration, and help

Comment: In all fairness, people have been saying "Thanks," "+1" and similar things in the comments since the site's inception, *despite the fact that we've had upvotes the whole time.*  Clapping hands and such is how the whole rest of the world works, and if we have that, we are justified in saying to those commenters, "OK, you already have two great ways to say "thanks," do you *really need a third?*

Comment: The negative reaction in [the original announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1364007) boils down to two things: 1.  The community was not asked first, and 2.  A lot of the folks who are here really, really dislike social networks and the havoc they cause.  Stack Overflow was created as the antithesis to those things, so the community is rightly puzzled that we would actually be moving *towards* that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with your point but is it really necessary in the first place to add a second option which is the hand clapping? Comments by design allows you to say "thanks" and say other useful things to add to the discussion like we are demonstrating right now. In the comments, it specifically goes against saying +1 but if you have enough rep for comments, you already have enough rep for upvotes yes?

Comment: It's a new feature, that they are testing on just SO... which is pretty common with how new features are generally introduced n the network.The new tab doesn't necessarily mean we'll get more reactions to choose from, it's just reactions aren't votes, and therefore needed a location separate from votes to be viewed.

Comment: I don't like the idea of emoji reactions, they make me go  in the .

Comment: @RobertColumbia  

Comment: They're watching your votes to see your reactions...

Comment: Nobody knows. But I guess that at the end of the year I might be able to answer it. Maybe the question could simply ask if more similar features are currently planned.

Comment: Maybe they dont want the comment section to get filled with "Thanks for the help" and stuff ...

Comment: @Dharmaraj thats kind fo obvoius if you read the original announcement post...