# Was there a community requirement to have reaction feature so "instead of clicking on like, you can just say 'thanks'"?

Tags: discussion, reactions, thanks

There is an interview to SO's CEO Prashanth Chandrasekar in a Spanish newspaper: [“No puedes hacer que la gente vaya a la oficina solo por tenerles ahí; debes confiar en que harán su trabajo”](https://retina.elpais.com/retina/2020/06/29/tendencias/1593435653_948491.html) <sub>You cannot make people go to the office just for the sake of it: you must trust they will do their work</sub>

There I was surprised to read the comment:

> (...) la semana pasada lanzamos la función de dar las gracias. Por primera vez, en lugar de hacer clic en me gusta, puedes sencillamente decir “gracias”. Es algo que la comunidad quería hacer.

That is:

> Last week we rolled out the 'thank you' feature. For the first time, instead of clicking on like, you can just say 'thanks'. It is something the community wanted to do

I went through the 'Thank you reaction' announcement [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1983854) and the only rationale I found is:

> We discovered that “thanks” appears in 1 of 6 comments left under answers

Is there any other rationale to roll out this change, which at the time of writing has a net score of -999 in the announcement post?

Comment: most people  think correctly, that it s polite, when somebody helps to sove their problem, that haunted them for some time, but a upvote and accepting the answer is ususally enough, a clicki8ng on a button seems to me redundant, besides that it woill not stop the thanbk comment in anyway

Comment: "when somebody helps to slove **their** problem..." (emphasis mine). The fundamental issue underpinning "thanks" is that many users seem to think Stack Overflow is a free coding service for getting answers to **their** coding problems and nothing else. The idea that it's intended as a _resource for future visitors_ and that questions are simply part of the mechanism for building that is completely lost on them. A "thanks" button helps misrepresent SO's purpose as a "solve *my* problem" platform.

Comment: Note to self: How could I miss this post? Thank you for bringing it up here! Since the interview was published on June 30th, reading through it left a somewhat sour aftertaste - it is very saddening to see the "something that the community wanted to do" statement and not even one word about how the feature was received or that SE had to announce that it would be turned off. Unless the article was prepared way in advance (for example, before June 17th), I am starting to look silly for advocating best intentions.

Comment: The problem with the CEO's words is that he is kind of jumping to conclusions. Posting thanks comments doesn't necessarily mean that there is a desire for a thanks button. I wish it would have been worded better. Also the feature hasn't really been launched. I thought and it was announced only as a test, not as an introduction of a new feature. Again, the wording seems a bit sloppy, even accounting for that he probably gave the interview in English, it was translated to Spanish by the newspaper and then again into English here, which might have lost some nuances.

Comment: Just a random observation; it was mentioned in the podcast with Ben Popper (Director of Content at Stack Overflow) and Paul Ford (not a Stack employee; he is on the podcast as a "friend of Stack Overflow"). Ben introduced it with a bit of fanfare, and Paul's reaction was "Finally!" As a listener, I was surprised and somewhat dismayed that neither of them seem to have heard about upvotes.

Comment: @tripleee See [Yaakov Ellis's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398909/data-validation-background-for-the-thank-you-reaction-feature-test/398912#comment779408_398912). The company thinks that voting and expressing thanks is not the same, i.e. there are useful contributions that aren't helpful and vice versa. One of these days, after the data analysis has happened I will ask a question about it.

Answer (score 29):

Yes there was a need, in the sense that they interpreted the amount of "thanks" comments as a problem that could be solved by adding a "thanks" button.

What they probably should have done instead is block comments containing "thanks", and show a popup explaining votes, instead, meanwhile unlocking votes for low rep users, making it only a visual change for them.

Comment: Alternatively they could have accepted that humans like to express thanks to each other with words, and that it's harmless really.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the new feature, but I suspect most of the comments were not simply one word "Thanks", but "Thanks" with some extra information, which cannot be conveyed by a button.

Comment: The funny thing is that votes for low rep users are already being counted, only that the info is just available through SEDE. It would have made sense to display that info more prominently.

Comment: Does this mean that if we keep posting comments that insult the poster with snarky epithets, we'll get an emoji reaction for that, too? I mean, there's a clear and pressing "need"...

Comment: A "Vomit" or "Garbage Truck" emoji for dumping homework question would be my next choice @CodyGray

Comment: @CodyGray actually that wouldn't necessarily be such a bad idea. It's not really (or at least it shouldn't be) about *wanting* to insult the poster, it's about expressing frustration and a downvote doesn't do that properly. If it were invisible to the poster, the downvotes and close votes would still do their job, but you'd get an additional "damn you!" button to let you vent without telling the poster to do unsanitary things...

Comment: The reason we don't allow it, @Kayaman, is because it's inappropriate and against the spirit of the site. This site is not about users; it's about content. That's why it's both inappropriate to send a personal "thank you" *and* to send a personal "screw you". You can find other ways to express your frustration. Use upvotes and downvotes to express your opinion about the usefulness of a particular post.

Comment: @CodyGray I meant in the sense that you would have a button that wouldn't actually *do* anything (except maybe something visually for you), i.e. equivalent to punching a wall. I know SO is supposed to be a QA site all about content (which is fine by me), but every so often you hear this "community" talk, and communities are about people. I don't really enjoy the schitzophrenic "be welcoming, yet strict, also strictness can be rudeness so be careful" nature, but I understand the business reasonings behind the whole mess.

Comment: @Kayaman That sounds like something that a userscript would/should provide. It's not quite so schizophrenic as you make it out to be. Granted, the messages from the company are somewhat mixed and confusing. But all we're *really* asking you to do is focus on content (not on users) and avoid snarky comments because they can be easily misinterpreted and hurt someone on the other end.

Comment: Do we need a design contest for the [Help Vampire](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216144029/https://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) icon? But that would be about (ab)users, not content, so we can't have it.