# When should I react (say thanks) to an answer and when should I upvote it?

Tags: discussion, support, upvotes, reactions

Well, I'm posting this as a question instead of an answer to [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/8967612) or [Data validation & background for the Thank You Reaction feature test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909/8967612) because it's going to be asked sooner or later.

Now, suppose I'm a new user who doesn't know anything about how the site works. I'm looking to solve a problem and I find a question similar to mine, so I start reading the answers. I want to give a (positive) feedback to one or more answers. I see two ways to do so; I'm confused (<sup>1</sup>). **Based on what criteria should I decide whether I should upvote or "react"?** Or let me be more specific:

- What types of answers should I both upvote and "react" to? Follow-up question: **Why both?**
- What types of answers should I upvote but *not* "react" to or "say thanks"?
- What types of answers should I "react" to but *not* upvote?

Well, you could say *"choose whatever feels right to you"*, and that's fine, but I'm looking for the viewpoint of the creators; they (probably) have some scenario in mind. That's why this question is especially directed towards staff members (or those who had a say in implementing this feature) but anyone who has an answer is welcome.

I'm asking this question because, like I said, it'll need to be asked sooner or later, and because...

- I genuinely don't know/see the difference (or when to use which).
- I would like to know whether or not they carry different messages. If so, what are they?
- If, on the other hand, they carry the same message, why do they have different outcomes then? <sub>(not even going to ask why they both need to exist; I already saw some arguments in the second post)</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Might as well!</sub>

Comment: I would also add: what types of question should I downvote and "react" to? .. (no it's not a joke, maybe someone wrote a detailed answer but at the end it's completely wrong)

Answer (score 55):

I made a simple flowchart to help you and others decide what to do:

[image]

Comment: Great flowchart! I just would like to add to the _"associate your name"_ part that the name won't be _noticeably_ visible to other users (not on the post's page, or in a notification) and will probably not be seen by the other users (including the one being "thanked").

Comment: Kudos for the *"certain observers"* caveat. The prayer emoji looks like two hockey sticks to me.

Comment: I thought it was a guy burying his head in his hands out of shame, @charlietfl. But even a prayer doesn't suggest "thanks" to me. Neither does the "wash your hands" emoji that the other half of the users see.

Comment: Important premise is missing. Do you want to say thanks? -> Do you have upvote privileges? -> ...

Comment: Can we have bounty on meta questions, please... this answer is priceless...

Comment: I would like to thank for this answer, but there is no react button. So I post a comment.

Comment: @charlietfl In reality, it's the symbol of two chairs with integrated speaker. Probably a new kind of innovative bus.

Comment: Thank you Cody, this has been very clear and educative! I hope you get to read this comment before it gets deleted. But regrettably, there was no compare-hand-sizes emoji next to the post to express my gratitude in a different way. (Joking aside, I actually think this answer is amazing, and hope it won't be flagged as offensive soon, as someone, somewhere without a doubt will find this post to bee too snarky, offensive or otherwise fail to see the humor in it, which is already borderline forbidden anyway)

Comment: "Answer a couple of questions..." That may not work on low-traffic tags. And might encourage spamming the site with answers (on doomed duplicate questions) just so they can later say 'thanks' to a post. Instead, edit some questions/answers for grammar, clarity, consistency, formatting, etc.... They could always jump into the horrific... um... er I mean wonderful inviting ['Thanks in Advanced'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanced%22) fray and help cleanup some of those posts. Keeping in mind, a lot of those posts need more work than just a phrase removal.

Comment: Completely off topic, but what did you use to make the flowchart? It looks nice.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Pretty much the first tool I found with a Google search. I wanted to make my life easy. Specifically, it was https://www.zenflowchart.com. All of the free services I found required me to create an account, but this one was the lowest friction, because it let me log in using my existing Google account.

Comment: @Remy There is no snark here. You can read my other answers/comments for that.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think it snark either, I apologise if I made it seem like I did. I was just remarking that some people do seem to take any kind of humor as a form of snark nowadays.(I also just noticed it got expanded, you did a great job, as I think it does actually reflect is well)

Comment: This Answer is not "correct", or at least not complete, I would think...?, as @OP clearly states "and I find a question similar to mine", => so the Qt is not "mine" in the Scenario, but the Chart only takes into account the Case of "the Qt is mine". And for Qt's that are not "mine", you need 45 Pts to be able to post a Comment, afaik, or what I remember when I had <45 Pts...

Answer (score 5):

[The linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction) is titled "Feature test"; it's quite obvious the test's result was "it doesn't work".

My answer to the "how to use it" question is: it doesn't matter, because the feature will be removed soon. Or maybe it will be replaced by another similar feature, which will be easier to understand and use.

Comment: `it's quite obvious the test's result was "it doesn't work"` Um, where exactly does it say that? The [other linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909/8967612) states that it's still _"currently being tested"_ and that _"the current iteration of the Thank you Reaction feature will be turned off at the conclusion of the current test (on July 17)"_ until they _"find the best way forward"_.

Comment: The test isn't over yet. This answer may be written from a perspective some weeks in the future from now.

Comment: "the feature will be removed soon" seems a bit optimistic to me. We still have that awful eyesore of a home page that non-logged-in users have to suffer, after all.