# Profile page says "votes" where it should refer to "reactions"?

Tags: bug, profile-page, reactions

In the recently-updated profile page under the "Reaction" section it says I have case no "VOTES".

This doesn't seem correct / doesn't make sense. Shouldn't it says "you haven't <something> any reactions" ? (Uhh "You haven't reacted" ...?)

[image]

Comment: It has the same empty state text for all categories becase reactions are a type of vote. Maybe the tab shouldn’t be called “Votes and Reactions” then, which would incidentally resolve the overflow issue.

Comment: @user4642212 sounds like an implementation detail leaking through. In apps I work on I probably would favor a "less is more" approach here simplify the text to something like "None" which then would work in all categories, is static, and requires little maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

The Stack Exchange software considers almost everything to be a "vote" behind the scenes. There are, of course, upvotes and downvotes, but there are also close votes, reopen votes, delete votes, and undelete votes. Then, flags are considered in some senses to be votes. So, it's not at all surprising that "reactions" would be considered votes.

I'm not sure if this is really confusing or worth fixing.

*Especially* since [this experiment will mercifully be over soon (July 17)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398909/data-validation-background-for-the-thank-you-reaction-feature-test)…

Comment: Correct - ultimately this is an architectural decision to not add a query to the question page.