# Make it clear that saying thanks is a public action that everyone can see

Tags: feature-request, privacy, reactions, thanks

As a long time member of SO, I considered the new "say thanks" feature as another kind of voting, which naturally should be private, like the existing upvote/downvote actions.

I also expected to get some daily "thanks" summary, like votes, in the timeline, and was astonished to see this instead:

[image: names of people who said thanks]

**Names of everyone who thanked are exposed**, and while personally I'm fine with it, I doubt others are.

I don't ask to make it private. Just make it crystal clear that it's public, e.g. by adding a note to the tooltip:

[image: Thanks tooltip with a note]

Can this please be done?

Comment: don't worry, tomorrow this feature will be disabled .. finally ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif really?? Didn't notice... lol.

Comment: See the [official announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909/11682469): "Lastly, we would like to confirm here that the current iteration of the Thank you Reaction feature will be turned off at the conclusion of the current test (on July 17), [...]."

Comment: I see you got the strange pointing tipi icon. With any luck we will never see this again :)

Comment: You are using "thanks"???!!! I am no longer speaking to you ;)

Comment: @JeanneDark _"..while we analyze the data and consider the different feedback that has been given, to find the best way forward"_. Hopefully, the "best way forward" will be that we won't see it again.

Comment: They're turning it back off? How am I going to show my appreciation for useful answers going forward?

Comment: @ivarni by posting comment "+1, thanks!!11!!!!" of course.

Comment: @Dalija *cough* I... ah... was only testing... *cough*

Comment: Haha, turning a live feature off on friday. I'll be grabbing my popcorn and hope for some fun bug to pop up because of it over the weekend.