# Remove obsolete page describing "reactions" from Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, reactions

The Stack Overflow Help Center still contains a page about "reactions":

https://stackoverflow.com/help/reactions

These were being tested from June 17, 2020 through July 17, 2020 (one month). [They have now been turned off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909) and are no longer displayed on the site in any way.

Please remove this obsolete page from the Help Center.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Thank you for this post!

Comment: This is irksome; I found the reactions help entry but [not a one about how voting works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404252/1079354).

Comment: There are multiple articles in the Help Center about how voting works. Among them are the [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) privilege pages, and also [Why vote?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), [What is "voting corrected"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), etc. It all depends on what you're looking for. @Makoto

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about the delay. The page has been removed.

Comment: I'm happy this is done but I'm bitterly disappointed that it took so long.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I hear ya. It's pretty embarrassing, too.