# The "Thanks" feature may be encouraging "Thanks" comments

Tags: discussion, questions, thanks

Among the replies to:

[Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398494#398494)

I remember some people were warning that a "Thanks" feature would take focus away from actually accepting answers; and now, a similar thing has happened to me. But - that's not why I'm posting! Read all the way down please.

This newbie question:

[What does this Code validation formula mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679028/)

is a bit problematic in that context is missing, but apparently I was able to address OP's misunderstanding - they say so, in a "Thanks" comment:

> I get it now. thank you so much! The program works well.. My seats is arr[5][7]. If I don't use -1 the seats the is reserved is the one after it. If the input is =1 the seat that is reserved is 2...

Since the question title is about OP *understanding* the code - I conclude that my answer solves the question, i.e. OP is effectively accepting. At first I was just annoyed by the non-acceptance, but then it occurred to me there's another dynamic at play. Here's what seems to have happened (a bit of speculation of course):

- OP realizes the answer has indeed answered their question.
- OP's attention is drawn to the "say thanks" widget, and away from the acceptance widget.
- OP presses "Thanks".
- OP realizes they also need to say the answer resolves the issue, so - because they are unaware of the acceptance option - they make a comment to that effect: They explain the "thanks" as "Thanks, I accept the answer".

So, **the presence of the Thanks feature seems to *encourage* rather than discourage the posting of a Thanks comment** (in addition to discouraging acceptance, which is what other people have pointed out).

Comment: It gets me when a new user just says thanks and never come back again. I hate reminding them we have accept button here in SO. Cause I have to make another useless comment in  the post.

Comment: Given that also before the "Thank you" was introduced new users often didn't accept an answer that help them, I'm not sure how much a single incident really tells us. If there is a trend it should show up in the aggregated data of the data explorer. You don't even know if op really clicked the thank you button...

Comment: Fun fact: this isn't the only post pointing out this behavior. There's several answers on the thanks announcements and a few deleted questions

Comment: @BDL: Of course this is an anecdote, a single case. But what's "special" about this case is that OP nearly-literally shows that their intention is to accept.

Comment: @einpoklum I had "This solve my problem, thank you" comments where op didn't accept an answer for ages. I really don't like the Thank you feature, but if you want to argue against it, why not query the data explorer and find out if the acceptance rate among new users has changed?

Comment: @Zoe just to add to that, I've already seen multiple examples where OP has *commented* with "thanks", clicked the "thanks" button but has neither upvoted (when they can) nor accepted the answer. There was at least one question where OP commented the same "thanks" comment to every single answer. I can't remember if they clicked the thanks button in that case.

Comment: @VLAZ: Well, I think that it's significant that such a comment is made _after_ (or almost at the same time as) press thanks. This cum-hoc situation suggests a possible causative effect.

Comment: @Zoe: Edit to emphasize that the point is not the discouraging of acceptance but the encouragement of thanking. But of course I realize there are other examples - I'm claiming that their existence is likely...

Answer (score 23):

In response [to the original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/399003/1):  This isn't a paradox.  This is the ***status quo***.

Even *before* this button was introduced, we've wanted people to accept answers.  [Remember the accept ratio?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/175248) This was used to bludgeon OPs into accepting answers or we'd snub their question entirely if we felt their accept rate was "too low".  So, it's no longer visible on the site.

In effect, we have something on the order of 8+ years of already established behavior in which OPs simply don't accept answers...and the current test to make it easier for people to say "thanks" won't even come close to addressing that problem.  In fact, that's not even the problem it's *meant* to be addressing.

This isn't something new.  This is what we've been dealing with since time immemorial.

Comment: @einpoklum:  I feel like you've completely invalidated this answer because of a mischaracterization on your part...I believe your original argument was more suited to the fact that "thanks" led to less acceptance, and my point was that was always how it was.  Now you're making an *entirely different* point that a "thanks" button leads to more "thanks" comments.

Comment: The title was about the paradoxical effect; but the body was mentioning both the non-acceptance and the paradoxical effect. Now, the non-acceptance point was already made, and comments made me realize I should "removed the duplicate part" of the post. I'm sorry that I made you go to the trouble of writing this reply. (I'm not being facetious, I'm actually apologizing.) If you tweak the wording I'll un-downvote. Or you could say ("responding to the original version of this question). Again, sorry.

Comment: the accept ratio was a good feature, so many users will not get any answers anymore, sorry that it is gone

Comment: @nbk:  No, it was a toxic feature.  Who wants to be part of a community when all you hear is the constant badgering of, "oh, you didn't do this action so obviously your problem isn't worth my time?"

Comment: that is exactly what i mean, notoriuos people should be reminded on login you hve 20 Questions and only 2 accepted.that would increase the bad acceptance. An when we are at it,  amessage, you didn't upvote your answer too. but i uderstand who wants to hear the nobody has answered me Still what good will a thank you button do, when they didn't marked it as answered or upvote it, this also wpuld only show, nobody need your answer.

Comment: @nbk I am with you on this. I have tons of unaccepted or even unvoted answers. Sometimes ppl just don't care about it. And it is quite annoying. Well you could argue, that reputation is an indicator of the "acceptance rate", but I like to help regardless of this fact. If the answer is interesting or If I just happen to know the answer I try my best. I think we should have reminders for ppl with lots of non-accepted answers. Or a small 1-2 min tutorial for new users that they have to complete (might be overkill). This might also reduce this huge pile of bad quality first-time-posts.

Comment: i have also the unsung hero batch, i simply don't think that the thank you button will change it for the better, but we spoke that we can't make someone upvote and we can't make them comment on downvotes or what ever, but now we **want to force** them to use a button instead of a short thank you and than you should use it besides upvoting and accepting

Comment: When you click on the "thank you" button you could ask for "do you want to mark this answer as accepted" (only the author). The joke is, that new users especially write it in the comment section regardless (see post OP). Maybe have some more hints like this just for newbies until you reach a milestone of n reputation - why not?

Also if you think of enforced learning. How does it work? With treats. You have to emit some dopamine. Maybe give them a badge or idk show them a popup/text with "thanks for choosing an answer you just raised your reputation by n pts".

@nbk Just makes it complex.