# I don't really Stack Overfollow you there

Tags: support

I might not be the better person in terms of UI/UX, but I am wondering if the term *"following"* is the best choice for the link under a followed question:

[image: "following" link]

Especially considering all the other terms are action (*share*, *edit*, *close*, *flag*, and even, when your are not following the question already, *follow*).

I also saw that a tooltip actually seems to have been added on this link for that exact matter of comprehension:

[image: Following tooltip]

Note that there is no other tooltip on any links of that set.

Why was *following* chosen over a more aligned *unfollow* here?
And shouldn't this choice be reconsidered?

---

For what it worth: I read recently someone commenting on the [Principle Of Least Astonishment or POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment#:%7E:text=More%20generally%2C%20the%20principle%20means,not%20astonish%20or%20surprise%20users.) and feel like the fact that it feels wrong to me or to the person who proposed it on [meta back then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345676/) is tightly linked to this principle.

Comment: [Already suggested when the feature was announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345676/) and was declined. For what it's worth, I also think "unfollow" is better.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, honestly, the comment of [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345676#comment1158132_345676) is not really helping clear it out. And the fact that there was a need to bring in a tooltip seems to contradict the saying.

Comment: I don't really disagree. Honestly, the only reason I brought it up is because a couple of weeks ago I was thinking of posting a FR myself for changing it but went through the announcement thread and found it was already suggested and declined. Hence why I remembered this post now.

Comment: AFAIK, the tooltip is there because this is a new feature that uses Stack design principle, not because of this issue. There's already a FR to add tooltip to other links.

Comment: FWIW I get a tooltip on all of them, just that for the others it's an `<a>` with a title prop instead of a `<button>` with aria-props and a JS controlled popover.

Comment: By the way, in case you didn't notice - if you click **follow** [the link *in the tooltip you get* is **Unfollow**](https://i.imgur.com/8O4qzl3.png).

Comment: @VLAZ only when you just clicked *follow* if you reload the page or come back to it after a while, there is just the tooltip

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes, that's what I meant. I just find it jarring that you get an "unfollow" button which...well, unfollows a post. But only if you've just followed it.

Comment: I concur with "unfollow," and agree that the current term violates POLA.

Answer (score 8):

My proposal

1. Replace the "follow" link entirely with a toggle similar to the bookmark toggle.
2. Replace the "History" link button with a "history" text button down by the other text buttons.

edit: History should say Activity, sorry.

[image]

[image]

Sorry about my MSPAINT skills.

Comment: Not sure about history in the links, I like the bell icon on the other hand

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but youtube also uses this, and it may make people think this is a social media. Kinda like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction#:~:text=On%20the%20left%20of%20an,will%20appear%20below%20the%20icon.).

Comment: Oof. Your link murdered my browser.  Here is the base link with less crashing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Oops :). Didn't see that.

Answer (score 7):

It might not be the best term but nor is the alternative.

I don't think the Principle Of Least Astonishment is meant to be applied/judged to every single UX element you can find. Instead it should be applied to the whole UX. Cherrynitpicking is easy.

The links under the post always keep the same title. Close doesn't become unclose, flag doesn't become unflag. I would be astonished if all those words all of sudden change based on their state. None of those links do that, so the *follow* link doesn't either. I like my UX to be consistent.

You could argue the follow link is not a similar function compared to the other links. It feels more like a toggle only option and those are normally situated at the left of a post. Vote, bookmark and thanks compete for the space there. So if you want to make an argument about UX asking for it to be moved to the left feels more logical.

We can't predict the future but maybe that follow feature is about to be extended with a dialog where you can select what you want to follow: Edits, comments, answers, accepts. If that is the plan then follow is fine where it is. We only need to wait another 6 to 8 weeks to appreciate our current astonishment.

Comment: Mhm, your third paragraph is not completely true. *close* does change to *reopen*.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That is after the whole post changed state. the Delete link isn't there all the time either.

Comment: You are "cherrynitpicking" here :) For a question to go to from open to close, there is a process, a review queue and all, in the end the question ends up closed. Is the link to reopen it labeled "closed"? Following a question is the same, except that the process to end up with a followed question is one step: "click on the link".

Comment: So as you can see, I don't agree with your "it's the only one that is a switch" statement either. From the end-user point of view, and that is even more true for someone having a low reputation and so less privileges, closed is also a simple switch, the question is either closed or not.

Comment: Flag and close are dialogs, share is a dialog, edit is navigation state change. That is the same once you reached 15 rep.

Comment: I totally agree on that part, indeed.  So yes, maybe this shouldn't be in this link set at all, and act more like the bookmark UI/UX.

Comment: And then I am actually wondering, shouldn't you bookmark **answers** and follow **questions**. What is the point of bookmaking a question, if you don't have the activity that goes with it? While you might want to not follow the buzzing activity but still want a quick link to that super useful one-line that @xyz posted back in June '14?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks ago bookmark was still called favorite. It made sense when it was called that way. Then UX folks got their hands on it and now we have this discussion ...