# Change “following” to “unfollow”

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, follow-posts

I noticed that the button for unfollowing says “following”.

I feel like changing it to “unfollow” would be more descriptive, and slightly less confusing.

Right now, you press “follow” and to unfollow you press “following...?"

Yes, it isn’t the end of the world, but it would make it a little less confusing.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399338/i-dont-really-stack-overfollow-you-there