# Stack Overflow Member Spotlight

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

Good morning everyone,

I am new to programming and have benefited so much from this site over the past couple of months. While it is just one of the many resources I am using to deepen my understanding of programming, it has certainly proven to be the most beneficial for me and my particular learning style. For that I am grateful. Grateful for the platform itself, but more so for the users that take time during their day to help answer questions.

That said, I had an idea for a possible new feature on the website.

**Stack Overflow Featured User Project**

Stack Overflow would not exist without the users taking the time to write about, research, and analyze the programming topics we are passionate about. The Stack Overflow Featured User Project would be an attempt to help users who are willing to participate to enhance their online presence by promoting engaging information about themselves, their relationship to programming, and the interesting work they're doing within the programming environment.

Perhaps the featured user profile could remain up for a month or so before being moved to a "Previous Featured User" section which could house all the profiles by year and month so the users could link to it if they so choose. For example, the link could be added to a LinkedIn profile, a CV, a Blog, etc.

In addition to occupying a section on the Stack Overflow website, they could also promote the profile on their social media.

The Featured User Profile could be structured something like:

**Creative Header**

- Picture(s) and links to current projects, books, blogs, etc.

**Biography**

A brief third-person personal biography. An opportunity for the user to personalize/humanize themselves by:

1. Sharing their name, where they live, what they do for a living, how much experience they have, etc.
2. Highlight their accomplishments in their field of work, hobbies, interests, and recently completed / upcoming projects.
3. End with contact information (for example - You can reach him/her at...)

I envision the biography to be around 250-500 words. The goal is to have the biography section serve as a conversation starter. Not overly intimate and to try to incorporate their own personality into it.

**Let's Talk About Programming Q&A**

Q&A questions would be sent to the featured user ahead of time to answer and then return. The questions should not be terribly technical, but rather serve as an opportunity to get to know the user better on a more human level. Perhaps some examples would illustrate what I am getting at:

1. What is your earliest programming memory?
2. What does programming mean to you?
3. What is your favorite programming language and why?
4. What compelled you to get started with programming?
5. What is your greatest/most memorable accomplishment? Did you have any hurdles? If so, how did you overcome them?
6. If programming was out of the picture, what profession would you see yourself in?
7. What advice or suggestions do you have for the younger generation interested in getting into programming?
8. Any parting words? How can we get in touch with you?

Additionally, we would have an **Apply** section where users can apply to this project. Basic requirements can be established, and then users could then nominate themselves or others via email with brief details about who they are, their work, and how they meet the requirements.

Comment: The first prerequisite is to reach 1 million reps. That was the time when [Stack Overflow hosted a Q&A session with Jon Skeet back in May 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/01/jon-skeet-answers-your-questions-irl/).

Comment: No thanks.  As an SO curator, I can see ways in which this could go horribly wrong:(

Comment: This would be too politicized. lets just stick to programming

Comment: I almost tagged this [tag:facebook] ...

Comment: @AndrewT. Does that mean [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2020-08-09/1144035?sort=reputationchange#1144035) will be "officially featured" by SO in 1 ~ 2 weeks?

Comment: @bravemaster Maybe, although not in the same way as with Jon Skeet because of everyone's favorite virus. We'll see though, the company has changed since 2018 - there's probably not a fixed policy

Comment: "Sharing their name, where they live, what they do" - well, surely this will go terribly right :)

Comment: Yeah....having seen down/close voting result in death threats, I am fully convinced that this is bad idea:(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would argue that the *best* thing to do is to offer a bounty to award them some extra reputation on the site, if you really wanted to say thanks.  Some of us don't do this for praise or attention; we just like to help on occasion.

(I especially don't want my face on the internet if I can help it, or ways to contact me.  We've already had issues with people reaching out to try to get help on their questions outside of Stack Overflow, and we shouldn't perpetuate that.)

We're a Q&A site, and while we're flattered and grateful that you're thankful for the efforts put into the site with answering, praise/highlights aren't *central* to the notion of Q&A.

Answer (score 17):

One of the principles on which this site was created was an emphasis on the content, not people creating it.

For instance, we often say that downvotes are not punishment because they are not reflective of the person who wrote the post, but rather of the content of post. Similarly, people with high reputations are people who have provided useful content.

It's also behind [the pushback to the recent experiment in adding the "thanks" reaction to posts here on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/215552). That reaction goes toward the user rather than the content. Content gets upvotes, people get reputation.

That principle also backs pushback towards attempts to compare/convert Stack Overflow to a social media site. I feel like this proposal would push Stack Overflow that much closer to that idea by focusing on the person rather than the content.

Perhaps something that promotes great *content* on the site could be considered...

Comment: "Perhaps something that promotes great content on the site could be considered..." - Like the hot network questions :) Those links are... dangerous. You click one, you're not working for the rest of the day.