# Was there an update with a change of the line spacing?

Tags: discussion, design

It seems to me that since this afternoon there is an increased line spacing in questions and answer everywhere in the text.

Is this an oversight or by design?
Do we have to live with it permanently now?

I don't see any improvement when reading text now and you have to scroll more!

Comment: Apparently. Mobile view is uglier than ever now, barely readable with all that spacing.

Comment: Not a fan of this change.  Less data-dense.

Comment: I've got say-- this looks *really, really* ugly. To be honest, in the start, I thought they changed the font :)

Comment: [Here's a userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353542) to revert the change (puts line-height back at 1.3 instead of the new 1.6)

Comment: I have also noticed that the SO server has been *very* slow today. Probably caused by processing all that extra whitespace. ‎

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: SO will always surprise us ... what the hell is the magic line-height number: 1.61538462 ?

Comment: Wait, I need to scroll down to the Answers section to see if anyone posted my thoughts... Might take a while

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting?cb=1

Comment: @TemaniAfif 21/13? 42/26? I'm guessing that it's being calculated from another settings

Comment: Seems to have been [mostly reverted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/353446/revisions).

Comment: Now it's 1.5. I am glad I missed the 1.6, but 1.5 is still way too much. It's not even so much the added scrolling, it just makes the text hard to read. Please can we go back to the tighter spacing we had before? There was nothing wrong with it. And no, this is not people being "resistant to change", it is a change for the worse. Excessive line-height has been a design trend for some years, and I have no idea why. It doesn't make text easier to read, it looks bad and makes text harder to read.

Comment: Agreed.  I *thought* I was seeing things until my eyes noticed this metapost.  Some of us *don't want* to have to add styles to userscripts/userstyles to fix an issue which was never broke in the first place.  Simply see the comments above.  SO please revert this.

Comment: I didn't notice anything until I read this, and now I can't unsee it :-(

Comment: I just sprained my index finger from all the extra scrolling I now need to do

Comment: Apparently, they slightly [changed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353561) from the 1.6 line height with space between elements. But to me, still hard to read with awfully larger paragraph breaks and less than stellar UI.

Comment: I don't know if I missed this when I noticed the line height changing but not the bottom margin on paragraphs seems horribly huge, Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640832/arranging-divs-in-the-footer for example.

Comment: Should this also be tagged as a feature-request to revert the line spacing?

Comment: yeah it's a little rough...

Comment: Or maybe it could be a bug report? After all changing the formatting is one thing but changing the line spacing to such a comparatively large value might not have been intended. In any case I think that status-review should be added.

Comment: 2 days in - no diamond in sight. Must be a very long weekend.

Comment: No one else seems to share my view, but I like this change. Previously I always gave up on large chunks of text, but they seem more readable with a little extra space.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> Is this an oversight  ...

No, it is not an oversight.

> ... or by design?

It is part of the [New Post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting). It rolls-up a couple of long-overdue [styling issues](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/prose/). I guess with the adoption of [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) these styling changes are easier to apply across the network. This new line-height came as a stowaway

> Do we have to live with it permanently now?

You certainly have [to live with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change) for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). It is also worth [revisiting this MSE question on design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like)

> I don't see any improvement when reading text now and you have to scroll more!

Yes, there are already [userscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353542/158100) that adjust / rollback some of these changes. I'm sure people will link them here in the comments

You can add the following style to your own userscripts/userstyles add-on to resolve this issue:

```css
.s-prose { 
    line-height: 1.3 !important; 
}
```

The actual value can be adjusted from `1.3` to something else based on your personal preferences.

Comment: Umm... what about that new code fence?

Comment: @10Rep what about it?

Comment: On dark mode the background of a code fence changed to a black. Try it out.

Comment: @10Rep y'all wanted dark-mode, now you have it. It doesn't get much darker than that ;)

Comment: None more black.

Comment: @rene But my eyes are bad at contrasting :D. I can barely see code. Plus, the line spacing makes me want to revert to light mode.

Comment: @10Rep that is the big Master Plan of Aaron, revert to light mode ...

Comment: I thought he was the one who created dark mode! But he's succeded.

Comment: @10Rep I'm told he was reluctant about it at first.

Comment: There is nothing "long-overdue" about this spacing change. Plain text looks ugly and code looks horrible. I wouldn't add extra height to my IDE so why would I want code blocks to?

Comment: @rene I don't mind the dark background of the code block if the overall dark mode was darker but it looks really bad right now.

Comment: There's so much space we need SpaceX's help to get between lines of text

Comment: Thank you for that fix. I can look at it again now. It was hurting my eyes with all these spaces.

Comment: For those without userscipt but who are using uBlock-Origin you can style elements with `element:style(details)` syntax. So all you need is add *custom filter* like `stackoverflow.com##.s-prose:style(line-height: 1.3 !important;)`. This can be done by picking at `stackoverflow.com` eye-dropper icon (selector tool in uBlock), select anything and replace selection text with `##.s-prose:style(line-height: 1.3 !important;)`.

Comment: Psst... I think you forgot this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/

Comment: Also at 54 min 44 secs in [episode 42 (of the classic series), 2009-02-17](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode42-2009.02.17.mp3) - part of the Stack Overflow drinking game, from 53 min 00 secs. ["42" is (likely) a coincidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcF3ulnFtc4&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=27&t=6m25s) as the improbability field is probably not that strong.

Comment: The [original audio source of episode 5 (of the classic series) is at SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-73). The 6-8 weeks part is at 03 min 18 secs - 05 min 05 secs.

Answer (score 57):

@Rene said most of what there is to say. But the changes don't exactly stop there: The line spacing *also* applies to code sections, and the code sections are *so* light (for me), that the syntax highlighting doesn't really pop out as much:

```c
#include "foo.h"
void bar(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

EDIT:
Check out bullet points! SO bad:

- point 1
- point 2
- point 3
- point 4

Too much spacing!

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by increased corner radius of code blocks?

Comment: @oguzismail You aren't. I don't know whether to be happy or not :D

Comment: @oguzismail well, at least that now matches all the other border-radius's. So jay for consistency.

Comment: I don't know @rene it looks weird and narrows the horizontal space for text on mobile view. And I don't understand why anyone would need rounded corners around code blocks, it's stupid. I'd fire straight away whoever brought this atrocity into life

Comment: @oguzismail there are 172 sites in the SE network, not all are about code. It could well be these changes work great on 171 sites. Just on SO they missed a few typical use-cases.

Comment: @rene At least 5-6 sites are related to code. Such as code review, SF, SO, the list goes on.

Comment: @oguzismail Now that you mention it, I notice it and can't unnotice it. Very ew... something new to add to my SO sanity fixes user styles.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry :D Can't focus on anything, I'll have to take a break from SO for a week or so, I hope they fix it.

Comment: @rene, it could well be that changes that don't benefit one of the sites doesn't get applied...oops.

Comment: @TylerH I guess end goal is to show code blocks within circles. Change we observe now is only first small step

Comment: @gnat reminds me of the phase where people started putting avatars in circles because someone "brilliantly discovered" that "corner space is wasted space in headshots!" not considering that we can't do anything useful with it after reclaiming that space...

Comment: @TylerH Not considering my head isn't circular :(

Comment: @matt Sorry, no offense intended for oblate spheroids :-)

Comment: "Am I the only one bothered by increased corner radius of code blocks? –" ... I was not... until you point it out! Dammit! (like the bacjground color on dark theme, though)

Comment: @Pac0 It's actually a bug!

Comment: @oguzismail well, I am now. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 15):

Here is a list of all the changes made:

- The extra spacing.
- The new curve around code fences: I dislike this because coders like me prefer techier UI, instead of smooth new style UI. Instead of neat animations in our IDE's, we prefer old style UI.

[Here is a userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/Compact-Line-Height/StackCompactLineHeight.user.js) from @CertainPerformance to revert the line gap:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Stack Compact Line Height
// @description      Reduces the space between lines back to what it used to be
// @author           CertainPerformance
// @namespace        https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts
// @version          1.2.0
// @include          /^https://(?:[^/]+\.)?(?:(?:stackoverflow|serverfault|superuser|stackexchange|askubuntu|stackapps)\.com|mathoverflow\.net)//
// @run-at           document-start
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

// SEMI-IMPORTANT: If you wish to avoid flickering on pageload, this script must run before the page content loads
// If using Tampermonkey, you may need to enable instant script injection via:
// Settings -> Experimental -> Inject Mode -> Instant

'use strict';

// Feel free to adjust the numbers below as desired

(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
/* Spacing for normal text: */
.s-prose {
    /* 1.3 was the old line-height, 1.5 is the new line-height */
    line-height: 1.3 !important;
}
/* Spacing for code blocks: */
.s-prose pre:not(.s-code-block) {
    /* 1.3 was the old line-height, 1.30769231; is the new line-height */
    line-height: 1.3 !important;
}
/* Spacing between paragraphs: */
.s-prose p {
    /* 15px (equal to 1em) was the old margin-bottom, 1.4em (equal to 21px); is the new margin-bottom */
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
`;
```

Lastly, there is this new bug in dark mode. The code fence's background turns pure black. See the [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400727/12708583) for more detail.

Comment: Here's a full difference comparison of the OLD vs NEW css styling: https://www.diffchecker.com/JQ0He3pu

Comment: @Prid I can see they also changed some of the blockquote css. Thanks!

Comment: where? I don't see the blockquote changes. There might be more CSS files with changes that I haven't found yet, as the only difference is the blockquote text being lighter in color.

Comment: found another file with all the relevant changes (line-height, blockquote, code blocks, inline codes, etc.), called `stacks.css`: https://www.diffchecker.com/EmT786VM

Answer (score 7):

> Was there an update with a change of the line spacing?

Yes.

> Is this an oversight or by design?

By design. [More details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/674989).

> Do we have to live with it permanently now?

As long as we show our disagreement as entire community [at the feature-request to revert it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/674989) like we did at the ["Thank you" reactions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/12139179) bringing SO to maybe overthink their plannings and strategies regarding this new feature.

> I don't see any improvement when reading text now and you have to scroll more!

Same here. I wonder whether there is any date in the future where Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow finally [let the community to talk with **before** implementing such features](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398429/12139179).

Comment: There is another feature request asking for ability to customize line spacing in profile settings https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353536/313443