# Is Stack Exchange actually considering Collaboration Bounties (or other similar measures)?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-incentives

The recent satisfaction survey asked if people would like to see rewards for collaborative behavior, such as badges, collaboration bounties, and some new form of currency. However, unless I've missed something, I don't remember anything like this ever being discussed on Meta.

Is Stack Exchange actually seriously considering implementing something like that? If so, can we expect to see a concrete proposal about this being posted on Meta for community feedback? If so, when can we expect to see something like this?

Comment: I certainly hope there isn't an alternative to reputation. Isn't the craze with internet points high enough already? It's just going to make downvotes even more "negative" to new users.

Comment: @10Rep Yeah, I don't know exactly what that point in the survey means. I'd be really curious to get some clarification from SE about what they're actually thinking here - unless I'm missing something, this is the first I've heard about it.

Comment: Maybe they want something like "Thanks"-points ;) I'm only half-joking. It could be a way to make [Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction) come back, if they feel there's enough "data" to support it.

Comment: @Scratte The thanks feature was pretty horrible. At first glance, it didnt seem bad to me, but after a while I realised I was getting thanks instead of accepts and upvotes. If they bring it back, I'm outta here :D

Comment: Which survey? I didn't see any survey in the home page?

Comment: Can you link to the satisfaction survey?

Comment: @PeterHaddad You gotta look on the top banner, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is something we've been exploring and discussing internally. However, there's nothing concrete yet that could be shown, we're still very much in the research/exploration phase.

Our researcher and I put together some peer-reviewed studies as well as case studies and have been going over it to provide initial recommendations, that's... about it.

In terms of concrete things, right now there isn't much. What I can say is it's not related to the "thanks" reaction nor tied to reputation, if it's done it's not going to affect (reward or remove) reputation.

If we do move ahead with it (a likely if, but still an if), you can expect it to go through the normal review process for new features and it'll definitely be discussed at least with the Moderator Council and users through research before we build anything.

Comment: Question: When you say "normal review process", that means not implementing the feature and throwing it at us, right?

Comment: @10Rep Erm, yes. Right. When we have more concrete plans on it you should hear about it.

Comment: Ok, that reassures me. I do hope there are new badges.