# If I appreciate the effort and scope of an answer but cannot verify its correctness, is upvoting appropriate?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes

If I appreciate the effort and scope of an answer but cannot verify its correctness, and I am not the asker, is upvoting the answer a correct thing to do?

For example, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781921/3181104). I might've never seen the Google Sheet function `let` and seeing it in action prompted me to learn about it, which is cool. The answer appears to be well formatted and come from good effort. However, I would rather not verify its correctness.

In this case, is upvoting the answer appropriate?

Comment: It's your vote, if you think the post deserves one you're fine to give it one.

Comment: Though it's up to you, I think it would be better if people would only upvote answers that actually are useful or that they know are correct, not just that they think look credible. It's easy (especially with AI) to write credible-looking answers with no real value and get upvotes. (In this case, it sounds like you did find it useful.)

Comment: Not the example, but many [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) generated answers look superficially like that. The same for 100% plagiarised answers (wholesale copied from a blog post or part of a blog post. Or wholesale copied from official documentation (without any attribution whatsoever)). Better check for plagiarism before voting.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the upvote arrow it states "This answer is useful". Only upvote if you find the answer useful. But personally I would only upvote if the answer is useful to answering the question it applies to. I would not upvote an answer just because it happened to lead you to some new API or feature you didn't know about beforehand. That usefulness, to you, doesn't indicate its usefulness to the question that was asked. If you happen to also verify that the answer really is useful to the question, then sure, give it an upvote.

Comment: "is upvoting the answer appropriate" That depends on the used definition of appropriate. What do you want to achieve? Increase the signal to noise of the content? Give some random internet points to someone? Your goals decide what would be the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: Essentially your qualification is "maybe good". That would match the choice to not vote at all. It really shouldn't be this hard to make that choice.

Comment: This reminds me of the finale of the movie Billy Madison where the entire crowd likes the answer but the subject matter expert (quizmaster) knew how to judge it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKjxFJfcrcA

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to thank the user. On stackoverflow that's [not needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1997232), it's no a social network where you make friends and chat with them. Think of it as of a good documentation site in writing which you participate and where each up- or down-vote should help future readers.

Comment: Related: [MSE — How to upvote responsibly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/how-to-upvote-responsibly)

Comment: None of which means that your impulse to want to do something to recognize or appreciate the person posting the answer isn't great. It absolutely is. And this is a good meta question, thanks for posting it. The fact that the consensus (which I agree with) seems to be that you shouldn't use an upvote to do so in this case doesn't change those things. It just means SE's design doesn't support doing so in cases like this.

Answer (score 77):

While you can always vote as you think it is appropriate (whether it is up or down, unless you are committing voting fraud), upvoting answers merely because they look good on the first sight is not very good idea.

Upvoting sends signal that the answer is good or useful. If you haven't verified the correctness and usefulness yourself and you don't have the expertise to tell it is a good answer, then you might be sending a wrong signal to other people.

Not everyone here has the experience and knowledge and some people may rely on answers being upvoted when considering their information. If you upvote a bad answer that superficially looks good you are actively harming the purpose of this site.

This is now more important than ever, because there are plenty of AI generated posts sitting on the site. They can hold completely inaccurate and bad information, but can look like really good and elaborate answers. and such answers are not posted only by people with low reputation, but also by high reputation users.

**Please, don't upvote something just because it superficially looks good.**

Not only you will be doing disservice to others, but you can actually do harm to yourself, too. Votes are being locked after few minutes and if you figure out later that the answer is not correct, you will not be able to reverse the vote, unless the answer has been edited in the meantime. When you are here looking for answers, you might land on some answer you upvoted a while ago without checking it, and then your own vote might lead you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 19):

> I appreciate ... an answer but cannot verify its correctness ...

That means you have not "found the answer useful", which is the basic criterion for upvoting. You've just found it nice, or worthy-of-appreciation, which are not the same thing. So,

> is upvoting the answer a correct thing to do?

**No.**

Suppose it were incorrect; is it a good idea for it to have many votes? appear first to users looking to solve the problem? I'm pretty sure you'd agree that would be an undesirable state of affairs. So don't make that happen.

---

<sub>On *other* SE sites, though, such an answer may be sufficient for an upvote - when things like personal experience and perspective, or aesthetics inherent in an answer itself, are criteria for upvoting.</sub>

Comment: @PeterCordes: Well, I doubt this situation occurs on a regular basis. Anyway, see edit.

Comment: I appreciate your effort with this answer; but unfortunately I cannot verify it because I would had to wrote comment like that somewhere and see if it works, so I cannot upvote at this time.

Comment: Forget regular basis, I won't recommend leaving such comments at all, case in point is the comment above by Arek Kubiński, its not useful for the answer author, the comment author or any other readers.

Comment: @ArekKubiński: What effort? I just wrote my opinion. Still... you know what? I'm convinced. It's not useful enough of a comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have been convinced (!) by the arguments against my suggestion.

Comment: Good on you, I happily flip my vote. I do think that giving an opinion is fine in general, but not as a *suggestion* in an answer under a post seeking guidance. There is a time and a place.

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking, people come to StackOverflow to **solve problems**, and they expect answers to be sorted in that respect. So, you should upvote answers which solve the problem (or at the very least partly solve it, or some closely related problem). If you're not quite sure if an answer appropriately solves the problem or not, then don't vote.

Imagine if you had a problem with your car, and your friend recommends a mechanic to you. You go to the mechanic, and after a while of messing around you realize they're hopeless to solve your problem and it was a total waste of time. You ask your friend and they say, "oh, I had no idea they're a shoddy mechanic, I just had a great conversation with them and they showed me some sweet cars on their lot; that's why I recommended them."

Comment: You remind me that one of the front lights on my auto is not working and I need to schedule a service appointment (already forgetting 3 days in row to do it). So your answer is very useful to me and I want to upvote it.. but because I don't know, whenever your answer can solve OP problem or some closely related problem at least partially, I am, according to your answer itself, should not vote, sorry.